# Clean the muddy quartata-fish

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, grid

This challenge is in honor of the Rookie of the Year category winners of [Best of PPCG 2015](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8007/cast-your-vote-for-best-of-ppcg-2015): [muddyfish](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32686/muddyfish) (for [I'm not the language you're looking for!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55960/im-not-the-language-youre-looking-for)) and [quartata](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45151/quartata) (for [Implement a Truth-Machine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62732/implement-a-truth-machine)).
Congratulations!

### Background

In the deepest trenches of the ocean, there lives a rare and elusive square-shaped fish called the *quartata-fish*.
It looks like the [glider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glider_%28Conway's_Life%29) from the Game of Life cellular automaton.
Here are two quartata-fish of different sizes:

```
-o-
--o
ooo

--oo--
--oo--
----oo
----oo
oooooo
oooooo
```

You have managed to snap a photo of the quartata-fish, but the fish is rather hard to see since it's covered in mud.
Now you'll have to write a program to clean up the photo.

### Input

Your input is a rectangular 2D grid of the characters `.-o#`, given as a newline-separated string.
If you want, you can use pipes `|` instead of newlines as the separators, and you may assume one trailing and/or preceding separator.

The input will contain exactly one quartata-fish of some side-length `3*n`, where `n ≥ 1` is a positive integer, surrounded by periods `.` that represent the ocean floor.
The fish will always be in the orientation depicted above.
Overlaid on this grid, there will be exactly one non-empty rectangular region of hashes `#`, which represents a blob of mud.
The blob may cover the quartata-fish partially or entirely.
An example input would be

```
............
..--oo--....
..--oo--....
..---#####..
..---#####..
..ooo#####..
..oooooo....
```

### Output

Your output shall be generated from the input by replacing all the hashes with the characters `.-o`, so that the grid contains exactly one quartata-fish.
There will always be a unique way to perform this replacement properly; in particular, the blob of mud will cover the fish entirely only if its size is 3×3.
The output shall use the same separator as the input.
For the above input, the correct output would be

```
............
..--oo--....
..--oo--....
..----oo....
..----oo....
..oooooo....
..oooooo....
```

### Rules and scoring

You can write a full program or a function.
The lowest byte count wins, and [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default/) are disallowed.
There are no time bounds: if your submission would eventually halt given unlimited time and resources, you're fine.

### Test cases

```
Input:
.......
...-o-.
...--o.
##.ooo.
##.....
Output:
.......
...-o-.
...--o.
...ooo.
.......

Input:
...-o-.
...-#o.
...ooo.
.......
Output:
...-o-.
...--o.
...ooo.
.......

Input:
.........
.###.....
.###.....
.ooo.....
Output:
.........
.-o-.....
.--o.....
.ooo.....

Input:
.....
.###.
.###.
.###.
Output:
.....
.-o-.
.--o.
.ooo.

Input:
......
......
......
...###
...###
...###
Output:
......
......
......
...-o-
...--o
...ooo

Input:
###o--....
###o--....
###-oo....
###-oo....
###ooo....
###ooo....
###.......
Output:
--oo--....
--oo--....
----oo....
----oo....
oooooo....
oooooo....
..........

Input:
............
..--oo--....
..--oo--....
..---#####..
..---#####..
..ooo#####..
..oooooo....
Output:
............
..--oo--....
..--oo--....
..----oo....
..----oo....
..oooooo....
..oooooo....

Input:
...--oo--....
.#########...
.#########...
.#########...
...oooooo....
...oooooo....
.............
.............
Output:
...--oo--....
...--oo--....
...----oo....
...----oo....
...oooooo....
...oooooo....
.............
.............

Input:
..............
..............
.########.....
.########.....
.########-....
.########-....
.########o....
.########o....
.########o....
.########o....
.########.....
..............
Output:
..............
..............
..............
..............
....--oo--....
....--oo--....
....----oo....
....----oo....
....oooooo....
....oooooo....
..............
..............

Input:
.................
.................
..---ooo---......
..--#########....
..--#########....
..--#########....
..--#########....
..--#########....
..oo#########....
..oo#########....
..oo#########....
....#########....
Output:
.................
.................
..---ooo---......
..---ooo---......
..---ooo---......
..------ooo......
..------ooo......
..------ooo......
..ooooooooo......
..ooooooooo......
..ooooooooo......
.................

Input:
.........................
.........................
....----oooo----.........
....----########.........
....----########.........
....----########.........
....----########.........
....----########.........
....----########.........
....----########.........
....oooo########.........
....oooo########.........
....oooooooooooo.........
....oooooooooooo.........
.........................
Output:
.........................
.........................
....----oooo----.........
....----oooo----.........
....----oooo----.........
....----oooo----.........
....--------oooo.........
....--------oooo.........
....--------oooo.........
....--------oooo.........
....oooooooooooo.........
....oooooooooooo.........
....oooooooooooo.........
....oooooooooooo.........
.........................
```

Comment: Is it ok if the entry has a probability it won't finish (bad randomness) even though the chances of that are extremely low? Also are you allowed to change characters other than the single newline-pipe?

Comment: @muddyfish Yes to first question (it must eventually finish with probability 1, assuming perfect randomness, but may theoretically run forever), no to second (the characters are fixed).

Comment: so is a probability of 0.9 recurring ok?

Comment: @muddyfish If you're generating random grids in a loop until one fits, that's ok.

Comment: Important test case: `......|......|......|...###|...###|...###` (in case a solution tries all possible top-left coordinates, and tries to fit a 6x6 over the area)

Comment: @Sp3000 Thanks, I'll edit that in when I get the chance.

Answer (score 9):

### Python 2, <s>433</s> 411 bytes

```
import re;i,o,l,j=input(),range,lambda s,r:s.replace(*r),"".join;i=l(l(l(i,".1"),"#."),"| ");s=o(len(i))
for x in s:
 for y in s:
    for q in s:
     r=map(list,l(l(i,"o."),"-.").split(" "))
     try:
        for v in o(q):r[x+v][y:y+q]=["".join(c*(q/3)for c in b)for b in["-o-","--o","ooo"]][3*v/q]
        m=re.match(i," ".join(j(i)for i in r))
     except:0
     if sum("-"in p for p in r)and m:print"|".join(l(j(i),"1.")for i in r);_
```

Exits with a `NameError`. Takes input pipe separated.

I'm mixing tabs and spaces here. SE doesn't render tabs properly.

```
'###o--....|###o--....|###-oo....|###-oo....|###ooo....|###ooo....|###.......'
 --oo--....|--oo--....|----oo....|----oo....|oooooo....|oooooo....|..........

'.....|.###.|.###.|.###.'
 .....|.-o-.|.--o.|.ooo.

'...-o-.|...-#o.|...ooo.|.......'
 ...-o-.|...--o.|...ooo.|.......
```

(Note extra spaces at the start are for prettiness only and aren't actually printed)

Comment: You can get rid of the extra tabs in your code and replace them with single spaces to cut down on a few bytes (that is, if you took the white space into consideration when counting the bytes in your code).

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 291 bytes

```js
g=>eval('w=g.search`\n`;h=g.length/w|0;for(n=(w<h?w:h)/3|0;s=n*3;n--)for(x=w+1-s;x--;)for(y=h+1-s;y--;[...g].every((c,i)=>c==o[i]|c=="#")?z=p:0)for(p="",i=h;i--;)p=(l=[,"-o-","--o","ooo"][(i-y)/n+1|0],l?"."[t="repeat"](x)+l.replace(/./g,c=>c[t](n))+"."[t](w-x-s):"."[t](w))+(p?`\n`:"")+p;z')
```

### Explanation

Takes input grid as a newline separated string. Not completely golfed, will do more when I get time.

It works by:

- Getting every possible position and size of a fish in the bounds of the input grid.
- For each position/size, it builds a grid string with a fish in that position.
- Checks if this is the correct output by iterating over every character. If each character either matches or is a hash, it outputs the built string.

```js
var solution =

g=>
  eval(`

    // Get size of input grid
    w=g.search\`\n\`;
    h=g.length/w|0;

    // Check every possible size (n) and position (x and y) of fish
    for(n=(w<h?w:h)/3|0;s=n*3;n--)
      for(x=w+1-s;x--;)
        for(y=h+1-s;y--;

          // Check if possible solution matches input grid
          [...g].every((c,i)=>c==p[i]|c=="#")?z=p:0
        )

          // Create possible solution grid
          for(p="",i=h;i--;)
            p=(
              l=[,"-o-","--o","ooo"][(i-y)/n+1|0],
              l?
                "."[t="repeat"](x)+
                l.replace(/./g,c=>c[t](n))+
                "."[t](w-x-s)
              :"."[t](w)
            )+(p?\`\n\`:"")+p;
    z
  `)
```

```html
<textarea id="input" rows="6" cols="40">..............
..............
.########.....
.########.....
.########-....
.########-....
.########o....
.########o....
.########o....
.########o....
.########.....
..............</textarea><br />
<button onclick="result.textContent=solution(input.value)">Go</button>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 4):

### Python 2, 325 bytes

```py
def f(s):
 s=map(list,s.split());R=range;L=len(s);M=len(s[0])
 for h in R(L/3*3,0,-3):
  for x in R(M-h+1):
   for y in R(L-h+1):
    if all(s[v%L][v/L]in".-#o #"[0<=v%L-y<h>v/L-x>=0::2]for v in R(L*M)):
     for k in R(h*h):s[y+k/h][x+k%h]="-o"[482>>k/h*3/h*3+k%h*3/h&1]
     return'\n'.join(map(''.join,s)).replace('#','.')
```

A badly golfed solution for now – the `for .. in range(...)`s are an utter train wreck. Inputs/outputs newline separated strings.

The byte count currently assumes space indents only – I'll switch to mixed tabs/spaces later when I'm done golfing, if necessary.