# Trick or Treat polyglot

Tags: code-golf, string, polyglot

Since Halloween is coming up I thought I might start a fun little code golf challenge!

The challenge is quite simple. You have to write a program that outputs either `trick` or `treat`.
"The twist?" you may ask. Well let me explain:

Your program has to do the following:

- Be compilable/runnable in two different languages. Different versions of the same language don't count.
- When you run the program in one language it should output `trick` and the other should output `treat`. The case is irrelevant and padding the string with whitespace characters are allowed (see examples).
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf),  so the solution with the fewest bytes wins.

A few explanations:

**Valid outputs** (Just for the words not for running the code in the two languages. Also adding quotes to signalize the beginning or end of the output. Do not include them in your solution!):

```
"trick"

"Treat"

"    TReAt"

"
     tRICk          "
```

**Invalid outputs**:

```
"tri ck"

"tr
eat"

"trck"
```

I'm interested to see what you can come up with! Happy Golfing!

I'd like to note that this is my first challenge so if you have suggestions on this question please leave them in the form of a comment.

### Leaderboards

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
# Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
# Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
# Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the leaderboard snippet:

```
# [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```js
var QUESTION_ID=97472,OVERRIDE_USER=23417;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=o.replace(TAGS_REG,"")),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i,TAGS_REG = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:400px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: [This meta answer](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/830/41881) states that near-duplicates can be tolerated if there's a good reason. I believe that the popularity this question receives from being close to Halloween is a good reason in itself, so I'll vote to reopen. I wouldn't mind closing it after Halloween (but I don't know if this would be a good thing either).

Comment: Does a null byte (`0x00`) count as white space?

Comment: @Riley I'll say yes.

Comment: @mbomb007. This is a duplicate of *what*?

Comment: @TRiG http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55960/im-not-the-language-youre-looking-for?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: definitely not a duplicate.  The only thing the same about that other one is that it's also a polyglot challenge with specified output.

Comment: This would also have been a fun one as a code challenge instead of golf.

Comment: @BrianMinton Which type of code challenge, i.e., which winning criterion, do you have in mind?

Comment: actually, looking at the tags, I think that what I was thinking of was just popularity-contest.

Comment: ... 3 pages... I *really* think that this is getting a lot of activity based on the current value of the seasonal variant.

Comment: The leaderboard doesn't work for me; it only shows the top 10 overall answers, and none of the Winners by Language.

Comment: @Oliver do you know why the leaderboard doesn't work?

Comment: What a great question!  I love how some of the answers illuminate and exploit how simple code fragments mean different things in different languages-- e.g. truthiness/falsiness and associativity of the ternary operator.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

## [2sable](http://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable) / [pl](https://github.com/quartata/pl-lang), 8 bytes

```
0000000: 74 72 65 61 74 93 d0 cb                          treat...
```

Both programs have been tested locally with the same 8 byte file, so this is a proper polyglot.

#### 2sable: trick

This is the program in [code page 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Code_page_layout).

```
treat“ÐË
```

[Try it online!](http://2sable.tryitonline.net/#code=dHJlYXTigJzDkMOL&input=)

#### pl: treat

This is the program in [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#Characters).

```
treatô╨╦
```

[Try it online!](http://pl.tryitonline.net/#code=dHJlYXTDtOKVqOKVpg&input=)

### How it works

#### 2sable: trick

```
t         Square root. Errors since there is no input. The exception is caught, the
          stack left unaltered, and the interpreter pretends nothing happened.
 r        Reverse stack.
          Reversed empty stack is still empty stack. ;(
  e       Compute nCr. Errors since there is no input.
   a      Alphanumeric test. Errors since there is no input.
    t     Square root. Errors since there is no input.
     “    Begin a lowercase string literal.
      Ð     Excluding ‘, ’, “, and ”, Ð is the 71st non-ASCII character in CP1252.
       Ë    Excluding ‘, ’, “, and ”, Ë is the 66th non-ASCII character in CP1252.
          (implicit) End string literal.
          Both characters together fetch the dictionary word at index
          71 * 100 + 66 = 7166, which is 'trick'.
```

#### pl: treat

```
treat     Bareword; push the string "treat" on the stack.
     ô    Unimplemented. Does nothing.
      ╨   Flatten the stack. This doesn't affect the output.
       ╦  Unimplemented. Does nothing.
```

Comment: But I've got to admit this answer is plain ridiculous! What's next? An answer that's shorter than the words themself?

Comment: This answer is extremely impressive. It's amazing that you managed to write a program shorter than the length of the two words.

Comment: Huh? Those are 2 programs

Comment: @FireCubez It's the same code, byte per byte. The visual representation varies with the codepage though.

Answer (score 206):

### Python / Windows Batch, 25 bytes

```
print"trick"#||echo.treat
```

Everything after the # is interpreted as a comment by python, while the || is an OR in batch, saying that as the previous command failed, execute this one.

I also like the use of an OR as it almost reads "trick or treat" :)

Comment: TBH I up-voted this just for the comment about the OR.

Comment: TBH I never ever expected my first post here to get 65 upvotes :)

Comment: TBH lets not just talk about upvotes. Its not Quora

Comment: @SAndrew as a brand new member of this community, i didnt expect to make a post that would be this well recieved this soon, and i'm happy to have been able to contribute. I'm not trying to brag, please don't misunderstand. I'm just really happy to be so well recieved as i'm so new. thanks for you're comment :)

Comment: @nephi12 I have tried running your code, but it doesn't seem to work. Running it on Python, as expected, runs flawlessly. But in a bat file, it just writes `'print"trick"#' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`
However, this version has worked for me:
`print "trick"#|echo.treat` - piping the output to the `echo`

Comment: @YotamSalmon double check that a "treat" isn't output after the error, as that is the function of an OR in batch. also, i'm not on windows right now, but i think i tried the pipe and it didnt work... are you running this in a script or on the prompt?

Comment: @nephi12 No "treat" is printed after the error. I'm running it from a bat script. What windows do you use? I'm using windows 7. However, if replacing the `||` operator with a pipe (`|`) works for you (when you're in front of a windows computer, try it out), it can save you a byte ;-)

Comment: huh, i'll look into it. not sure why it doesn't work for you as is though.

Comment: @YotamSalmon community consensus says that STDERR is ignored by default; only STDOUT is considered. Try the command again with `2>nul`.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Oh, cool! Didn't know that. Thanks for informing me!

Comment: @SAndrew quora stopped caring about upvotes for a long time. Stack exchange does

Comment: It's been several months since your first post now but I just found it and I want to say that we are now avatar buddies. </chat>

Answer (score 160):

## Whitespace / Starry, 135 bytes

Here's to a clear night sky on Halloween!

```
  + +    +      + + 
    +

* +   +*      +     *

   +    *           
     + +        

 +* +   



 +* + .  + .   +      +* +   +* . . .
```

*Note that whitespace on empty lines may not be preserved if you copy from the above code*

Whitespace outputs "TRICK". [Try it Online!](http://whitespace.tryitonline.net/#code=ICAgCSAJICAJIAogICsgKwkgKwkgCSsgKyAKCSsKICAJCiogKyAgICsqIAkgICsJICAJKgoJCiAgICsgIAkqICAJIAkJCiAgIAkgKyArICAJCQoJCiArKiArCQogIAoKCiArKiArIC4gICsgLiAgICsgICAgICArKiArICAgKyogLiAuIC4K)

Starry outputs "TREAT". [Try it Online!](http://starry.tryitonline.net/#code=ICAgCSAJICAJIAogICsgKwkgKwkgCSsgKyAKCSsKICAJCiogKyAgICsqIAkgICsJICAJKgoJCiAgICsgIAkqICAJIAkJCiAgIAkgKyArICAJCQoJCiArKiArCQogIAoKCiArKiArIC4gICsgLiAgICsgICAgICArKiArICAgKyogLiAuIC4K)

### Explanation

#### Starry

Starry ignores all tabs and new lines so the code it reads is the following

```
         + + + + + +  * +   +*   +  *   +  *       + +   +* +   +* + .  + .   +      +* +   +* . . .
```

Bytewise, pushing values is very expensive compared to stack and arithmetic operations in Starry. The code starts by pushing and duplicating 4 and the performs a number of operations on it and with 2 and 1 pushed later on produces all of the required ASCII values.

**Annotated Code**

```
Stack (after op)    Code        Operation
4                            +  Push 4
4 4 4 4 4 4          + + + + +  Duplicate top of stack 5 times
4 4 4 4 16            *         Multiply top two items
4 4 4 4 16 16        +          Duplicate top of stack
4 4 4 16 4 16          +        Rotate top three items on stack right
4 4 4 16 20         *           Add top two items
4 4 20 4 16            +        Rotate...
4 4 20 64             *         Multiply...
4 64 4 20              +        Rotate...
4 64 80               *         Multiply...
4 64 80 2                  +    Push 2
4 64 80 2 2          +          Duplicate...
4 64 2 80 2            +        Rotate...
4 64 2 82           *           Add...
4 64 2 82 82         +          Duplicate...
4 64 82 2 82           +        Rotate...
4 64 82 84          *           Add...
4 64 82 84 84          +        Rotate...
4 64 82 84           .          Pop and print as character (T)
4 64 84 82            +         Swap top two items on stack
4 64 84              .          Pop and print... (R)
84 4 64                +        Rotate...
84 4 64 1                 +     Push 1
84 4 65             *           Add...
84 4 65 65           +          Duplicate...
84 65 4 65             +        Rotate...
84 65 69            *           Add...
84 65                .          Pop and print... (E)
84                   .          Pop and print... (A)
                     .          Pop and print... (T)
```

#### Whitespace

As the name may suggest, Whitespace only parses the three whitespace characters—space, tab, and newline. Unlike the Starry, the Whitespace simply pushes the ASCII values of `T`, `R`, `I`, `C`, and `K` and the prints them.

**Annotated Code**

```
<Space><Space><Space><Tab><Space><Tab><Space><Space><Tab><Space><LF> Push the ASCII value of R
<Space><Space><Space><Tab><Space><Tab><Space><Tab><Space><Space><LF> Push the ASCII value of T
<Tab><LF><Space><Space> Pop and print the T
<Tab><LF><Space><Space> Pop and print the R
<Space><Space><Space><Tab><Space><Space><Tab><Space><Space><Tab><LF> Push the ASCII value of I
<Tab><LF><Space><Space> Pop and print the I
<Space><Space><Space><Tab><Space><Space><Tab><Space><Tab><Tab><LF>   Push the ASCII value of K
<Space><Space><Space><Tab><Space><Space><Space><Space><Tab><Tab><LF> Push the ASCII value of C
<Tab><LF><Space><Space> Pop and print the C
<Tab><LF><Space><Space> Pop and print the K
<LF><LF><LF>            Terminate the program. The following line is not run.
<Space><Space><Space><Space><Space><Space><Space><Space><Space><Space><Space><Space><Space><Space><Space><Space><Space><Space><Space><Space><Space><Space><LF>
```

The interweaving of pushes and prints was chosen based solely on aesthetic reasons as it does not affect the byte count.

Comment: so beautiful sky

Comment: this is by far the best answer, so creative. im shocked by the ingenuity. and the skill. bravo!

Answer (score 141):

## Linux ELF x86 / DOS .COM file, 73 bytes

```
00000000  7f 45 4c 46 01 00 00 00  1a 00 00 00 1a 00 43 05  |.ELF..........C.|
00000010  02 00 03 00 1a 00 43 05  1a 00 43 05 04 00 00 00  |......C...C.....|
00000020  eb 0c b4 09 ba 41 01 cd  21 c3 20 00 01 00 b2 05  |.....A..!. .....|
00000030  b9 3b 00 43 05 cd 80 2c  04 cd 80 74 72 69 63 6b  |.;.C...,...trick|
00000040  00 74 72 65 61 74 24 eb  d9                       |.treat$..|
00000049
```

NASM source:

```
ORG 0x05430000

BITS 32                                         ;
                                                ;   ELF HEADER    --   PROGRAM HEADER
; ELF HEADER                                    ; +-------------+
DB 0x7f,'E','L','F'                             ; | magic       |    +--------------------+
                                                ; |             |    |                    |
; PROGRAM HEADERS                               ; |             |    |                    |
DD 1                                            ; |*class 32b   | -- | type: PT_LOAD      |
                                                ; |*data none   |    |                    |
                                                ; |*version 0   |    |                    |
                                                ; |*ABI SysV    |    |                    |
DD 0x01a        ; offset = vaddr & (PAGE_SIZE-1); |*ABI vers    | -- | offset             |
                                                ; |             |    |                    |
entry:  DD 0x0543001a                           ; |*PADx7       | -- | vaddr = 0x0543001a |
DW 2                                            ; | ET_EXEC     | -- |*paddr LO           |
DW 3                                            ; | EM_386      | -- |*paddr HI           |
DD 0x0543001a                                   ; |*version     | -- | filesz             |
;       inc     ebx     ; STDOUT_FILENO         ; |             |    |                    |
;       mov     eax, 4  ; SYS_WRITE             ; |             |    |                    |
DD 0x0543001a                                   ; | entry point | -- | memsz              |
DD 4                                            ; | ph offset   | -- | flags: RX          |
                                                ; |             |    |                    |
        jmp     short skip                      ; |*sh offset   | -- |*align              |
BITS 16                                         ; |             |    |                    |
treat:  mov     ah, 9                           ; |             | -- |                    |
        mov     dx, trick + 0x100 + 6           ; |*flags ______|    |                    |
        int     0x21                            ; |______/      |    +--------------------+
        ret                                     ; |*ehsize      |
BITS 32                                         ; |             |
DW 32                                           ; | phentsize   |
DW 1                                            ; | phnum       |
skip:                                           ; |             |
        mov     dl, 5   ; strlen("trick")       ; |*shentsize   |
        mov     ecx, trick                      ; |*shnum       |
                                                ; |*shstrndx    |
                                                ; +-------------+
        int     0x80
        sub     al, 4   ; SYS_EXIT
        int     0x80


trick:  DB      "trick/treat$"

BITS 16
        jmp     short treat
```

This uses the fact that the ELF header starts with 7F 45, which, interpreted as x86 code, is a jump.

The relevant parts for the DOS .COM:

```
-u100 l2
07D2:0100 7F45          JG      0147
-u147 l2
07D2:0147 EBD9          JMP     0122
-u122 l8
07D2:0122 B409          MOV     AH,09
07D2:0124 BA4101        MOV     DX,0141
07D2:0127 CD21          INT     21
07D2:0129 C3            RET
-d141 l6
07D2:0140     74 72 65 61 74 24   -                           treat$
```

Comment: Bravo, sir. Bravo.

Comment: My heart skipped a beat.

Comment: http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html is a good read for anyone interested in the header overlap trick here.

Comment: This is one of the finest answers i've ever seen on this site. Codegolf a little too often turns into esoteric languages purpose-built for golfing, rather than clever answers. This is beautiful.

Comment: This is great stuff.

Answer (score 105):

## [evil](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Evil) / [ZOMBIE](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/zombie.html), 109 bytes

Another spooky answer !

```
xf is a vampire summon task f say "trick" stumble say "jzuueeueeawuuwzaeeaeeaeawuuuuwzuueeueeaw" animate bind
```

The `ZOMBIE` code defines a `vampire` named `xf` whose only task `f` is activated at instanciation and will output `trick` once before being deactivated by `stumble`. The other `say` call is dead code (how appropriate !) for `ZOMBIE`, but contains most of the `evil` code.

For `evil`, the `xf` name is a call to jump to the next `j`, which precedes the `zuueeueeawuuwzaeeaeeaeawuuuuwzuueeueeaw` zombie moan that crafts and output `treat`. The code following is either executed (lowercase letters) or ignored but since there's no `w` no output should be produced.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks, I enjoyed this occasion to get into some less-known esoteric languages :)

Comment: Well, from the four you've used I have seen Agony a few times before, and I vaguely remember to have seen ZOMBIE once. Never heard of HashHell or evil before, though. :)

Comment: the Halloween theming of this is impressive! I'd never even heard of those two languages

Answer (score 96):

### Python / Perl, 28 bytes

```pl
print([]and"trick"or"treat")
```

### Explanation

Since `[]` is an ArrayRef in Perl, it's truthy, but it's an empty array in Python, therefore falsy.

Comment: Similarly, `print({}and"trick"or"treat")` in Python / Lua.

Comment: @user200783 That would have the same effect in Perl as well, since `{}` is a HashRef!

Comment: Is also almost identical for Python / Ruby, but requires an extra whitespace: `print ([]and"trick"or"treat")`

Comment: Love it!  This is a great commentary on what implicit conversion-to-bool does to readability.

Comment: This could be a polyglot in Lua, Perl, and Python if it were `print({}and"trick"or"treat")`!

Answer (score 47):

### PHP / JavaScript, <s>32</s> 30 bytes

Displays `trick` in PHP and `treat` in JS.

```
NaN?die(trick):alert('treat');
```

The unknown `NaN` constant is implicitly converted to a string by PHP, making it truthy. It's falsy in JS.

#### Alternative method, 38 bytes

```
(1?0:1?0:1)?die(trick):alert('treat');
```

The ternary operator is right-associative in JS:

```
                1 ? 0 : 1 ? 0 : 1
 is parsed as:  1 ? 0 : (1 ? 0 : 1)
 which equals:  0
```

And left-associative in PHP:

```
                1 ? 0 : 1 ? 0 : 1
 is parsed as:  (1 ? 0 : 1) ? 0 : 1
 which equals:  1
```

Comment: You're right, my bad

Comment: alert() is JavaScript in HTML, though, not JavaScript from the console.

Comment: Alternative method: '\0'=="\0"?die(trick):alert('treat');`.

Comment: Debugging chained ternary operators in PHP must be so much fun.

Comment: @Robert Debugging *anything* in PHP is so much fun.

Answer (score 39):

## HTML / HTML+JavaScript, 53 bytes

```
treat<script>document.body.innerHTML='trick'</script>
```

`treat` is the document´s text content in HTML.
If JS is enabled, it will replace the HTML content with `trick`.

Comment: Interesting solution. I like it

Comment: You should use `document.write()` instead. -8 bytes

Comment: @darrylyeo `document.write` would not replace the HTML output but append to it.

Comment: Tested in Chrome. Fully works. Turning javascript on and off changes the content on refresh.

Comment: @Tatarize: Tested in Firefox 49, Opera 41, Safari 5.0, Chrome 54, Edge 38 on Windows, Firefox 5.3 and Safari 5.0 on iOS, Firefox 49 and Dolphin 11.5 on Android. **Only Firefox on Windows replaces; all others append.**

Answer (score 33):

## C / Java 7, <s>165</s> <s>155</s> <s>128</s> <s>123</s> <s>122</s> <s>120</s> 103 bytes

```
//\
class a{public static void main(String[] s){System.out.print("treat"/*
main(){{puts("trick"/**/);}}
```

//\ makes the next line also a comment in C but is a regular one line comment in Java, so you can make C ignore code meant for Java and by adding /* in the second line you can make a comment for Java that is parsed as code by C.

Edit:
I improved it a little bit by reorganizing the lines and comments.

Edit2:
I did some more reorganizing and shortened it even more.

Edit3:
I added corrections suggested by BrainStone to remove 5 bytes, thanks :)

Edit4:
One newline turned out to be unnecessary so I removed it.

Edit5:
I changed printf to puts.

Edit6:
I added a correction suggested by Ray Hamel.

Comment: You can safe 1 byte by changing C to C++ and replacing ``#include<stdio.h>`` with ``#include<cstdio>``. Not much but a byte is a byte. And additionally removing ``int `` infront of ``main`` will safe 4 bytes. ``int`` is implied by C and C++

Comment: Thanks, I modified the code according to your suggestions :)

Comment: Nice! I had a hard time coming up with something for Java, and ended up with [Java 7 + Whitespace myself](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97507/52210). Btw, you can golf one more byte by removing the space at `String[]s`.

Answer (score 29):

## Jolf + Chaîne, 12 bytes

Because Chaîne cannot accept a file to upload with an encoding, I assume UTF-8. (If I could assume ISO-8859-7, this would be 11 bytes, but that would be unfair.)

```
trick«treat
```

In Chaîne, `«` begins a comment, and the rest is printed verbatim. In Jolf, `«` begins a string. Thankfully, `trick` does nothing harmful (`10; range(input, parseInt(input))` basically), and `treat` is printed.

[Try Jolf here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=dHJpY2vCq3RyZWF0)

[Try Chaîne here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Cha-ne/?code%3Dtrick%C2%ABtreat%7C%7Cinput%3D)

They both work on my browser (firefox, latest version), but the same cannot be said for other browsers.

Comment: I suppose being the inventory of many obscure languages has it's benefits...

Comment: Nice to see that we are getting close to soloutions pretty much only consiting out of the words themself. I wonder if anyone can reuse the `tr`.

Comment: @BrainStone I personally doubt that `tr` could be reused in any golf--it's a small piece of information that would take _at least_ an operator to encode in golfing languages, then a language specific conditional. It would probably even out to either the same length, or longer. However, that's just my conjecture ;)

Comment: Let's find out. But I have to agree. A byte count of 10 or less would be insane!

Comment: @BrainStone, 8 bytes: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97580/5011

Comment: @SeanC I'm sure he's aware :P

Comment: @SeanC I'm very well aware of this and was seriously blown away by it!

Answer (score 28):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix/) / [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 31 bytes

```
t;./e;_a]"kcirt">o?@;=v=./r;\;/
```

[Trick it out!](http://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=dDsuL2U7X2FdImtjaXJ0Ij5vP0A7PXY9Li9yO1w7Lw==) [Treat it online!](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=dDsuL2U7X2FdImtjaXJ0Ij5vP0A7PXY9Li9yO1w7Lw&input=)

*Halloween themed*? Note the horrifying facts about these languages and the code:

1. If and even if you do nothing (just put no-ops), you can *never* get out of the loop that is determined to be running forever...
2. And being stuck in the middle of a 3D and a 2D programming language (Oh agony...)
3. Inside the dimensions, you'll gradually lost where you are... where you were...
4. And there is a `=v=` smiling at you which acts at no-ops in the code

Let's dig into the mystery of the hidden 31-bytes communication protocol of dimensions and terror...

### trick

When the code folds or unfolds itself... That is `cubified`, the layout looks like this:

```
      t ; .
      / e ;
      _ a ]
" k c i r t " > o ? @ ;
= v = . / r ; \ ; / . .
. . . . . . . . . . . .
      . . .
      . . .
      . . .
```

And the main part is this part in the middle:

```
" k c i r t " > o ? @ .
. . . . . . . \ ; / . .
```

It pushes `k,c,i,r,t` onto the stack and `o` outputs and `;` pops within a loop bounded by reflectors and `?` which guides you depending on the value on the top of the stack...

### treat

All of a sudden, the code transforms from a cube to a Hexagon. (Imagine that)

```
   t ; . /
  e ; _ a ] 
 " k c i r t 
" > o ? @ ; = 
 v = . / r ;
  \ ; / . .
   . . . .
```

And the main part is this part:

```
   t ; . /
  e ; _ a ] 
 . . . . . . 
. . . . @ ; = 
 . . . / r ;
  . . . . .
   . . . .
```

It runs `t;` which prints `t` and hits the mirror and turns its direction to NW starting from the SE corner and hits another mirror.  This runs `r;` and wraps to `e;_a` and the `]` brings it to the Instruction Pointer 1 which starts at corner NE pointing SE and hits `/` which reflects horizontally to `;` then `t`.

Then it wraps to `=`, `;`, and `@` ends the mess.

So... What is `_` doing there?

*Why* is it inside the `t` `e` `a` (the first 3 letters in the code)?

Here comes the end of the story -

it does *nothing*.

<strike>Does it sound like the end of a horror story?</strike>

Comment: Nice, very nice! It's difficult to create a polyglot out of two 2D languages. I like the horror story that goes along with it ;)

Comment: Not sure if this or ELF/.COM answer is more impressive. Good job!

Answer (score 27):

## [#hell](http://esolangs.org/wiki/HashHell) / [Agony](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Agony), 43 bytes

So much `><>` everywhere, what is this, an April Fools challenge? Here's an answer with appropriately themed languages.

```
--<.<.<.<.<.$
io.write("trick")--+<~}~@+{+<
```

`#hell` is a subset of `LUA` which fortunately accepts `io.write` output calls. We use `LUA`'s `--` comments so that it only executes this fragment.

`Agony` is a `Brainfuck` derivative, which has the particularity to have its code and working memory on the same tape. The first line only prints 5 characters (10 cells) from the end of the code segment, where I encoded `treat` as `Agony` commands. `LUA`'s comment opening `--` modifies the value of a cell which isn't used.

Comment: I have to say your Halloween themed ones are the best imho. Very creative!

Comment: @BrainStone Thanks, I had fun making them !

Answer (score 24):

### SQL / Javascript, 54 bytes

```
select('trick')
--a;function select(){alert("treat")}
```

Same approach as with my [QB/JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97472/trick-or-treat-polyglot/97509#97509): First line has the SQL statement, the second line has a 'comment' for SQL and a NOP for JS. Then, we define SQL's `select` statement as a valid JS function.

Comment: That is a very smart way of combining these two languages. Have a +1!

Answer (score 23):

## /Brainf..k/, 143 + 3 = 146 bytes

This answer requires the `-A` flag to output in ASCII for Brain-Flak and luckily Brainfuck doesn't care about that flag so it doesn't affect the output in Brainfuck.

```
(((((()(()()()){})({}){}){}){})+++++++[<+++<(((()()()())((((({}){}){}){}){}()))[][][][]())>>-])<[<++++>-]<.--.---------.------.>++[<++++>-]<.>>
```

[Try it Online!](http://brain-flak.tryitonline.net/#code=KCgoKCgoKSgoKSgpKCkpe30pKHt9KXt9KXt9KXt9KSsrKysrKytbPCsrKzwoKCgoKSgpKCkoKSkoKCgoKHt9KXt9KXt9KXt9KXt9KCkpKVtdW11bXVtdKCkpPj4tXSk8WzwrKysrPi1dPC4tLS4tLS0tLS0tLS0uLS0tLS0tLj4rK1s8KysrKz4tXTwuPj4&args=LUE)

[Try it Online!](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=KCgoKCgoKSgoKSgpKCkpe30pKHt9KXt9KXt9KXt9KSsrKysrKytbPCsrKzwoKCgoKSgpKCkoKSkoKCgoKHt9KXt9KXt9KXt9KXt9KCkpKVtdW11bXVtdKCkpPj4tXSk8WzwrKysrPi1dPC4tLS4tLS0tLS0tLS0uLS0tLS0tLj4rK1s8KysrKz4tXTwuPj4&args=LUE)

### How this works

The only overlap between the syntax of Brain-Flak and Brainfuck are the characters `<>[]`.  For brain-flak this mostly means the program has to ensure an even number of stack switches `<>`. And for Brainfuck this means we need to avoid infinite loops caused by use of the `[]` monad.

The Brain-Flak code is as follows:

```
(((((()(()()()){})({}){}){}){})[<<(((()()()())((((({}){}){}){}){}()))[][][][]())>>])<[<>]<>[<>]<>>
```

Aside from the `[<<...>>]` bit in the middle and the `<[<>]<>[<>]<>>` at the end this code is pretty par for the course as far as Brain-Flak programs go.  The negative around the zero (`[<...>]`) is there to create a loop for Brainfuck.  The inner `<...>` is used to move the Brainfuck to an empty cell before it encounters the `[][][][]` which would loop infinitely otherwise.

The Brainfuck code is as follows:

```
+++++++[<+++<[][][][]>>-]<[<++++>-]<.--.---------.------.>++[<++++>-]<.>>
```

Aside from the aforementioned bits this is also a pretty standard program so I will spare you the details.

Comment: I like this one :D

Comment: There are a *LOT* more than two languages that match the regex `/brainf..k/`, so you should use the same header format as everyone else.

Comment: @mbomb007 the only other language I could find that fits this regex is [brainfork](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfork).   Conveniently when run in brainfork this prints "TRICK" so I will leave the regex for the time being.

Comment: `For brain-flak this mostly means the program has to ensure an even number of stack switches` Are you sure about that? It shouldn't matter since `<>` is a NOP in brainfuck

Comment: @DJMcMayhem it has to end on the same stack we put everything otherwise it won't print anything.

Answer (score 22):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish) / [Fishing](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fishing), 38 bytes

```
_"kcirt"ooooo;
[+vCCCCCCCC
   `treat`N
```

For the sake of making a `><>` / `Fishing` polyglot.

It's my first piece of `Fishing` code after having played for a long time with `><>`.
My first impression : as in nature, the fisherman has less physical capabilities than its pray but makes up for it with its tool !

Here the code is extremely simple : `><>` will only execute the first line, where `_` is a vertical mirror and has no effect since the fish starts swimming horizontally. It just pushes `trick` on the stack then print it before stopping.
For `Fishing`, the `_` instructs to go down. The fisherman will follow the deck that is the second line while catching the characters of the third line. These will push `treat` on the tape then print it, stopping as it reaches the end of the deck.

If erroring out is allowed, you could go down to 35 bytes with the following code which will throw an error when run as `><>` once the `trick` is printed off the stack :

```
_"kcirt">o<
[+vCCCCCCCC
   `treat`N
```

---

You should also check my themed languages answers, [#hell / Agony](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97472/trick-or-treat-polyglot/97533#97533) and [evil / ZOMBIE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97472/trick-or-treat-polyglot/97542#97542) !

Comment: Aw, I wanted to make a fish/fishing polyglot :) You beat me to it. Nice one!

Comment: +1 for "_as in nature, the fisherman has less physical capabilities than its pray but makes up for it with its tool !_"

Answer (score 20):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E)/[Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 10 bytes

```
"trick"’®Â
```

**Explanation**

**05AB1E**

```
"trick"     # push the string "trick"
       ’®Â  # push the string "treat"
            # implicitly print top of stack (treat)
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=InRyaWNrIuKAmcKuw4I&input=)

**Actually**

```
"trick"     # push the string "trick"
       ’®Â  # not recognized commands (ignored)
            # implicit print (trick)
```

[Try it online](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=InRyaWNrIuKAmcKuw4I&input=)

Comment: You know, I can clearly read the `trick`, but how is `’®Â` treat?..

Comment: Now people have known this feature. Next time we'll get questions such as "*hQq3k or bvM;p polyglot*"...

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: ’®Â is translated as "take the word with index 3757 from the dictionary", which is "treat".

Comment: @Emigna Ok... So all ~1.1M English words are accessible in 05AB1E?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: No, there are 10k in total (each representable as 2 characters). You can find the whole list [here](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/dictionary.py).

Comment: @Emigna Ah ok. I learn something new every day. :) I guess it's always loaded into memory, or is there some sort of automatic `import/using` system in 05AB1E, so it only adds the dictionary to the memory if it needs it? Not that 76.6kb for a dictionary list is anything at all to load into memory; I'm just curious how it works.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: It is loaded with the interpreter so it's always in memory, but as you say it's so small it doesn't matter.

Comment: This doesn't work. Either you have to use UTF-8 as the encoding, or you have to use the corresponding characters for CP437 from Windows-1252 (which gives [`"trick"Æ«┬`](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=InRyaWNrIsOGwqvilKw&input=)).

Answer (score 16):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) / [Standard ML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_ML), 56 bytes

```haskell
fun putStr x=print"treat";val main=();main=putStr"trick"
```

**Haskell view**

The semicolons allow multiple declarations in one line and act like linebreaks, so we get

```haskell
fun putStr x=print"treat"
val main=()
main=putStr"trick"
```

A Haskell program is executed by calling the `main` function, so in the last row `putStr"trick"` is executed which just prints `trick`.
The first two rows are interpreted as function declarations following the pattern `<functionName> <argumentName1> ... <argumentNameN> = <functionBody>`. So in the first row a function named `fun` is declared which takes two arguments named `putStr` and `x` and the function body `print"treat"`. This is a valid Haskell function with type `fun :: t -> t1 -> IO ()`, meaning it takes an argument of an arbitrary type `t` and a second one of some type `t1` an then returns an IO-action. The types `t` and `t1` don't matter as the arguments aren't used in the function body. The IO-action type results from `print"treat"`, which prints `"treat"` to StdOut (notice the `"`, that's why `putStr` instead of `print` is used in `main`). However as it's only a function declaration, nothing is actually printed as `fun` is not called in `main`.
The same happens in the second line `val main=();`, a function `val` is declared which takes an arbitrary argument named `main` and returns *unit*, the empty tuple `()`. It's type is `val :: t -> ()` (Both the value and the type of *unit* are denoted with `()`).

[Try it on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/MYQF7C)

---

**Standard ML view**

[Standard ML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_ML) is a primarily functional language with a syntax related to, but not the same as Haskell. In particular, function declarations are prefixed with the keyword `fun` if they take any arguments, and the keyword `val` if they don't. Also it's possible to have an expression at top level (meaning not inside any declaration) which is executed when the program is run. (In Haskell writing `1+2` outside a declaration throws a `naked expression at top level`-error). Finally the symbol for testing equality is `=` instead of `==` in Haskell. (There are many more differences, but those are the only ones that matter for this program.)
So SML sees two declarations

```haskell
fun putStr x=print"treat";
val main=();
```

followed by an expression

```haskell
main=putStr"trick"
```

which is then evaluated. To determine whether `main` equals `putStr"trick"`, both sides have to be evaluated and both must have the same type, as SML (as well as Haskell) is statically typed.
Let us first have a look at the right side: `putStr` is not a library function in SML, but we declared a function named `putStr` in the line `fun putStr x=print"treat";` - it takes an argument `x` (this is the string `"trick"` in our case) and immediately forgets it again, as it does not occur in the function body. Then the body `print"treat"` is executed which prints `treat` (without enclosing `"`, SML's `print` is different from Haskell's `print`).
`print` has the type `string -> unit`, so `putStr` has the type `a -> unit` and therefore `putStr"trick"` has just type `unit`. In order to be well-typed, `main` must have type `unit` too. The value for *unit* is in SML the same as in Haskell `()`, so we declare `val main=();` and everything is well-typed.

[Try it on codingground.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_smlnj_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMUVp1b0JYWWRRNmc)
Note: The output in the console is

```haskell
val putStr = fn : 'a -> unit                                   
val main = () : unit                                                    
treatval it = true : bool
```

because in [SML\NJ](http://smlnj.org/) the value and type of every statement is displayed after each declaration. So first the types of `putStr` and `main` are shown, then the expressions gets evaluated causing `treat` to be printed, then the value of the expression (`true` as both sides  of `=` are `()`) is bound to the implicit result variable `it` which is then also displayed.

Comment: I always thought `fun ... ... =` was syntactic sugar for `val rec ... = fn ... =>`. But then again it's been decades since I used ML.

Comment: @Neil You're right, `fun` is syntactic sugar for anonymous function bound with `val` (`rec` is only needed if the function is recursive) and therefore the formulation "must be prefixed" is badly chosen, I'll edit the answer. In general using `fun` is best-practice, especially in code golf as it's much shorter.

Answer (score 15):

### QBasic / JavaScript, <s>51</s> 44 bytes

```
'';PRINT=a=>{alert("Treat")}
PRINT("Trick")
```

In QBasic, it prints the second line and doesn't execute the first line because it's believed to be a comment (thank you '). In JS, it calls the function PRINT, which is defined on the first line, right after the JS NOP `'';`.

Comment: A very clever approach!

Answer (score 15):

## Ruby / C, <del>64</del> <del>62</del> <del>51</del> 48 bytes

```
#define tap main()
tap{puts(0?"trick":"treat");}
```

#### What Ruby sees:

```
tap{puts(0?"trick":"treat");}
```

The `tap` method takes a block and executes it once. It's a short identifier that we can create a `#define` macro for in C. It also allows us to put a braces-enclosed block in the shared code, even though Ruby doesn't allow `{}`s in most contexts.

The only falsy values in Ruby are `false` and `nil`. In particular, 0 is truthy. Thus, Ruby will print "trick."

#### What C sees (after the pre-processor):

```
main(){puts(0?"trick":"treat");}
```

0 is falsy in C, so C will print "treat."

2 bytes saved thanks to daniero.

Comment: Nice. You can use `puts` instead of `printf` to save two bytes

Comment: Thanks! I'm so used to just always using `printf` in C, I've forgotten that it also has a `puts` function.

Comment: Two ideas: Can't you use something shorter for ``tap``? And why didn't you get rid of the spaces? ``p ? "trick":"treat"`` => ``p?"trick":"treat"``

Comment: `tap` actually serves two purposes. It's a short identifier for `#define` to latch onto, but it also allows me to put the braces directly in the Ruby code. `{}` blocks in Ruby don't work like they do in C and similar languages, but `tap` _does_ take a block, and executes it once.

Comment: Method names in Ruby can end with a question mark, so a space is needed after `p`. `?<character>` is a character literal, so a space is needed after the `?`.

Comment: @m-chrzan Ok. I'm not familiar with Ruby. But still a nice solution.

Answer (score 15):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly) / [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

```
0000000: FE 22 74 52 69 63 6B 22 3F 37 29 FB ED 35                ."tRick"?7)..5
```

A fun one using Jelly's string compression.

**Jelly: treat**

```
“"tRick"?7)»ḣ5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9RwxylkqDM5Gwle3PNQ7sf7lhs@v8/AA)

**05AB1E: trick**

```
þ"tRick"?7)ûí5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8D6lkqDM5Gwle3PNw7sPrzX9/x8A)

**How it works**

In Jelly `“"tRick"?7)»` is a compressed string that returns `'Treatment dormy/ Orly awry'`. `ḣ5` takes the first five characters, printing `Treat`

In 05AB1E `þ` doesn't affect the program. `"tRick"` is a literal string. `?` prints this string then the rest of the program (`7)ûí5`) doesn't have any effect either.

I used [this](https://tio.run/##Dc9nV5JhGAfwr2I0bS@zrbazbXsPs0Jp27B1bh4RUbMBVKhADEVRVDYP03OuPw@dk@fchz6C1xd54t3v7a@zw2Tq0XVjMysRuFqX8kM1sDmp6zoLt6G7zdjeZWhqrKf8khps0P94/tplTMZlQiZlSqZlRqp11XhVrRaqxX@KdEindMmsDMowD/jYNsi2YbZ5WTGzorDSy4qFlT5WrHXLDMtXrFy1ek392nXrN2zctHnL1m3bG3Y07ty1e8/effubmlsOHDx0@MjRY8dbT5w8dfrM2XNt5y9cvHT5ytVr12/cvHX7zt177fc7Hjx8ZOzsMj1@8vTZ8xcvu1@9fvO25937Dx8/VVK1hhxjMVqxs/CyCLHwsfAvWllEtZqymr1s1YqVdFmwcLEYqW1ZeFgEWDhYOBfdbAlofhY5zVHu10qaWjaTnwIUpHGaoBBN0hSFaZpmKCLzNEfzFKUYxSlBSUpRmjKkUpZylKcCFalECxAwQ0EvLOiDFf2wYQCDGMJnDOMLvuIbvsMOB5z4gZ/4BRdGMIoxuOGBF7/hgx8BBDGOCYQwiSmEMY0ZRDCLOcwjihjiSCCJFNLIQEUWOeRRQBElLPwH) to convert from Jelly's code page to 05AB1E's code page. [This](https://tio.run/##DdHnUlNRGEbhW8FYsTfEDtjFjr0XBA3EjgXb7BxCCCCWJGqAJKZAIBAgPSeVme/NiTMysydegt@NHPPv@btmdXWYTL26bmxmJcLm5L/8cA1wteq6jpKhp83Y3m1oaqxHHnMN@m/PH7uMybhMyKRMybTMSLWuGq@q1UK1@FeRDumULpmVQRnmQR/bhtg2wjYvK2ZWFFb6WLGw0s@KtW6ZYfmKlatWr6lfu279ho2bNm/Zum17w47Gnbt279m7b39Tc8uBg4cOHzl67HjriZOnTp85e67t/IWLly5fuXrt@o2bt27fuXuv/X5H54OHxq5u06PHT54@e/6i5@Wr12963757/@FjJVWLkOMsxip2Fl4WIRY@Fv4lK4uoVlNWs5etWrGSLgsWLhajLNwsPCwCLBwsnEtutgQ0P4uc5igPaCVNLZvJTwEK0gRNUoimaJrCNEOzFJF5mqcFilKM4pSgJKUoTRlSKUs5ylOBilSiRQiYoaAPFvTDigHYMIghDOMTRvAZX/AV32CHA058xw/8hAujGMM43PDAi1/wwY8AgpjAJEKYwjTCmMEsIpjDPBYQRQxxJJBECmlkoCKLXG1bAUWUsPgf) does the reverse in case anyone is interested.

Jelly code page is [here](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page).

05AB1E code page is [here](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage).

Comment: First answer that actually uses the rule that arbitrary capitalization is acceptable! I like it

Comment: @BrainStone Thanks! I think it's also one of the few (or maybe only) answer that uses the same core code in each language to produce the words 'trick' and 'treat'. In most other answers those are separate

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 14):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL) / [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 17 bytes

```
'TRICK'%];"TREAT"
```

In MATL this [outputs](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=J1RSSUNLJyVdOyJUUkVBVCI&input=) `TRICK`. In CJam it [outputs](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=J1RSSUNLJyVdOyJUUkVBVCI&input=) `TREAT`.

### Explanation

#### MATL

```
'TRICK'         Push this string
%];"TREAT"      Comment: ignored
                Implicit display
```

#### CJam

```
'T              Push character 'T'
R               Push variable R, predefined to empty string
I               Push variable I, predefined to 18
C               Push variable C, predefined to 12
K               Push variable K, predefined to 20
'%              Push character '%'
]               Concatenate stack into an array
;               Discard
"TREAT"         Push this string
                Implicit display
```

Comment: You're missing 3 characters there! (EAT)

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon Thanks! Edited

Comment: Now you are missing three in the MATL explanation!

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon Aww. Thanks again :-D

Answer (score 14):

## [ShapeScript](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/shapescript) / [Foo](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Foo), 13 bytes

```
'trick'"treat
```

**Try it online!** [trick](http://shapescript.tryitonline.net/#code=J3RyaWNrJyJ0cmVhdA&input=) | [treat](http://foo.tryitonline.net/#code=J3RyaWNrJyJ0cmVhdA&input=)

#### How it works

ShapeScript is parsed character by character. When EOF is hit without encountering a closing quote, nothing is ever pushed on the stack. `'trick'` does push the string inside the quotes, which is printed to STDOUT implicitly.

Foo doesn't have any commands assigned to the characters is `'trick'`, so that part is silently ignored. It does, however, print anything between double quotes immediately to STDOUT, even if the closing quote is missing.

Answer (score 14):

### Ruby / Perl, 21 bytes

```pl
print"trick"%1||treat
```

#### Perl

Calculates `"trick" % 1` which is `0 % 1` so the `||` sends `treat` to `print` instead, since Perl accepts barewords.

#### Ruby

Formats the string `"trick"` with the argument `1`, which results in `"trick"` which is truthy, so the `||` isn't processed.

Answer (score 13):

## Objective-C / C, 50 bytes

```c
puts(){printf("trick");}main(){printf("treat\n");}
```

Objective-C got candy and [prints treat](http://ideone.com/Hdt3fO), but C didn't and [prints trick](http://ideone.com/eRC6M2).

#### How it works

I don't know a lot about **Objective-C**, but it does what we'd reasonably expect in this situation. The re-definition of `puts` doesn't affect the output since we never call the function, and `main` prints **treat** and a linefeed to STDOUT.

You might expect **C** to do the same, but at least gcc 4.8, gcc 5.3, and clang 3.7 don't.

Since we do not need the *real* **printf** (which takes a format string and additional arguments) and the string to be printed ends with a linefeed, we can use **puts** instead. **puts** is slightly faster than **printf** (which has to analyze its arguments before printing), so unless we redefine the function **printf** as well, the compiler optimizes and replaces the call to **printf** with a call to **puts**. Little does the compiler know that calling `puts` with argument `"treat"` will print **trick** instead!

Not including **stdio.h** is crucial here, since defining **puts** would require using the same type it has in the header file (`puts(const char*)`).

Finally, it is noteworthy that the call to **printf** in **puts** passes a string *without* a trailing linefeed. Otherwise, the compiler would "optimize" that call as well, resulting in a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 12):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly) / [pl](http://github.com/quartata/pl-lang), 12 bytes

```
0000000: 74 72 65 61 74 0a 7f fe 00 ba 49 fb                 treat.....I.
```

This is the program displayed using [Jelly's code page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page).

```
treatµ
“¡ṾI»
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=dHJlYXTCtQrigJzCoeG5vknCuw&input=)

This is the program displayed using [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#Characters).

```
treat
⌂■␀║I√
```

[Try it online!](http://pl.tryitonline.net/#code=dHJlYXQK4oyC4pag4pCA4pWRSeKImg&input=)

Both programs have been tested locally with the same 12 byte file, so this is a proper polyglot.

#### How it works

In Jelly, every line defines a *link* (function); the last line defines the *main link*, which is executed automatically when the program is run. Unless the code before the last `7f` byte (the linefeed in Jelly's code page) contain a parser error (which would abort execution immediately), they are simply ignored. The last line, `“¡ṾI»` simply indexes into Jelly's dictionary to fetch the word **trick**, which is printed implicitly at the end of the program.

I don't know much about pl, but it appears that the interpreter only fetches one line of code and ignores everything that comes after it. As in Perl, barewords are treated as strings, so `treat` prints exactly that.

Answer (score 10):

### Batch/sh, 30 bytes

```
:;echo Treat;exit
@echo Trick
```

Explanation. Batch sees the first line as a label, which it ignores, and executes the second line, which prints Trick. The @ suppresses Batch's default echoing of the command to stdout. (Labels are never echoed.) Meanwhile sh sees the following:

```
:
echo Treat
exit
@echo Trick
```

The first line does nothing (it's an alias of `true`), the second line prints Treat, and the third line exits the script, so the @echo Trick is never reached.

Answer (score 10):

## sed / Hexagony 32 bytes

```
/$/ctrick
#$@$a</;r;e;/t;....\t;
```

---

## sed

[Try it Online!](http://sed.tryitonline.net/#code=LyQvY3RyaWNrCiMkQCRhPC87cjtlOy90Oy4uLi5cdDs&input=)

The first line prints `trick` if there is an empty string at the end of input. (sed doesn't do anything if there isn't input, but a blank line on stdin is allowed in this case)

**Example run:**

```
$ echo | sed -f TrickOrTreat.sed
trick
```

---

## Hexagony

[Try it Online!](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=LyQvY3RyaWNrCiMkQCRhPC87cjtlOy90Oy4uLi5cdDs&input=)

The first `/` redirects the instruction pointer up and the the left, so it wraps the the bottom left, skipping the text used for sed. It reuses the r from the sed code and runs a few others to no effect. The expanded hex looks like this:

```
   / $ / c 
  t r i c k
 # $ @ $ a <
/ ; r ; e ; /
 t ; . . . . 
  \ t ; . .
   . . . .
```

**Output:**

```
treat
```

Comment: I've seen Hexagony posts that have pictures of the execution path, is there an easy to generate those?

Comment: Here it is https://github.com/Timwi/HexagonyColorer

Comment: Your Hexagony code prints a leading null byte. Not sure if that counts as whitespace for the purposes of this challenge.

Comment: @MartinEnder Sounds like it's allowed. Thanks for pointing that out, I always miss those for some reason...

Comment: I managed to fix that while also saving a few bytes (at the cost of printing an upper case `A`, although you could make that less ugly by changing all letters to upper case): http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=LyQvY3RyaWNrCiM7QUAkPC87cjtlOy90&input=

Comment: @MartinEnder This is my first time using Hexagony, so I didn't really look at the other pointers at all. This new one prints all lowercase without a null byte, but is a little longer.

Comment: @1000000000 How do you run that tool?

Answer (score 10):

## C# / Java

This probably doesn't qualify as it doesn't run on its own, but the challenge has reminded me of a quirk in how C# and Java handle string comparison differently that you can have some fun with for code obfuscation.

The following function is valid in C# and Java, but will return a different value...

```
public static String TrickOrTreat(){
    String m = "Oct";
    String d = "31";
    return m + d == "Oct31" ? "Trick" : "Treat";
}
```

Comment: Interesting quirk indeed.

Answer (score 10):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak) / Brain-Flueue, <s>265 253 219 165 139 115 113</s> 101 bytes

Includes +1 for `-A`

Thanks to Wheat Wizard for going back and forth, golfing a few bytes off each others code, with me.

```
((((()()()))([]((({}{}))({}([((({}()())))]([](({}{}){}){}{})))[]))[])[()()])({}()()){}({})({}[][]){}
```

Brain-Flak: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#NYoxDoBQCEOvQ4d/CM9BGL6DifHHwZVwdiwYgaY0ryk1qAVEjcHDg7@HaKePwZo27KsS1FpaHcNfppFSaoQemTm2HGt/5nkfa14v)
Brain-Flueue: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#NYpBCsBACAO/sznsI/oO8dDCFgpLD4U9iW@30VI1xDCJloNcoIkymJvzN29S6WPQogXrsgTRkmRH8ZdppJQooXlE9C36PJ79us@5xhov)

**Explanation:**
The first section lists the values that Brain-Flak sees.
When it switches to Brain-Flueue, I start listing the values as Brain-Flueue sees them.

```
# Brain-Flak
(
 (((()()()))             # Push 3 twice
  ([]                    # Use the height to evaluate to 2
   (
    (({}{}))             # Use both 3s to push 6 twice
    ({}                  # Use one of those 6s to evaluate to 6
     ([((({}()())))]     # Use the other 6 to push 8 three times and evaluate to -8
      ([](({}{}){}){}{}) # Use all three 8s to push 75
     )                   # The -8 makes this push 67
    )                    # The 6 makes this push 73
   [])                   # Use the height and the 6 to push 82
  )                      # Use the 2 to push 84

# Brain-flueue
 [])     # Use the height and 3 to push 84
[()()])  # Push 82
({}()()) # 67 is at the front of the queue, so use that to push 69
{}       # Pop one from the queue
({})     # 65 is next on the queue so move to the end
({}[][]) # 74 is next, so use that and the height to push 84
{}       # Pop that last value from TRICK
```

Comment: [A little competition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116996/56656)

Answer (score 9):

## Python / Pyth, <s>24</s> 22 bytes

*Thanks to @Loovjo and @Pietu1998 for some help*

```
#"treat"
print"trick";
```

In Pyth, this [outputs](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%23%22treat%22%0Aprint%22trick%22%3B&debug=0) `treat`. In Python, this [outputs](http://ideone.com/yPFLaM) `trick`.

**How it works**

**Python**

```
#"treat"       Comment
print"trick";  Print the string literal "trick"
```

**Pyth**

```
#"treat"     
#              Loop until error statement
 "treat"       Implicitly print the string literal "treat"
print"trick";  Throws an error since n has no right operand, breaking out of the loop
               The last ";" is a valid EOF
```

Comment: Couldn't you replace the `.q` with something that gives an error (e.g. `K`)? Edit: you can remove the `.q` all together as Pyth will try to run the second line and fail

Comment: To add to @Loovjo's comment, `n` fails as it has no second operand.

Answer (score 9):

### PowerShell / Foo, 14 bytes

```
'trick'#"treat
```

The `'trick'` in PowerShell creates a string and leaves it on the pipeline. The `#` begins a comment, so the program completes and the implicit `Write-Output` prints `trick`.

In Foo, [(Try it Online!)](http://foo.tryitonline.net/#code=J3RyaWNrJyMidHJlYXQ&input=), the `'trick'` is ignored, the `#` causes the program to sleep for `0` seconds (since there's nothing at the array's pointer), then `"treat` starts a string. Since EOF is reached, there's an implicit `"` to close the string, and that's printed to stdout.

Comment: Also works in J / Foo.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Is the explanation the same? I've never used J and I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: No, this doesn't work in J. `#` is the copy function, and it only takes non-negative complex left arguments, not strings. The comment symbol is `NB.`

Comment: @Adám right you are. Forgot the `#`

Answer (score 9):

## PHP/Perl, 28 bytes

```
print defined&x?trick:treat;
```

`defined&x`
gives something truthy in PHP (no idea why, but it does).
In Perl it checks if function `x` is defined - which is not.
--> `trick` in PHP, `treat` in Perl.

Comment: @jmathews Have you tried putting a [backspace control character](https://sbjh.wordpress.com/2013/02/08/generate-any-control-character/) into your windows version? What about `CLS`?

Comment: `\`` is the truthy value of defined&x or d&x ask me not which d you get

Answer (score 9):

## /// / Javascript, <s>32</s> 26 bytes

```js
/*//trick/*/alert("treat")
```

Try it online! [Slashes](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=LyovL3RyaWNrLyovYWxlcnQoInRyZWF0Iik&input=) | [Javascript](https://repl.it/EGr4/1)

*-6 bytes thanks to BrainStone*

**Explanation:**

- **///**

  ```
  /*//                        Replace * with nothing
     trick                    Print "trick"
          /*/alert("treat")   This is the start of a replacement,
                              but the third slash is missing,
                              so it doesn't do anything.
  ```
- **Javascript**

  ```
  /*                          Start of multiline comment
    //trick/                  Comment
            */                End of multiline comment
              alert("treat")  Print "treat"
  ```

Comment: You can replace `console.log` with `alert` to save some bytes.

Comment: Wow, that second - incomplete - `/` statement is very nice! I tried the same, but came to `/*\/alert('treat')/trick/*/alert('treat')` because I was unaware of this behaviour and tried to do a complete replace.

Answer (score 8):

## [Labyrinth](http://github.com/mbuettner/labyrinth)/[><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>32</s> 30 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to *Martin Ender*

```
v84.82."73.67.75.@
\"TAERT"
>o
```

**Explanation**

**Labyrinth (TRICK)**

The numbers represent ascii values of the letters in "TRICK"
`.` prints the ascii codes as bytes and `@` exists the labyrinth.

[Try it online](http://labyrinth.tryitonline.net/#code=djg0LjgyLiI3My42Ny43NS5AClwiVEFFUlQiCj5v&input=)

**><> (TREAT)**

Moves down and right and pushes the letters of "TAERT" to the stack.
Then loops to the beginning of the line, moves down and right.
Prints everything on the stack with `o`.

```
v
\"TAERT"
>o
```

[Try it online](http://fish.tryitonline.net/#code=djg0LjgyLiI3My42Ny43NS5AClwiVEFFUlQiCj5v&input=)

Answer (score 7):

## [Befunge-98](http://quadium.net/funge/spec98.html)/[><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 24 bytes

*Thanks to @ninjalj for reminding me about `k` which saved 2 bytes.*

```
"trick"rooooo@,k4"trea"
```

You can try [><> here](https://fishlanguage.com/playground) and [Befunge-98 here](http://misc.pietu1998.net/jsfunge-98/befunge98.html).

Befunge-98 pushes the characters `trick`, reverses direction, pushes `kcirt` and `aert`, prints the five characters on top of stack and quits.

><> pushes the characters `trick`, reverses the *stack*, prints the five characters on top of stack and errors out for no operands for `@`.

Comment: You can skip the `;` if you error out in fish.

Answer (score 7):

### Perl / Perl 6, 41 bytes

I don't believe they count as two versions of the same language; rather, I'll consider them different languages.

```
my @a="ick";my $a="eat";print "tr$a[0]\n"
```

#### Explanation

This code relies on differences in sigil declension.

Perl: `$a[0]` means get the first element of `@a`, which happens to be a scalar.

Perl6: `$a[0]` means get the first element of `$a`. If we wanted the first element of `@a`, we could use `@a[0]` instead.

Comment: I'm not a Perl expert, but can you use barewords and drop the quotes from `ick` and `eat`? Also, is `my` necessary?

Comment: The quotes and `my` are necessary in Perl 6, but not in Perl 5.

Answer (score 7):

## Python/Javascript (interpreters), <s>36</s> 27 bytes

```
["Trick","Treat"][+(1/2>0)]
```

**Explanation**

`1/2>0` will return `False` in Python, but `true` in JS.

Both languages use + to convert the boolean expression to an integer (+False is 0, +True is 1)

So, Python will evaluate the expression:

```
["Trick","Treat"][+False]
```

And Javascript will evaluate:

```
["Trick","Treat"][+true]
```

Python will return "Trick", Javascript will return "Treat"!

Thanks for @daHugLenny for 9 bytes saved :-)

Comment: You can replace `1e100==10**100` with `1/2>0` (if you're using Python 2)

Comment: @daHugLenny Cool, thanks :) I'll improve the solution!

Answer (score 6):

## [FOG](https://github.com/RikerW/Fuzzy-Octo-Guacamole/) / [Jolf](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Jolf), <s>16</s> 14 bytes

```
"trick"X"treat
```

Jolf prints the `"treat` at the end (doesn't need the matched quote), `X` does nothing in this case (it's JS eval on the input, which there is none), and the "trick" just makes a string that isn't used.

In FOG, the `"trick"` pushes `trick` to the stack, and the `X` prints it. The unmatched quote on the end of `"treat` exits with an error.

**Old Code:**

```
a"trick""treat"X
```

Simple. In Jolf, `a` means print the string after it and disables auto-output. (not really the last part, but yes in this situation)

The other 2 commands are ignored pretty much. (`X` uses JS eval on the input (I think), and `"treat"` also gets a string ready to use in a function. No function is used though, so these don't do anything.)

In FOG, `X` prints the most recent item on the stack. `a` adds the top 2 elements on the stack (`0` and `0`, gives `0`), and `"trick""treat"` pushes `trick` and then `treat`, and the `X` prints the top one.

Comment: What is FOG? I have not heard of that language.

Comment: @ETHproductions [FOG](https://github.com/RikerW/Fuzzy-Octo-Guacamole/), or Fuzzy Octo Guacamole, is his language.

Comment: Actually, `X` is eval'd input. Subtle difference.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien eh, close enough. Will edit with links also.

Answer (score 6):

## [Dip](https://github.com/mcparadip/Dip)/[05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 15 bytes

```
"trick"q"treat"
```

Prints `treat` in Dip and `trick` in 05AB1E.

Comment: My brain read the header as "Disposable." :P

Answer (score 6):

> ### Clip and Wake, 15 bytes

### 15 bytes

Guess what the two languages are.

```
"trick":"treat"
```

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, PHP  - 30 bytes

**Code**

```
print["trick","treat"][""==0];
```

**Explanation**

`""==0` is evaluated to `true` in PHP, `false` in Python, so Python will print the first element from list (index `0`, equal to false), PHP will print the second item (index `1`, equal to true).

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E)/[2sable](http://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable), 13 bytes

```
žQ„®Â „ÐË 1@=
```

[Try it online! (2sable)](http://2sable.tryitonline.net/#code=xb5R4oCewq7DgiDigJ7DkMOLIDFAPQ&input=),
[Try it online! (05ab1e)](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=xb5R4oCewq7DgiDigJ7DkMOLIDFAPQ&input=)

#### Explanations:

**05ab1e**:

```
žQ                Push list of printable ascii characters
  „®Â             Push dictionary compressed string "treat"
      „ÐË         Push dictionary compressed string "trick"
                  STACK: *ascii*, treat, trick
          1@=     Print second item on stack (treat)
```

**2sable**:

```
žQ                Not a command (ignored)
  „®Â             Push dictionary compressed string "treat"
      „ÐË         Push dictionary compressed string "trick"
                  STACK: treat, trick
          1@=     Print second item on stack (trick)
```

Answer (score 6):

## Japt / GolfScript, 15 bytes

```
"trick""treat";
```

**Japt** implicitly prints the last string literal, `"treat"`, the first string `"trick"` is basically ignored.

**GolfScript** pushes both strings to the stack and then the semicolon `;` pops `"treat"` and thus only `"trick"` remains on the stack which is printed at the end.

Comment: Thanks for using Japt :-) `trick` and `treat` can each be represented as a 3-byte compressed string ([here's how](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=InRyaWNrIj09YMmOa2A7CiJ0cmVhdCI9PWDJhHRgOw==&input=)), so I wonder if that can help you save any bytes.

Comment: @ETHproductions Wow, didn't know Japt could do that. Honestly, only found out about the language in the writing of this entry xD

Answer (score 5):

## Scala / CSS, 64 bytes

```
/*\u002A/ print("trick")//*/
/*/**/
*:after {content:'treat';}*/
```

Try it: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wkm2ak68/) [ideone](https://ideone.com/2bTCHh) (warning: wrong syntax highlighting)

Scala, like java, evaluates unicode escapes (`\u002A`, asterisk) before anything else, so scalac parses the code like

```
/**/                          //block comment
print("trick")                //code
//*/                          //eol-comment
/*                            //scala supports nested block comments, so this comment...
  /*
  */
  p:after {content:'treat';}
*/                            //...ends here
```

The CSS is parsed like this:

```
/*hello\u002A/ print("trick")//*/  //block comment
/*                                 //a block comment 
  /*                                 //with a slash and an asterisk
*/                                 //ending here
p:after {content:'treat';}         //code
*/                                 //invalid css syntax, jsfiddle silently ignores this
```

Comment: Are you sure if the CSS is valid if you need the HTML?

Comment: @SolomonUcko Most browsers imply `<html></html>` tags, and `*` matches every element, including `html`.

Comment: Good point. I just got confused when you changed it to a `p` tag in the explanation

Answer (score 5):

## VBA/Windows Batch, 21 Bytes

```
?"trick"'||echo.treat
```

For VBA, use the immediate window.  ? is print, ' makes the remainder of the line a comment
For Windows Batch, the || is an OR and makes the second bit run even if the first errors

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first post!

Answer (score 5):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/) / [Stuck](https://github.com/kade-robertson/stuck), <s>19</s> 17 Bytes

Stuck makes a comeback!

```
"trick"e#"treat"p
```

CJam will print `trick`, and Stuck will print `treat`! Here's an explanation in both languages.

**CJam:**

```
"trick"            e# pushes the strings "trick" to the stack
       e#"treat"p  e# the e# comments everything else out, stack implicitly prints
```

**Stuck:** <sup>*note that Stuck does not have comments so you can't run the below*</sup>

```
"trick"e#"treat"    | pushes the values "trick", e^2, "treat" to the stack
                p   | prints the top stack value
```

---

**Old Versions:**

19 Bytes: `"tr""ick""eat";e#yy`

Answer (score 5):

## TI-Basic / BF, 49 bytes

Pretty straightforward. The advantage is that it works with both your computer and your calculator :)

```
"-[--->+<]>-.--.---------.------.++++++++.
"TREAT
```

Answer (score 5):

## Bash / [Retina](http://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 16 bytes

```
echo trick||
treat
```

**Try it online!** [trick](http://ideone.com/A3XsbT) | [treat](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=ZWNobyB0cmlja3x8CnRyZWF0&input=)

#### How it works

Bash quite literally echoes trick or treat. Since the command `echo trick` successfully prints to STDOUT, the OR part isn't executed, so `treat` doesn't even generate a *command not found* error.

Retina begins with an empty space. Since there's an even amount of lines, it will perform a substituion. The regex `echo trick||` matches the string **echo trick**, the empty string, or the empty string, and replaces the match (the empty string) with **treat**.

Answer (score 5):

## C/C++, <s>76</s> 74 bytes

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){printf("tr%.3s\n",&"ickeat"[sizeof'a'-1]);}
```

Lots of C and C++ programmers react strongly when someone writes `C/C++` as if it was one language. This contribution is here both to trigger those who are allergic to that string and to demonstrate that they (or rather: we), in fact, are right. C and C++ are two different languages.

The explanation is simple. Character constants like `'a'` have different types in C and C++, so sizeof will return different sizes. This assumes a relatively normal machine where `sizeof int` is 4.

Comment: Note `sizeof'a'` works and saves you 2 bytes! In fact, I considered the prefix trick, and it actually costs more than it saves.

Comment: @BoBTFish Old habits of being careful die hard.

Comment: Didn't really go for golfing this, rather for obfuscation. `puts(sizeof'a'-1?"treat":"trick")` is shorter, but it's boring.

Answer (score 5):

### Triple glot: ///, SQL and JavaScript, 63 bytes

```
/*//trick/\*/select('or')
--a;function select(){alert('treat')}
```

Using my SQL/Javascript answer, and @daHugLenny 's excellent ///-Javascript post, I was able to make a piece of code run across three languages:

**///**

```
/*//trick/../..   Simply prints 'trick', does no replaces, stops execution because the second /// block is incomplete
```

**SQL**

```
/*//trick/\*/     //trick/\ is seen as a block comment
                  That last \ was added to set apart the following */, completing the block
select('or')      SQL Select statement, yielding 'or'
--a;...           Seen by SQL as a comment, ignored
```

**Javascript**

```
/*//trick/\*/     //trick/\ is seen as a block comment
select('or')      Function call to the function 'select', defined below
--a;              Decrement a, effectively a NOP
function select(){alert('treat')}
                  Defines the function select(), giving us 'treat'
```

Answer (score 5):

## gcc C/Python 3, <s>76</s> 53 bytes

```
#define print(_)main(){puts("trick");}
print("treat")
```

Saved 23 bytes thanks to Dennis!

The gcc C preprocessor replaces the `print` macro (discarding it's argument) with a C program that prints "trick". And Python 3 ignores the first line as a comment and simply prints "treat".

Answer (score 5):

## reticular + Turtlèd, 16 bytes

```
"trick"oll"eat";
```

[Try reticular online!](http://reticular.tryitonline.net/#code=InRyaWNrIm9sbCJlYXQiOw&input=) [Try Turtlèd online!](http://turtled.tryitonline.net/#code=InRyaWNrIm9sbCJlYXQiOw&input=)

reticular explanation:

```
"trick"oll"eat";
"trick"           push the string "trick" to the stack
       o          output it
        l         push length of stack (0)
         l        push length of stack (1)
          "eat"   push the string "eat" to the stack
               ;  terminate
```

Turtlèd explanation:

```
"trick"oll"eat";
"trick"           write "trick" to the grid, move turtle to the "k"
       o          idk, probably no-op
        ll        move turtle left two, to the "i"
          "eat"   write "eat" to the grid
               ;  something
```

Answer (score 5):

## VBA/R 16 bytes

```
    ?"trick";'treat'
```

VBA shows trick and R shows treat, can be reverse.

### Explanation

In VBA/R, ";" can be used for ending.

In VBA, single quotation start the comment and anything after that is ignore.

In R, "?" go to look for documentation, single/double quotation can be used for words.

Answer (score 5):

## Befunge/Whitespace, 113 chars

Probably not going to win on shortness, but at least, I had fun ! 
[Here is the hastebin](http://hastebin.com/raw/vazavubido)

```
"taert">:#,_@                     .
 .
         .
         .
        .
   .
            .
         .
        .
   .
             .
         .
        .
   .
           .
        .
        .
    .
  .
.
```

I have put dots to make sure SE show it well

[Try the befunge online !](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=InRhZXJ0Ij46IyxfQCAgIAkJCSAJICAKIAogICAgCSAKCSAgCSAKCQkKICAgCiAgICAJICAJCgkgIAkgCgkJCiAgIAogICAgCQkgCgkgIAkgCgkJCiAgIAogICAgCSAgIAoJICAgIAoJCQogIAkKICA&input=)

[Try the whitespace online !](http://whitespace.tryitonline.net/#code=InRhZXJ0Ij46IyxfQCAgIAkJCSAJICAKIAogICAgCSAKCSAgCSAKCQkKICAgCiAgICAJICAJCgkgIAkgCgkJCiAgIAogICAgCQkgCgkgIAkgCgkJCiAgIAogICAgCSAgIAoJICAgIAoJCQogIAkKICA&input=)

Comment: [113 bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#%22taert%22%3E%3A%23%2C%5f%40%20%20%20%09%09%09%20%09%20%20%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%09%20%0A%09%20%20%09%20%0A%09%09%0A%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%09%20%20%09%0A%09%20%20%09%20%0A%09%09%0A%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09%20%0A%09%20%20%09%20%0A%09%09%0A%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%09%20%20%20%0A%09%20%20%20%20%0A%09%09%0A%20%20%09%0A%20%20) unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Yep, I had put an extra linefeed when couting. Thanks

Comment: In case you want to add them, here are permalinks for [Befunge](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=InRhZXJ0Ij46IyxfQCAgIAkJCSAJICAKIAogICAgCSAKCSAgCSAKCQkKICAgCiAgICAJICAJCgkgIAkgCgkJCiAgIAogICAgCQkgCgkgIAkgCgkJCiAgIAogICAgCSAgIAoJICAgIAoJCQogIAkKICA&input=) and [Whitespace](http://whitespace.tryitonline.net/#code=InRhZXJ0Ij46IyxfQCAgIAkJCSAJICAKIAogICAgCSAKCSAgCSAKCQkKICAgCiAgICAJICAJCgkgIAkgCgkJCiAgIAogICAgCQkgCgkgIAkgCgkJCiAgIAogICAgCSAgIAoJICAgIAoJCQogIAkKICA&input=).

Comment: @Dennis Added them. Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak)/[Brain-Flueue](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>136</s> <s>124</s> <s>120</s> 108 + 1 = 109 bytes

*+1 byte for the `-A` to cause character output*

```
((((()()()))([]((({}{}))({}([((({}()())))]([](({}{}){}){}{})))[]))[])[()()])(({}()())<{}{}>[[]]())({}[][]){}
```

[Try it online! Brain-Flueue](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#PYxNCoBACEavo4u5QQSdQ75FwQTB0CKYlXh2U4P8AT/eQ6cszmYmQQQ1tbjVSCp9jFG0YE1KLKiVdMC/vSReRQCqT4KQ1Ny9bd7G8ezXfY7ZZ38B)

[Try it online! Brain-Flak](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#PYw7CoBADESvkxR7AxE8xzDFWgjiYmEbcva4iWA@kOE9EpKl2aoCzmBuPm9zQaWPKYsWrElJwVqkQ/3tJfEKkFKfwCmZR0Tboo396ed9jH69)

This is a non-trivial modification of [Riley's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116898/56656), which he has since golfed down even further than I have.  I recommend you check out if you have not already.

Answer (score 4):

## [Turtlèd](http://github.com/Destructible-Watermelon/Turtl-d), Python, 23 bytes

```
"Treat";print('Trick' )
```

Produces Treat in Turtlèd, Trick in Python

probably also produces "Treat" in foo

Explanation:

### [Turtlèd](http://turtled.tryitonline.net/#code=IlRyZWF0IjtwcmludCgnVHJpY2snICk&input=)

```
"Treat"                  Write Treat
       ;                 Move down by register amount. nop as register is 0
        print            Nops and move right
             ('          if current cell is ' (it will not be)
               Trick'    Nops, move right, write a space
                      )  End if
    [implicit print grid]
```

### Python

(I can't ideone right now)

```
"Treat";                   comment
        print('Trick' )    print "Trick" to output
```

Answer (score 4):

## Clojure + Common Lisp, <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```
(print(if '()"trick"'treat))
```

Clojure version on ideone: https://ideone.com/3xIhpb

Common Lisp: https://ideone.com/N3qzIW

In Common Lisp `nil` is the same as `'()` and thus `'()` evaluates to `false` whereas in Clojure empty list is not `nil` and thus is `true`. I hope its being not a full program but a snippet(?) is fine for the challenge.

Comment: If it runs on Ideone without any additional code required, in both languages, I'd say that qualifies as a full program for our purposes. +1 from me.

Answer (score 4):

## [LiveScript](http://livescript.net) + JavaScript ES6, 29 bytes

```
alert(/.*/=='trick'||'treat')
```

In LiveScript comparing a regular expression with a string literal return an array with the matches of the expression in the string. In JavaScript it only returns true the string representation of both are the same. `alert` will convert it's input to string, displaying `['trick']` as just `trick`.

Comment: `'tr'+(/.*/=='ick'||'eat')` is just 25 bytes, but seems it's not allowed as it isn't neither a function or a full program.

Comment: And `/.*/=='trick'||'treat'` is 22 ;)

Answer (score 4):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////)/[D1ffe7e45e](https://esolangs.org/wiki/D1ffe7e45e), 59 bytes

See what I did there?

```
/@//TREAT
/37333120813633633333333363333336222222226//
/$/__/
```

Basically, in D1ffe7e45e / begins and ends comments. So, `TREAT` is in a comment but the source that prints `TRICK` isn't. The `__` is two no-ops to stop the D1ffe7e45e program from repeating. The source that /// interprets should be self-explanatory.

Comment: Well those comments disappeared o_O

Comment: I don't think this works again. the `/@/__/` is changed to `//__/`, so it doesn't halt

Comment: (replace the first or second @ with something else)

Comment: Yeah makes sense, this is my first time with this language ^_^

Answer (score 4):

## /// / FEU, 24 bytes

```
/ /
p/trick/
end
a/treat
```

Try it online! [Slashes](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=LyAvCnAvdHJpY2svCmVuZAphL3RyZWF0&input=) | [FEU](http://feu.tryitonline.net/#code=LyAvCnAvdHJpY2svCmVuZAphL3RyZWF0&input=)

**Explanation**

- **///**

  ```
  / /       Replace space with "\n...
  p/trick/  ...p". Print "trick". Replace "\n...
  end       ...end\n...
  a/treat   ...a", third slash is missing so it doesn't do anything.
  ```
- **FEU**

  ```
  / /       Execute the next block for each strings matched by " "
  p/trick/  Prepend "trick"
  end       End block
  a/treat   Append "treat"
  ```

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, Lua 41 Bytes

PHP print trick an Lua treat

```
--$a;echo"trick";/*
print("treat")
--*/
```

Comment: You don't need the 2nd `$a;`. That is inside comment in both languages.

Comment: You can join the 2nd and 3rd lines. And better check your count as currently I see there only 39 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## Python and Lua, 29 bytes

This solution is posted separately from but in addition to my other solution due to the use of a different set of languages and a much more competitive byte count.

The 29th byte is the newline at the end. In Python, the empty string `''` is considered a falsey value, while in Lua, it's considered true. In Lua, the `or` is short-circuited by `''and'trick'` evaluating to a true value and printing, while in Python the `and` short-circuits due to `''` and prints the true value on the other side of the or.

```
print(''and'trick'or'treat')
```

Comment: Do you need to count the newline at the end?

Comment: I don't know. Python's interpreter occasionally throws a fit when you omit it, but only with occasional syntactic oddities.

Answer (score 4):

## VBScript, JScript, 41 bytes

`x="treat"
rem=x="trick"
WScript.echo(x)`

The VBScript "rem" hides the JScript code.

Answer (score 4):

## CJam / HTML, <s>17</s> 14 bytes

Edit:

- ***-3*** bytes off. Thanks to @ETHProductions

Code:

```
TREAT<"trick"
```

## HTML:

```
TREAT<;"trick"
TREAT           print TREAT
     <          tag open: ignore rest since there is no closing bracket
```

## CJam:

```
TREAT<;"trick"
TREAT<         e#random stuff / push vars
      ;        e#discard stack
       "trick" e#literal trick
               e#implictly print
```

Comment: I think HTML is not considered a programming language.

Comment: I think you can remove the `!--`.

Comment: @FliiFe Lets say it's PHP. Would work too.

Comment: @FliiFe you're allowed to use non-programming-languages in constant output challenges.

Answer (score 4):

### Perl / Ruby : 41 bytes

```
#line 9
print __LINE__==2?"treat":"trick"
```

Lines beginning with `#` are comments in both Ruby and Perl. Except that lines following (roughly) the regex `#\s*line\s+\d+` are executed by Perl's compiler and change the line number as the compiler sees it (see the doc : [Plain Old Comments (Not!)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Plain-Old-Comments-(Not!))).

So when arriving to the second line, Perl thinks it the 9th while Ruby thinks it's the second. Hence Ruby will print `treat` while Perl will print `trick`.

Comment: I did not know that was possible! Good to know... Shame it's not global: `perl -E'eval"#line 9\nsay __LINE__";say __LINE__'`

Comment: @DomHastings I learned about it only a few days ago (I was bored so I went through the doc and found this :D ). Indeed, it would've been nice..

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3 / JavaScript, 46 bytes

There weren't any "true" Python/JavaScript polyglot answers yet, so I figured I'd try my hand at writing one:

```
a=1//2;alert=print
alert(["trick","treat"][a])
```

#### Python 3

This is how Python sees the code:

```python
a=1//2;alert=print
alert(["trick","treat"][a])
```

`//` is integer division in Python 3, so `a=1//2;` sets variable `a` to `0`. Then `alert=print` sets the variable `alert` to the function `print` so that we can use `alert` to output.

In the next line, `alert` is called on the item at index `a` in the array `["trick","treat"]`. Since `a` is `0` and `alert` is `print`, this prints `"trick"`.

#### JavaScript

This is how JS sees the code:

```js
a=1//2;alert=print
alert(["trick","treat"][a])
```

The first line is parsed as `a=1`; the rest is simply a comment. This sets variable `a` to `1`.

The second line, much like in Python, `alert`s the item at index `a` in `["trick","treat"]`. Since `a` is `1`, this alerts `"treat"`.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6) / [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>47</s> <s>33</s> 22 bytes

```
1
alert`trick`;"treat"
```

#### JavaScript

This should be fairly obvious: `1` and `"treat"` do nothing, and `` alert`trick` `` alerts `trick`.

#### [Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=MQphbGVydGB0cmlja2A7InRyZWF0Ig==&input=)

In Japt, lowercase letters (except those in strings) transpile to method calls, e.g. `.a(`. However, if it comes after another lowercase letter, it is instead transpiled to `"a"`. All open parentheses are cut off at semicolons `;`. This means that the code roughly transpiles to:

```
1 .a("l".e("r".t("trick")));"treat"
```

This is then evaluated as JavaScript. `"r".t("trick")` is `"r`", `"l".e("r")` is `"l"`, and `1.a("l")` is `1`. However, the poor JS engine's work is pointless: only the result of the last expression is sent to STDOUT, so the `1` is discarded and `treat` is printed.

Answer (score 4):

## Shakespeare Programming Language / Befunge-98, 467

```
"kcirt"4k,@.Puck,.Page,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Enter Page and Puck]Page:You is the sum of a big big big big big big cat and the sum of a big big big big cat and a big big cat.Speak thy mind!You is the sum of you and a big pig.Speak thy mind!Puck:You is the sum of me and the sum of a big big big pig and the sum of a big big pig and a pig.Speak thy mind!You is the sum of you and a big big pig.Speak thy mind!Page:You is the sum of you and a big cat.Speak thy mind![Exeunt]
```

Try it online: [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://tio.run/##hZA9D4MgEIb/ytXZMHVysoNDNxOnxjhc8WoJBY1CUn89hSamX2gHErh7H@7JTcPNuURyMZpkL9OclZbLlJXYUcoO3MAxYxUnTeFSF9rQCKEJqFsI2Sa8slNvQUxgrgSTVdBfAOEsuujhaJ70ZngJ4XuFVQOh9OAMSuh29zt19pUXNojuGwnKEVtF20r@p/XA0sTYwH@Oa57xrX6ykZXUxZ2sNo1zDw) / [Befunge-98](https://tio.run/##hZA9D4IwEIb/ysmMnRyUSQcGNxMmQxiOctSmoRBoE/n1lZoQvwoOTdq79@k9uZJqqwVtD3vnIsVlb6Kdio/sYrmK2QUFxezEDZwTlnHS5C95qg314JuAugKfLfwrubYW5ADmRjDYBtoaEEopgoejedKr4TmE7xWWdYRqAkdopK42v1PHqfLCOim@Ea8csG1oXWn6aTkwNzE08J/jkmd4q59sYCV5eierTeHcAw)

Befunge-98 prints `trick`, Shakespeare prints `TREAT`.

**Explaination**

Befunge executes until the `@`, so the SPL program is ignored. In SPL, everything until the first dot is ignored because it's the title.

**Edit:** port the answer to the official SPL interpreter - I couldn't get it to work before.

Answer (score 4):

## [Emoji](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Emoji)/[Emojicode](http://www.emojicode.org/), 50 bytes

```
trick➡
treat
```

[Try Emoji online!](https://tio.run/##S83Nz8r8///D/IlbPsyftKakKDM5G8R4NG8h14f5/Y0f5ve2f5g/o@HD/ClLSopSE0tADKBg5///AA)
[Try Emojicode online!](https://tio.run/##S83Nz8pMzk9J/f//w/yJWz7Mn7SmpCgzORvEeDRvIdeH@f2NH@b3tn@YP6Phw/wpS0qKUhNLQAygYOf//wA)

Answer (score 4):

## Julia/Python, 31 Bytes

Nothing special, just taking advantage of the similarities between the languages. Julia uses 1 as the first index, while Python uses 0.

```
l=["trick","treat"]
print(l[1])
```

[Try it online - Julia!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0/f8/xzZaqaQoMzlbSQdIpyaWKMVyFRRl5pVo5EQbxmr@/w8A)

[Try it online - Python!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P8c2WqmkKDM5W0kHSKcmlijFchUUZeaVaOREG8Zq/v8PAA)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Unless Julia does something I don't know, you can remove the extra spaces in the first line: `list=["trick","treat"]` and you can also rename `list` `l` to save some more bytes

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, nice first golf! And you still haven't removed the space after `,` as far as I can tell.

Comment: Forgot about that one! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8 / Whitespace, <s>169</s> <s>145</s> <s>142</s> <s>141</s> 125 bytes

The `N`s are only added so the code has the correct indentations, which represent newlines for the Whitespace part of the program (see explanation below for the spaces and tabs used).

```
interface M{static void main(String[]a){System.out.print("TREAT");}}N
           N
         N
            N
        N
N
  N
                N
        N
  N
 N
N
```

[Try it here : Whitespace (outputs *TRICK*)](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/PzOvJLUoDchU8K0uLkksyUxWKMvPTFHITczM0wguKcrMS4@OTdSsDq4sLknN1csvLdErAAqWaCiFBLk6hihpWtfWcikocHIqKChAaCAJpDjBFBBxcSkowNhAcS6QQk6wGBfX//8A)
[Try it here : Java 8 (outputs *TREAT*)](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNL0jNy0rJ/v8/M68ktSgtMTlVwbe6uCSxJDNZoSw/M0UhNzEzTyO4pCgzLz06NlGzOriyuCQ1Vy@/tESvAChYoqEUEuTqGKKkaV1by6WgwMmpoKAAoYEkkOIEU0DExaWgAGMDxblACjnBYlxc//8DAA)

#### Explanation:

**Java**:
The Java part is pretty straight-forward. It's a full program with mandatory `main`-method, which prints `TREAT` to STDOUT. All (leading and) trailing spaces, tabs and newlines are ignored.

**Whitespace:**
Whitespace uses spaces, tabs and new-lines as its source-code, ignoring everything else. Here is the same code with the spaces replaced with `S`, tabs replaced with `T`, and new-lines appended with `N` for better readability:

```
SSSN                          # Push 0    (K)
SSTTSSSN                      # Push -8   (C)
SSTTSSN                       # Push -2   (I)
SSSTTTN                       # Push 7    (R)
SSSTSSTN                      # Push 9    (T)
NSSN                          # Create Label LOOP
 SSSTSSTSTTN                  #  Push 75
 TSSS                         #  Add the top two values on the stack together
 TNSS                         #  Pop and output as character with this codepoint
 NSNN                         #  Jump to Label LOOP
```

Instead of printing directly, pushing the lowered values in reverse to the stack, and then adding a constant in a loop before printing saves 16 bytes. I've used this approach in a lot of other Whitespace programs of mine, and it can also be found in [this Whitespace tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158232/52210). The constant `75` is generated by [this Java program](https://tio.run/##fVJNb9swDL33VxA8SVBqZMCKYXaEoh12MLbsUGcfQFsMsqsm6hzZk@gAwZDf7sm1nY9u6EWC@B6fSD4@qY06f3r41bZFqbyHuTL2zxlA3eSlKcCTonBtKvMA6wCxjJyxy9t7ULyjAfQBcNo3JYEEdTu9T54RYwn8WpWl9h2QWtJL7aL51Y@f364@f/04gVS@u0iOVUb6zaiG2OOPlWOdnpFpYmZvLqaJEWKo4FCDRJzQpJZjVp@Xb0lDHvcVRktN1yHgGd@nA5AM4ovq@8oEpFaFvjZWuW2vy/Jzw5M910lGkf7dqNKzml9i9uXOZhgTF@5AqiWNj91wm0fmolLbJa0Yh9m@16My/mn/SPFokgeZA5yGuDn9sj@zrSe9jqqGojp0Q6Vl2KdLFKOowCSMFkUqEGJA8do0Uj58@1KZnZb/zNqdhWNYosGl17Q7i@0wkI1ywRfMMhTMzqaXuMAYM@SnC1HE415RdSLVoXyuaBWp3DPL@f@cJyGL2dv3wcSgvRi2pp@b09Q4GxgY/MW@l13btoub9MOnvw), which I've created for previous challenges.

Comment: You should be able to work the java code in. Would save some bytes

Comment: @BrainStone Good point, I've changed it for -24 bytes. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## Scala / Javascript, 33 bytes

```
if(0==false)"trick"; else "treat"
```

`0==false` returns true in javascript, but false in scala

Answer (score 3):

## Befunge-98/DOS .COM file, 27 bytes

```
00000000  22 20 b4 09 ba 0b 01 cd  21 c3 20 74 72 65 61 74  |" ......!. treat|
00000010  24 6b 63 69 72 74 22 34  6b 2c 40                 |$kcirt"4k,@|
0000001b
```

The Befunge-98 part pushes the characters of a string to the stack, and then outputs the top 5 characters in the stack and ends.

The DOS part is:

```
00000000  2220              and ah,[bx+si]
00000002  B409              mov ah,0x9
00000004  BA0B01            mov dx,0x10b
00000007  CD21              int 0x21
00000009  C3                ret
```

Where the first instruction is just some dummy non important instruction, and the rest calls INT 21h function 09h, which prints a $-terminated string pointed to by DS:DX.

Answer (score 3):

### [Charcoal](http://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal) and [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 13 bytes

```
trick©"treat"
```

#### Charcoal

Charcoal's [code page](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki/Code-page) reads this as `trick»"treat"`. `trick` prints the string to the canvas. `»` closes a block; apparently, if it is unmatched, it ends the program. The canvas is then printed to the screen.

[Try it online](http://charcoal.tryitonline.net/#code=dHJpY2vCuyJ0cmVhdCI&input=)

#### Pip

```
t              Variable (no-op)
 r             Generate random number (and do nothing with it)
  i            Variable (no-op)
   c           Variable (no-op)
    k          Variable (no-op)
     ©         Unrecognized character, ignored
      "treat"  String, output implicitly
```

[Try it online](http://pip.tryitonline.net/#code=dHJpY2vCqSJ0cmVhdCI&input=)

Answer (score 3):

## C/Lua, 65 bytes

```
#include<stdio.h>/*
print"trick"--[[*/
main(){puts("treat");}//]]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously) and Python 2, 21 bytes

*thanks to quartata for this solution*

```py
print"trick"#X"treat"
```

Try it online: [Actually](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=cHJpbnQidHJpY2siI1gidHJlYXQi&input=), [Python 2](http://ideone.com/Wb145I)

### Explanations

Actually:

```
print"trick"#X"treat"
print                  5 NOPs (they only do things if the stack isn't empty)
     "trick"           push "trick"
            #          listify
             X         discard (stack is now empty)
              "treat"  push "treat"
                       (implicitly print)
```

Python 2:

```py
print"trick"#X"treat"
print"trick"           # print "trick"
            #X"treat"  # a comment
```

Comment: `print"trick"#X"treat"` is shorter but much more boring.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby / ECMA6 27 bytes

```
{'t':'trick'}['t']||'treat'
```

Turns out you don't need to assign a JSON object in oredr to use it in ecma6

Original, with plain Javascript:

## Ruby/Javscript <s>32</s> 31 bytes

```
a={'t':'trick'};a['t']||'treat'
```

Because ruby treats the key as as symbol (:t), does not match with 't' so goes to the or. Whereas JavaScript is not as fussy.

Comment: Cool trick! I'm not sure if this qualifies as a full program/function though :(.

Answer (score 3):

## Python/Brainf**k (87 Bytes)

```
print("treat")#+++++++++[>+++++++++<-]>+++.--.<+++[>---<-]>.<++[>---<-]>.<++++[>++<-]>.
```

Python ignores everything after the `#` because its a comment and brainf**k ignores `print("treat")#` because they are unrecognized characters.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth and SMBF, 28 bytes

```
"trick"<.q<.q<.q<.q<.q"taert
```

"trick" explanation:

> Pyth has a `quit`-type operation with `.q`, which I use at `<.q` to end the program. Everything afterwards is uninterpreted, but in order for me to fix arity I need to add arity 0 data after each arity-2 `<`.  Otherwise, the program requires user input (although what Python datum the input wouldn't matter, since it's not used).  Pyth will implicitly print the "trick" at the beginning of the program.

"treat" explanation:

> The only characters that SMBF uses are as follows (the others are no-ops or not examined in memory): `"<.<.<.<.<.taert`.  The `<.` sets print out the last five characters of the program in reverse order (hence `treat` is reversed into `taert` to have it print as `treat`).

Comment: I appreciate the game you've set up, but can you remove the spoiler from the title please? :)

Answer (score 3):

## Forth/Perl, 53 bytes

```
1 ?dup : print"trick" ." treat" ; print"trick" or bye
```

Needs a case-insensitive Forth (e.g: GNU Forth).

When run in Forth, it defines a `print"trick"` word that outputs "treat", then calls it.

When run in Perl, it uses the colon of Forth's word definition as part of a conditional statement. In `?dup`, the question mark forms part of the aforementioned conditional statement, and `dup` gets treated as a bareword (a string without quotes). The dot in Forth's `."` primitive gets interpreted as Perl's concatenation operator, and `bye` gets treated as another bareword.

Answer (score 3):

## C / C++, 73 bytes

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){puts("treat\0trick"+sizeof'1'/sizeof 1*6);}
```

This could fail (printing `trick` in both C and C++) on an implementation with `sizeof (int) == 1`, which implies `CHAR_BIT >= 16`. As far as I know there are no such implementations in the real world.

Changing `int main()` to `int main(void)` would make it theoretically more conforming in C, but in practice all C and C++ compilers accept `int main()`.

Comment: We don't really require portability here; as long as it works in *one* implementation that predates the challenge, it's valid. With gcc/g++ and the right OS/architecture, you can replace `include` with `import`, remove `int` and replace `sizeof 1*6` with `2*3`.

Answer (score 3):

## C / C++, 72 bytes

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){char*a[]={"trick","treat"};puts(a[1//**/2
]);}
```

Compile with `gcc/g++ -ansi` and don't regard warnings. A C90-conforming C compiler does not recognize `//` as a comment but it skips `/**/`, leaving `puts(a[1/2]);`. C++ will see `puts(a[1]);`.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash / Wolfram Language (a.k.a. Mathematica), 19 bytes

```
echo trick;#&@treat
```

For Bash, `#` is a comment indicator so it just outputs `trick`. Mathematica multiplies two undefined symbols `echo` and `trick` but ignores the result and proceeds to the second command, which fully expanded goes

```
(Function[Slot[1]])[treat]
```

and evaluates to `treat`.

Answer (score 3):

## C / Javascript, <s>70</s> 47 bytes

**(excluding comments C=22 + Javascript=14 ~= 36 )**

```
/**\
/main(){puts("trick");}
//*/alert("treat")
```

What C sees:

```
main(){puts("trick");}
```

What javascript sees:

```
alert("treat")
```

Explanation:

```
/* C comment ends with '/' on next line but js comment remains open  *\ 
/ //BEGIN C Block 
#define function int 
//*/alert("this whole line is commented in C, but // is in the js comment")

//for additional tricks...
/*Most compilers can build K&R style C with parameters like this:*/ 
function volume(x,y,z)/**\ 
/int x,y,z;/**/ 
{ 
  return x*y*z; 
} 

/**\ 
/ 
#undef function 
#define var const char** 
#define new (const char*[]) 
#define Array(...)  {__VA_ARGS__} 
/**/ 

var cars = new Array("Ford", "Chevy", "Dodge"); 

/* Or a more readable version *\ 
/// BEGIN C Block 
#undef var 
#undef new 
/* END C Block */
```

Answer (score 3):

## Windows Batch, JScript, 35 bytes

`trick="treat";WScript.
echo (trick)`

The batch version displays the parentheses as delimiters.

Comment: This outputs `(trick)` instead of `trick`.

Comment: yes, the batch version displays the parentheses as delimiters.

Comment: Actually, batch displays whatever you write after. In this case, it will show `(trick)`. If you wrote `"trick"`, it would show that.

Comment: but then it won't be valid JavaScript, which requires the parentheses to run the function.

Comment: Can you use backticks?

Comment: no, must be parentheses because I am targeting the console environment, not the web one.  Naming the environment should really be a rule - calling it JavaScript alone isn't sufficient to identify the execution environment.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I mixed Javascript (ES6) with JScript. Those are different. Sorry. Well, you did all you could with what you have. I will praise it.

Answer (score 3):

## Windows Batch, VBScript, 34 bytes

```
trick="treat":WScript._
echo trick
```

The Batch `echo` will display the immediate text.
The VBScript uses the "_" line-continuation to run the "echo" command, which displays the contents of the variable "trick", which contains the string "treat".
VBScript does not require parenthesis for functions which do not return a value.

Comment: Can you explain how this works ?

Comment: @FliiFe, updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby / Crystal, 31 bytes

`puts 'a'=="a"&&"trick"||"treat"`

`'a'` is a string literal in Ruby and a character literal in Crystal. `"a"` is a string literal in both. This abuses that difference to detect the language the script is ran in.

Answer (score 3):

## HTML/[Foo](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Foo), <s>19</s> <s>15</s> 12 bytes

```
trick<"treat
```

Displays `trick` in HTML and prints `treat` in Foo.

Answer (score 3):

## sh / csh, 32 bytes

```
echo trick #treat|sed 's/.*#//'
```

For csh, the command must be executed interactively.

Explanation: In interactive mode, sh treats anything starting with `#` as a comment. csh does so only in batch mode.

ksh and bash behave the same way as sh.  tcsh behaves like csh.  Some of these shells have options to alter this behavior.

zsh behaves like csh for this particular command.

Comment: bash has `interactive_comments` shopt` and zsh has `INTERACTIVE_COMMENTS` to control this behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

## HTML / JavaScript (ES6), 28 bytes

```
trick<alert`treat`;var trick
```

[**Test HTML**](https://jsfiddle.net/d6nqg24c/) | [**Test JS**](https://jsfiddle.net/d6nqg24c/1/)

### Explanation

HTML is a lot like ///: it writes out any plain text, ignoring anything after a `<` until it gets to a `>`. Since there are no `>`s, it just writes "trick".

JS is simple: `` alert`treat` ``. However, to avoid a ReferenceError for `trick` not being defined, we have to add a `var trick` to tell JS that `trick` is really supposed to be there.

I wanted to add CSS that "prints" `or`, but it seems to be impossible:

- If the CSS is before the `<`, it gets written to the HTML document.
- If the CSS is after the `<`, it finds a syntax error and stops before running.

Answer (score 3):

## Labyrinth/Perl, 38 bytes

As `cat -v`:

```
$_=116.114.105.99.107.$@^"^@^@^L^B^_";print
```

Where `^@` represents ASCII 0 (␀), `^B` represents ASCII 2 (␂), `^L` represents ASCII 12 (␌), and `^_` represents ASCII 31 (␟). Or, as a `hexdump -C`:

```
00000000  24 5f 3d 31 31 36 2e 31  31 34 2e 31 30 35 2e 39  |$_=116.114.105.9|
00000010  39 2e 31 30 37 2e 24 40  5e 22 00 00 0c 02 1f 22  |9.107.$@^"....."|
00000020  3b 70 72 69 6e 74                                 |;print|
00000026
```

I have wanted to post a Labyrinth/Perl answer since reading [Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47066/emigna)'s [Labyrinth/><> answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97513/267). In that answer, Labyrinth code looks very much like it starts with a Perl [version string](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Version-Strings).

So, in this answer, Labyrinth just does the following:

```
$_=                    → dummy operations
116.114.105.99.107.    → print string
$                      → dummy op
@                      → end
```

while Perl does:

```
$_=                    → set the $_ variable to:
 116.114.105.99.107    →  a version string for the other language
 .$@                   →  concatenated with $EVAL_ERROR (null when no eval error)
 ^"^@^@^L^B^_";        →  XORed with "\0\0\x0c\2\x1F", to get "treat" from "trick"
print                  → and finally print the string
```

---

## Labyrinth/Perl alternate version, 105 bytes

Here is another version, modifying the string in Labyrinth code, instead of in Perl code:

```
; $_=116.114.105.99.107.$@
; ;print;      1+ 7+ 16
; ;;;;;;;;;;;;; 1
;              ;;
;;;;;9^_9^10^00 ^a
```

Labyrinth code follows the path. The last line modifies the code, rotating columns using `^`. After the last line has been interpreted, the field looks like:

```
; $_=116.114.101.97.116.$@
; ;     ;       +  +      
; ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;1         
;               ;         
;;;;;9^_9^10^005^ 9  07
```

After finishing interpreting the last line, Labyrinth follows the path upwards. Then, the 1 makes it attempt to turn rightwards, but hitting the wall makes it turn leftwards instead. Afterwards, Labyrinth just follows the path, eventually reaching code already explained for the first approach (where Perl modifies the string).

As you'll notice,  (in `9^_9^10^00 ^ 1`) numbers in Perl can have `_` in them, to make them more readable.

---

## Labyrinth/Perl, linear labyrinth version, 76 bytes

Not as fun as the previous one, but does the trick (or treat, as it may be):

```
25^25^25^23^0;$;=116.114.105.99.107.$@
        ; print$    ;   ;  1+ 7+ 16
;
```

---

## Labyrinth/Perl, boring version, 49 bytes

Separate code paths for Labyrinth and Perl:

```
;print 116.114.105.99.107
;
116.114.101.97.116.$@
```

Answer (score 3):

**Haskell / Ruby, 74 bytes**

```
--0;True=false
main=if True then print "trick" else print "treat";--0;end
```

***Haskell***

Anything starting with `--` is treated as a comment. Actual program in Haskell is now just

```
main=if True then print "trick" else print "treat";
```

which prints "trick".

***Ruby***

--0 is just -(-0). So the first line declares a constant **True** with a value false.
Next line does the actual printing and since **True** is false, it prints "treat". main is just treated as a variable in ruby and is assigned the value 0.

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) / [Batch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file), <strike>37</strike> 32 bytes

The perfect contrast, Linux vs. Windows!

```
echo;echo trick;exit<0echo treat
```

How it works on Linux: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@anJFvDSIUSooyk7OtUysyS2wMoAKpiSX/gQAA)

```
echo;                               -echo nothing
     echo trick;exit;               -echo trick
                     <0echo treat   -ignored by parser (already exited)
```

How it works on Windows:

```
echo;                               -echo nothing
                    <0              -find directory (with argument of 0)                  
     echo trick;exit                -can't find directory (skips command)
                      echo treat    -echo treat
```

-1 byte, Thanks to *CartManager XD*

-4 bytes by golfing a better way to comment

Comment: Why do you need the comment `#` if you have exited?  I don't know batch but I would think `echo;echo trick;exit;>NUL&echo treat` would work

Comment: Or even `echo;echo trick;#>NUL&echo treat`.

Comment: @CartManagerXD, that's a good idea, but for some reason the space in between `exit` and `#` has to be there. Although, you're right, you can remove the `#`, and then replace the space with a `;`. All in all it removes one byte

Comment: What is the purpose of the first `echo`?

Comment: @Cowsquack Without it, windows will also echo trick. For some reason echoing something before the `echo tick` renders everything up to the `<0` unparsable for windows.

Answer (score 3):

### C/C++, 75 bytes

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){puts(sizeof'a'<sizeof(int)?"treat":"trick");}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I've added in the byte count for your submission. There are a few optimizations you can make here. For starters, a lot of whitespace is unnecessary, so removing it would shorten the byte count. `sizeof('a')<sizeof(int)` is shorter by 1, though it causes the outputs to be swapped. Additionally, return types aren't strictly necessary for `main` - GCC assumes `int` if it's not explicitly stated.

Comment: Combining all of my suggestions, [this](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@6@cmZecU5qSalNckpKZr5dhx5WbmJmnoVldUFpSrKFRnFmVmp@moZ6ormkDZWfmlWhq2iuVFKUmlihZAenM5GwlTeva//8B) comes out to 74 bytes.

Comment: Also the parenthesis around the comparison are unnecessary. Which would save another 2 bytes.

Comment: You can remove the space between `#include` and `<stdio.h>` to save a byte

Answer (score 3):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php) / [Lost](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Lost), 112 bytes

```
v<<<<<<<<<<<>> > > >    >>>>>>
>%?"TRICv+"-+@> > > >        >
                 ^
        ^
    ^
^
  ^
                ^
        ^
  ^
 ^
^
^
```

[Try it online in Lost : `TRICK`](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/v8wGAezsFMCQ0w4MuOxU7ZVCgjydy7SVdLUdoFKcCgqcCnZcQBIIFOLADBCpACRBNIStwAkR54RIgIVB8nH////XdQQA) or [verify that it's deterministic](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/v8wGAezsFMCQ0w4MuOxU7ZVCgjydy7SVdLUdoFKcCgqcCnZcQBIIFOLADBCpACRBNIStwAkR54RIgIVB8nH////XDfuv6wgA).
[Try it online in Whitespace : `TREAT`.](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/v8wGAezsFMCQ0w4MuOxU7ZVCgjydy7SVdLUdoFKcCgqcCnZcQBIIFOLADBCpACRBNIStwAkR54RIgIVB8nH//wMA)

#### Explanation for [Lost](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Lost)

**Explanation of the language in general:**

Lost is a 2D path-walking language. Most 2D path-walking languages start at the top-left position and travel towards the right by default. Lost is unique however, in that ***both the start position AND starting direction it travels in is completely random***. So making the program deterministic, meaning it will have the same output regardless of where it starts or travels, can be quite tricky.

A Lost program of 2 rows and 5 characters per row can have 40 possible program flows. It can start on any one of the 10 characters in the program, and it can start traveling up/north, down/south, left/west, or right/east.

In Lost you therefore want to lead everything to a starting position, so it'll follow the designed path you want it to. In addition, you'll usually have to clean the stack when it starts somewhere in the middle.

**Explanation of the program:**

Let's ignore everything except for the first two lines. The other lines all point upward/north, to lead the flow towards the following part of the code. (NOTE: The small `t` are actually tabs (`\t`). But due to alignment it's better readable like this.)

```
v<<<<<<<<<<<>> > > >t>>>>>>
>%?"TRICv+"-+@> > >t>t  t >
```

All the arrows lead towards the leading `>` of the second line. A minor thing to note about the arrows:

```
v<<<<<<<<<<<>> > > >t>>>>>>
```

could also have been:

```
v<<<<<<<<<<<<< < < <t<<<<<<
```

Lost programs will wrap around in all directions; i.e. when it goes out of bounds at the left-hand side traveling in a west/left direction, it continues at the right-hand side in that same direction. Because of this, using `<<<>>>` will have a shorter path and is therefore slightly better for performance than `<<<<<<`, and since it doesn't affect the byte-count anyway, why not use it. :)

An additional minor note: these alternating trailing parts are there because we need to fit the spaces/tabs of the Whitespace program in it:

```
 > > >t>>>>>>
> > >t>t  t >
```

So, all those arrows, including the `v` after the `C` in the string (more on that in a moment), will lead to the leading `>` on the second line. After that, the program flows and execution is as follows:

- `>`: travel in an east/right direction
- `%`: Put the safety 'off'. In a Lost program, an `@` will terminate the program, but only when the safety is 'off'. When the program starts, the safety is always 'on' by default, otherwise a program flow starting at the exit character `@` would immediately terminate without doing anything. The `%` will turn this safety 'off', so when we now encounter an `@` the program will terminate (if the safety is still 'on', the `@` will be a no-op instead).
- `?`: Clean the top value on the stack. In some program flows it's highly likely we have a partial string on the stack, so we use this to wipe the stack clean of that potential string.
- `"`: Start a string, which means it will push the integer code-points of the characters used (rather similar as the Whitespace program).
- `TRICv+`: Push the code-points for these characters, being `84 82 73 67 118 43` respectively
- `"`: We're done pushing code-points of this string
- `-+`: Subtract the top two values from each other, so the `118 43` becomes `75` (`K`). (NOTE: `-+` are actually two loose operands: `-` will negate the top value on the stack (multiply it by `-1`), and `+` will add the top two values on the stack together.)
- `@`: Terminate the program if the safety is 'off' (which it is at this point). After which all the values on the stack will be output implicitly. Using the `-A` program argument flag these code-points will be output as characters instead.

#### Explanation for [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php):

**Explanation of the language in general:**

Whitespace is a stack-based language using only spaces ( ), tabs (`\t`), and newlines (`\n`) (hereafter indicated with `STN` respectively). Any other character is ignored. Printing in Whitespace can either be done as character or as integer. When it outputs as character, it will use an integer on the stack as code-point and convert it to its corresponding UTF-8 character before outputting.

Integers are pushed to the stack as follows:

- `S`: Enable Stack Manipulation
- `S`: Push what follows as integer to the stack
- `S`/`T`: Sign bit where `S` is positive and `T` is negative
- Some `T` and `S` followed by an `N`: Put number as binary to the stack (`T=1` and `S=0`)

For example: `SSSTSTSN` will push `10` to the stack.

**Explanation of the program:**

If we ignore all non-whitespace characters, the program will be this:

```python
SSSTN           # Push 1     (T)
SSTTSSTSN       # Push -18   (A)
SSTTTTSN        # Push -14   (E)
SSTTN           # Push -1    (R)
SSSTN           # Push 1     (T)
NSSN            # Create Label LOOP
  SSSTSTSSTTN   #   Push 83
  TSSS          #   Add top two values on the stack together
  TNSS          #   Pop and output top of the stack as character with this code-point
  NSNN          #   Jump to Label LOOP
```

Instead of directly pushing and printing each character, I push all characters to the stack in reversed order, with each of their code-points lowered by a constant value. In a loop I then add this constant to the integer, before popping and outputting it as character. [See this Whitespace tip of mine for more information on this approach.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158232/52210)
The constant `83` is the most efficient constant for this output-text, which is generated by [this Java program](https://tio.run/##fVJNa9wwEL3nVwxzktDGbKGh1F4RNpCDodtD7H5AGorsKLtKvbIrzS4sZX@7I8f2frQlFwnNe/M0M2@e1VZdPj/@atuyUt7DQhn75wKg2RSVKcGTonBta/MI6wCxjJyxy/sHULyjAfQBcNpvKgIJ6n76kLwixhL4taoq7TsgtaSX2kWL@fefX@efvtxOIJUfrpJTlZF@N6oh9vhT7VinZ2SamNm7q2lihBgqONYgESc0aeSY1ecVO9JQxH2F0VLTTQh4xg/pACSDeF5/W5mANKrUN8Yqt@t1WXFpeHLgOsko0r83qvKs4deYff5hM4yJC3ckNZLGx364zRNzUaXtklaMw@zQ60kZ/7R/ongyyaPMEU5D3Jx/2Z/ZzpNeR/WGoiZ0Q5Vl2KdLFKOowCSMFkUqEGJA8dY0Uj58@7cyOy//lbW/CMewRINLb2l3FtthIFvlgi@YZSiYnU2vMccYM@TnC1HG415RfSbVoXyhaBWpwjPL@f@cJyHL2fuPwcSgnQ9b08/Nado4GxgY/MW@l33btvnd7Tx/AQ), a generator I've created and used for some of my other Whitespace answers in the past.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby / [Brat](http://brat-lang.org), 26 bytes

```
#*
puts:treat
$*#p :trick
```

Ruby prints `treat` and Brat prints `trick`.

**Ruby**

The first line is a comment starting with `#`, so ignored. The second line prints out `treat` (the parser is liberal enough we don't need a space).

The last line is interpreted as `$*` (a global variable) and the rest is ignored as a comment starting with `#`.

**Brat**

In Brat, `#*` begins a multi-line comment and `*#` ends it.

The first line begins a multi-line comment, so the second line is ignored.

Brat sees `$` as part of the comment and `*#` closes the comment started above. That leaves `p :treat` to print out `treat`.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2 and C, 93 bytes

It's not exactly a competitive entry, but it was certainly a fun challenge. The Python section prints `trick` while the C portion prints `treat`.

```
#include <stdio.h>/*
print'trick'
#*/
#define pass int main(){puts("treat");return 0;}
pass
```

Answer (score 2):

## C / Shell <del>57</del> 50 bytes

Should be more verbose to match the C99 (missing include, no return value in main etc). But it runs fine with gcc, clang and tcc:

Updated version:

```
#define echo main(){puts("trick");}int
echo treat;
```

Initial version:

```
#define echo main(){puts("trick");}void*p=
echo "treat";
```

Comment: this could be shortened to `#define echo main(){puts("trick");}int` and `echo treat;`

Comment: @technosaurus Might work in some compilers, but gcc throws an error - not a constant initializer.

Comment: I didn't have an `=` sign, so it shouldn't complain about an initializer.  After preprocessing, C should see `echo main(){puts("trick");}int treat;`... which is just an unused (and uninitialized) variable named treat ... I think you may have added an equal sign to the end of the `#define` block. ... which brings it down to 50 bytes.

Comment: You don't need `int` in C89; a bare `treat;` will default to *int*.

Answer (score 2):

### [QBIC](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44680/showcase-your-language-one-vote-at-a-time/86385#86385) and QBasic 4.5, 45 bytes

QBIC is my attempt at a golfing language, based on QBasic. The language has evolved quite a bit from its original, as I think this snippet illustrates:

```
A$=STR$(q):IF A$=" 1"THEN?"trick"ELSE?"treat"
```

The space before the `1` is significant. QBIC will print `trick`, QBasic will show `treat`. So, what's going on here. First, QBasic:

```
A$=STR$(q)          Set A$ to a string representation of the number q                        
IF A$=" 1"          A$ is now " 0" because 'q' is not set and 0 by default.
                    Space added by STR$ :'(  
THEN PRINT "trick"  Ignored
ELSE PRINT "treat"  Printed
```

Now QBIC. This one is a little more complex:

```
A                   Creates A$ in te output BAS
$                   Start a Code Literal. QBIC is not yet very function-complete,
                    so on occasion we need to call QBASIC functions directly. However,
                    that may interfere with QBIC syntax. When a '$' is encountered,
                    QBIC ignores everything from that $ until a '|' or EOF and
                    just passes this along as QBASIC.  
=STR$(q)            Set A$ to a string representation of the number q                        
IF A$=" 1"          A$ is now " 1" because 'q' is pre-initilised to 1 by QBIC                       
THEN PRINT "trick"  printed
ELSE PRINT "treat"  ignored
```

We don't need `END-IF`s, because in the snippet the `IF` is in-line.

Answer (score 2):

## Dart - JavaScript (68 bytes)

Seems appropriate as Google has been livestreaming the Dart Developer Summit for the past two days.

```
var a=main();function main(){1==true?alert("Treat"):print("Trick");}
```

Formatted:

```
var a = main();

function main() {
  1 == true ? alert("Treat") : print("Trick");
}
```

---

### main method

> In Dart static variables may only be initialized with compile-time
> constants (hereafter referred to as just constants in the interest of
> brevity).  Static variables include all top-level variables as well as
> static variables of classes.

^ http://news.dartlang.org/2012/02/static-variables-no-longer-have-to-be.html

The Dart VM starts by immediately calling the main method.
As the variable 'a' is a top level one, the Dart VM will only initialize it when it's needed (lazy initialization).

JavaScript immediately initializes the variable by which the main method also gets invoked.

---

### truthy/falsey

> Dart differs from JavaScript in its treatment of truthy and falsey
> values. In JavaScript, the objects 1, non-empty string, and non-null
> objects are treated as true. In Dart, it’s more simple. Only the
> boolean value true is treated as true. In Dart, all object instances
> other than true are treated as false.

^ https://www.dartlang.org/resources/dart-tips/dart-tips-ep-4

The above quote explains why *1 == true* evaluates to true in JavaScript whilst it gets evaluated to false in Dart.

Comment: Couldn't you just use ``1?`` instead? And at least in JavaScript you can get rid of the outer most parentheses. I don't know about dart though

Comment: @BrainStone nope. As Dart requires a static type of bool for conditions, you can't just use *integer ? :*

Comment: @BrainStone you're right about the outer most parentheses though! Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 2):

## C / JavaScript (75 bytes)

Works with Clang on Mac, with some warnings, and Node.js.

```
main()
{puts("trick");}//\
function main(){puts=()=>console.log("treat");}
```

75 bytes is quite a bit but JavaScript is a verbose language for code golf.

I took inspiration from I_LIKE_BREAD7 for the escaped comment line to include non-C code in a .c file.

Comment: 64 bytes: ``//\\nmain=_=>{puts=_=>console.log`treat`}\nmain()\n{puts("trick");}`` (replace all `\n` with a REAL newline.) Example in C (http://ideone.com/YToPEb) and in Javascript (https://jsfiddle.net/1m2yfdow/).

Comment: I've actually reduced it to 62 bytes: ``//\\nmain=_=>{puts=_=>console.log`treat`}\nmain()\n{puts("tr‌​ick");}``. All I did was replacing ``main=_=>{puts=_=>console.log`treat`}`` with ``main=_=>puts=_=>console.log`treat` ``. Try it on https://jsfiddle.net/1m2yfdow/1/. This is a Javascript-only change, so, C won't be affected

Answer (score 2):

## Python, Lua 31 or 32 bytes

```
s="trick"
--0;s="treat"
print s
```

The one above has to be run using python 2.

```
s="trick"
--0;s="treat"
print(s)
```

The `--` designates a comment in Lua, while it is two negatives in Python.
Prints "trick" in Lua, but prints "treat" in Python.

Answer (score 2):

## Python / JavaScript, 32 bytes

```
1//2;print"trick"
alert("treat")
```

Python runs `1//2;`, which integer divides `1` by `2`, then prints `"trick"`. `alert("treat")` causes a runtime error because `alert` is not a function, but I believe this is allowed.

JavaScript runs `1` and sees the rest of the line as a comment. The second line alerts `"treat"`.

Note that I can't shorten `alert("treat")` to `` alert`treat` `` because Python will throw a syntax error during compilation.

Answer (score 2):

## Lua, Ruby - 31 bytes

```
s="trick"
--0;s="treat"
print s
```

The explanation is the same as my Python/Lua answer.
Prints treat in Ruby, trick in Lua.

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure/Groovy, 37 bytes

```
;/*
(println"trick");*/println"treat"
```

### Clojure (trick)

The `;` denotes a single-line comment, so *Clojure* sees:

```
(println "trick")
```

### Groovy (treat)

Any single `;` is a valid statement that does nothing. Obviously `/* ... */` is a multi-line comment. *Groovy* sees:

```
println "treat"
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python / [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 22 bytes

```
1
print"trick";"treat"
```

#### Python

This should be fairly obvious: `print"trick"` prints `trick`; `1` and `"treat"` don't do anything.

#### [Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=MQpwcmludCJ0cmljayI7InRyZWF0Ig==&input=)

This code transpiles to

```
1
.p("r".i("n".t(("trick"))));("treat")
```

The result of last expression is automatically sent to STDOUT, so this prints `treat`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix) / [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 24 bytes

```
WHAT"kcirt"u@!C;Co} `É.t
```

[**Test Cubix**](http://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=V0hBVCJrY2lydCJ1QCFDO0NvfSBgyYR0) | [**Test Japt**](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?code=V0hBVCJrY2lydCJ1QCFDO0NvfSBgyYR0)

The `.` represents the unprintable char U+0084.

#### Japt

Before running Japt code, it is first transpiled to JavaScript. The various features transpile roughly to:

```
WHAT    "kcirt"u  @               !C;       Co      `É.t
W,H,A,T,"kcirt".u(function(X,Y,Z){!C;return C.o()}),"treat"
```

The the code is evaluated, and the result of the last expression is sent to STDOUT. `W,H,A,T` are variables, but they're effectively no-ops since we don't do anything with them. `"kcirt".u()` makes the string uppercase, ignoring the function, but again, this is discarded. The only thing that matters is the `"treat"` at the end; this is printed, end then the program ends.

#### Cubix

Before the code is run, all whitespace is removed, and the code is transformed into the smallest cube net possible, padded with `.` no-ops. This particular program becomes:

```
    W H
    A T
" k c i r t " u
@ ! C ; C o } `
    É .
    t .
```

Then the code is run like a regular 2D language, with the IP (instruction pointer) starting at the top-left corner of the leftmost face. Here's what happens:

- `"kcirt"` - Push the char codes of these letters to the stack.
- `u` - Make a U-turn to the right, going down a row in the process.
- `` ` `` - Not implemented, so a no-op.
- `}` - Another no-op.
- `o` - Output the char-code on top of the stack (`t`).
- `C` - Another no-op.
- `;` - Remove the top item.
- `C` - Another no-op.
- `!` - If the top item is non-zero, skip the next instruction (`@`).

Since the top item is non-zero, the IP jumps the `@` and wraps back around to the `` ` ``. This repeats until the last character has been outputted, at which point `!` fails and the IP hits `@`, ending the program.

---

### Old solution, 25 bytes

```
"treat"//"kcirt"under@!;o
```

[**Test Cubix**](http://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=InRyZWF0Ii8vImtjaXJ0InVuZGVyQCE7bw==) | [**Test Japt**](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?code=InRyZWF0Ii8vImtjaXJ0InVuZGVyQCE7bw==)

#### Japt

This is very simple: `//` and everything after is a comment, so the only thing evaluated is `"treat"`. This is implicitly printed to STDOUT.

#### Cubix

The code is expanded to the following cube net:

```
      " t r
      e a t
      " / /
" k c i r t " u n d e r
@ ! ; o . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . .
      . . .
      . . .
      . . .
```

Then the code is run like a regular 2D language, with the IP (instruction pointer) starting at the top-left corner of the leftmost face. Here's what happens:

- `"kcirt"` - Push the char codes of these letters to the stack.
- `u` - Make a U-turn to the right, going down a row in the process.
- `....` - A bunch of no-ops.
- `o` - Output the char-code on top of the stack (`t`).
- `;` - Remove the top item.
- `!` - If the top item is non-zero, skip the next instruction.

The IP then wraps around to the right, so these last 3 instructions repeat until the stack is empty. Then `!` fails, so the IP lands on `@`, which ends the program. The Japt code is conveniently contained on the top face and never gets run.

Answer (score 2):

## C / Octave, 63 bytes

```
#define f() main(){puts("trick");}//\
f=@()(disp("treat"));
f()
```

Explanation:

What C sees:

```
#define f() main(){ puts("trick"); } //comment
f()
```

What Octave sees:

```
#comment
f = @()(disp("treat"));
f()
```

Pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

## Excel / Google Sheets, 28 Bytes

Anonymous worksheet formula that takes no input and outputs `"Trick"` to the calling cell in Excel and `"Treat"` to the calling cell in Google Sheets

```vba
=IfError(M("Treat"),"Trick")
```

Answer (score 2):

**Javascript/Ruby, <del>35</del> 30 bytes**

```
0?puts("trick"):alert("treat")
```

0 is truthy in Ruby, but not in Javascript.

Edit: Saved 5 bytes by replacing `[]==[]` with `0`.

Comment: As far as I know, JS doesn't compare by value. It compares if it's the same object, which it is not, as you are initializing two different empty arrays.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) and [ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink), <s>31 or 42</s> 29 bytes

```hs
trick/*b=b
main=putStr"treat"
```

Try it online! ([Haskell](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v6QoMzlbXyvJNokrNzEzz7agtCS4pEippCg1sUTp/38A), [ink](https://tio.run/##y8zL/v@/pCgzOVtfK8k2iSs3MTPPtqC0JLikSKmkKDWxROn/fwA))

#### Explained

Ink doesn't mind unclosed multiline comments, so as far as ink is concerned, the program is just `trick`, which gets printed literally.

Haskell interprets the first line as defining a function `/*` that takes two parameters named `trick` and `b` and returning the latter. `main` just prints `"treat"`

Answer (score 2):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console) (treat) & [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish) (trick), 15 bytes

```
"kcirt"H>'ອE@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/18pOzmzqETJw079wa61rg7//wMA) (Runic)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/Xyk7ObOoRMnDTv3BrrWuDv//AwA) (Gol><>)

The Gol><> is pretty straight forward. It pushes the char-literals for "trick" in reverse order, then `H` causes the entire stack to be dumped to output before terminating.

Runic starts at the `>`, pushes the char-literal `ອ` (decimal value 3757) and calls `E` which causes a dictionary lookup on 3757, which is "treat", `@` dumps stack and terminates.

Answer (score 2):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/) / [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 32 bytes

```
0. # ." trick"
( print("treat"))
```

Try it online: ([gforth](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//G@gpKCvoKSmUFGUmZytxaSgUFGXmlWgolRSlJpYoaSpo/v8PAA), [python](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/30BPQVlBT0mhpCgzOVuJS0OhoCgzr0RDqaQoNbFESVPz/38A))

#### Explanation

Not the most clever approach, effectively uses the different comment styles to have each language run its own code.

`#` starts a line comment in python, but adds the lowest digit of a double-length number to an output string in forth. `0.` is used as the double-length number in forth, but unused in python

Standalone parentheses are used for grouping in python (and are ignored when unneeded), while they denote a block comment in forth.

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg) / [Foo](https://tio.run/#foo), 14 bytes

```
("Treat")Trick
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//9fQymkKDWxREkzpCgzOfv/fwA)

[Try It online!](https://tio.run/##S8vP//9fQymkKDWxREkzpCgzOfv/fwA)

### Explanation

### Foo

```
("Treat")      Push "Treat"
         Trick NOPS
               Implicit print
```

### Keg

```
("Treat")      # For loop over stack length. Stack is empty, therefore it is skipped.
         Trick # Push "Trick"
               # Implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

Clojure/Script

**Clojure**

`(prn (if (= (str (type "")) "class java.lang.String") "trick" "treat"))`

**ClojureScript**

`(prn (if (= (str (type "")) "class java.lang.String") "trick" "treat"))`

**Explanation**

Clojure compiles down to JavaScript, and works quite the same as it does in Java.

`"class java.lang.String"` is not available in JavaScript, but, the `if` statements and `prn` work exactly the main.

Answer (score 1):

## Dart, Dart2JS, 49 bytes

`main(){print(identical(1,1.0)?"Treat":"Trick");}`

running by
dart gives:

```
$ dart web/test.dart 
Trick
```

for compiled version:

```
$ dart2js web/test.dart
$ nodejs out.js
Treat
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG! This question is [tag:code-golf], so please include the number of bytes in your code, and the two languages (dart2js, dart) that you use. Also, please remove extra spaces in your code.

Answer (score 1):

## /// / ><>, 29 bytes

```
/v//treat/
"l
t?
r!
i;
co
k
"
```

[Try /// online](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=L3YvL3RyZWF0LwoibAp0PwpyIQppOwpjbwprCiI&input=). This prints `treat` after it replaces all `v`s with null, then stops processing because of the single `/` which does not complete a `///` block.

[Try ><> online](http://fish.tryitonline.net/#code=L3YvL3RyZWF0LwoibAp0PwpyIQppOwpjbwprCiI&input=). Gives us `trick`. The first `/` wraps execution around to the `"` on line 8, it pushes `trick` onto the stack in reverse order, bounces off of the first `/` again, goes down at the `v` and uses a loop to print all the stacked characters LIFO.

Comment: Hi, would you mind to change the header to `# /// / ><>, 29 bytes`? This is so that leaderbaord snippet doesn't get confused.

Answer (score 1):

## /// / ><>, 22 bytes

```
\treat/
>"kcirt"ooooo;
```

Try it online! [Slashes](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=XHRyZWF0Lwo-ImtjaXJ0Im9vb29vOw&input=) | [Fish](http://fish.tryitonline.net/#code=XHRyZWF0Lwo-ImtjaXJ0Im9vb29vOw&input=)

**Explanation**

(♥ is a newline)

- **///**

  ```
  \t                      Print "t"
    reat                  Print "reat"
        /♥>"kcirt"ooooo;  Incomplete replacement, ignored
  ```
- **><>**

  ```
  \                       Mirror, makes IP go down
         ♥>               Go right
           "kcirt"ooooo   Print "trick"
                       ;  End program
  ```

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/)/[Befunge](http://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 21 bytes

```
"Trick"o"taerT",,,,,@
```

[Try it online! (CJam)](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=IlRyaWNrIm8idGFlclQiLCwsLCxA)
[Try it online! (Befunge)](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=IlRyaWNrIm8idGFlclQiLCwsLCxA)

---

#### CJam:

`"Trick"o` push "Trick" and print it.
`"taerT",` push "taerT" and take length, 5.
`,,,,` take lengths of ranges, leaves 5.
`@` tries to rotate top three elements.

CJam would normally print the stack on exit, but with only a single element the rotation causes an empty stack exception and the 5 is left unprinted.

#### Befunge:

`"Trick"` push each letter of "Trick".
`o` is unspecified and gets ignored.
`"taerT"` push each letter of "Treat" in reverse.
`,,,,,` pop and print 5 letters ("Treat")
`@` terminates Befunge naturally.

Befunge doesn't print the stack on exit so the letters from "Trick" don't cause a problem. *However, the unspecified* `o` *may be treated differently on other interpreters.* For instance [this one](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html) would reverse the instruction pointer and wrap back to `@` with no output.

Answer (score 1):

## Scheme / Brainf*ck, 80 bytes

My second attempt.

`(print 'trick);++++[>+++++[>+++++<-]<-]>>[>+>+<<-]++++[>++++<-]>.--.>+.----.<++.`

What Scheme sees: `(print 'trick)`

What Brainf*ck sees: `++++[>+++++[>+++++<-]<-]>>[>+>+<<-]++++[>++++<-]>.--.>+.----.<++.`

Happy Halloween.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (with SpiderMonkey `print`)/Python - 32 bytes

```
a=1
print(["trick","treat"][--a])
```

Comment: Would `a=1;print(["trick","treat"][--a])` work instead?

Comment: Yes, that works!

Answer (score 1):

### [SmileBASIC](http://smilebasic.com/en/reference) / ><>, 21 bytes

```
'kcirt'ooooo;
?"treat
```

[Try the ><> one here!](https://starfish.000webhostapp.com/?script=OQawxglgTgLsD2jEG4BQB+ARDKBTAhjEA)

Sadly SmileBASIC doesn't have an online interpreter.

#### SmileBASIC Explanation

```
'kcirt'ooooo; # `'` is a comment character in SmileBASIC, so this is ignored
?"treat       # `?` is an alias for "PRINT", the string doesn't need  to be closed
```

#### ><> Explanation

```
'kcirt'        push "trick" to stack
       ooooo   output "trick"
            ;  end execution
```

Answer (score 1):

## C / C++, 99 bytes

```
#include<stdio.h>
#if __cplusplus
#define puts(x) puts("treat")
#endif
main(){puts("trick");}
```

it is quite long, but i am wondering why there had not be one.

Comment: But there is: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97677/44874 ...

Comment: @steenbergh Duplicate answers are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP and PowerShell - 38 bytes

```
if($_ENV){echo "trick";}return "treat"
```

It's not that clever. Just makes use of the similarities between PHP and PowerShell

Answer (score 1):

## C / Common Lisp, <s>95</s> <s>92</s> <s>44</s> 40 bytes

```
//(princ"trick")
;main(){puts("treat");}
```

[Try C online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/19fX6OgKDMvWamkKDM5W0mTyzo3MTNPQ7O6oLSkWAMomppYoqRpXfv/PwA)

[Try Common Lisp online!](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74/19fX6OgKDMvWamkKDM5W0mTyzo3MTNPQ7O6oLSkWAMomppYoqRpXfv/PwA)

Both “normal” languages with very different syntax and semantics.

**Explanation**

For Common Lisp:

[`//`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_sl_sls.htm#SLSL) is a special variable used in the Common Lisp REPL to give the result of the value preceding the previous one, initially equal to `NIL`. Then we print `trick`. The following line starts with `;` and this in Commonl Lisp is considered a comment.

For C, the first line is a comment, and the other is the program. Note that the semicolon before the definition of the `main` function is syntactically correct.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript/Ruby - 32 bytes

(Assuming Spidermonkey-like output function `print`)

```
a=1
print(["trick","treat"][--a])
```

Ruby `--` is double negative, while in JavaScript it is decrement;

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (Spidermonkey `print`) (treat), Python (trick) - 34 bytes

```
a=1//2
print(["trick","treat"][a])
```

`//` is a comment in JavaScript, and truncating integer division in Python.

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98219/42545 I don't mind if you keep this, though, as the other one is browser JS.

Answer (score 0):

## knight & bash, 22 bytes

```c
: O'trick'&&echo treat
```

[Knight - trick](https://tio.run/##rVltU9tIEv5s/4rBKSyNLCey4Kq2bGSKZCFFHYEsJLcfwBeELGPVyrJPkmFZwv71XHfPi0Z@yV3ulg@WNfN0T/czPd09JureR9G3V0kWpctxfFCU42T@ejpsmiNpclcbisqnRbwCypPsvjZUJjOBGceTJItZmrJ0nt3TR1OPfjr//IH1qterT5fMr17/cXTJ9qvXk/N37Kfq9fIz61Xgk7MrA3v@@cyAfj7/cHT1d7vgzMaPNvuz9zeuZ4@uYFkxGU3DnDm8EjBRYKtWMRyy/Wru/PhXnMxgkjz6yvD7wcEKBpchDLoJmDTlCKxh3l5cnBEIPw7JyT76Zhhy@V4AQN6w9SFMlzHn19mIN5vkB@zK9Si4bB1fnNjf@uzCgl2KfrPa7TiazlmZx2H5jcNkayDwToFjMxag5KDZBPWLMC9im7PnZiPJSpYMmg0YpaVc5kyWWQQjJBzBezlbuMUiu/ZHwbPnei@go5GAOsLD08OBN29QfbJgj9OkjItFGMXNBnxPYxvGQdwWZrisdVPeZDeTm5w9v1yPbN5/1eJkSiOZMFtbGzDrlcWZUKFGd2D0JoPhTkeMgJ2NOC1ic@BFmBNN4@g3NpnnLFvO7uK8kPYwOynGyX1SKq2wOrrTc7VH4umwnsc6zJGWdzqcdZnlWbAEWppwlsflMs@YCg4hRvExWLXhIcyT8C6NlRVgRDp/jHM7gvWUIezrV6aMi@gtIiK@WFzSk2xwPQl6LuxRoIdXrMPjJsMSINl4ubBxS5nktMvgbd1gcfgLoU2YcWNZlU0tS2waCIMH2igGSiBZwHewbBEWJSunMSgL8xLAcgMcxShuaMTRE2WscYa2GgufPU4b3ajIIPMxdMtknoHZGLHeCEyLFCPFcrFAwrmKKjVi0m/GH9BukI06VCgvMohjSFwYudJywconS59uMXCCA5jE@pi80EwVZJT3hKs22o2mhmk6j@x9z@1xdBCHtRPkYLZM0zB/Mh2t9ufS2J6PlraMFpTyy2xFmpbo4RIyKWzy9Oj47bvbX3bOfr4wHDbV3iUb9frrendqit@fXm3RWMY5qQyzMfvXMlSvqPbBXGJvfQlBwHtLc3G6gQsS3q8L1zEvlCrzZYY7NJDJ1ynnha1yJR0ACO0yiRjN3i0n1/7@SNohNrpN6UEbUCzgWJUTG6Dg/26ajlsq71DxcVHJqgI4FFqBKGti/RrugPX26n6i8xiLh6xV5su4BTGoxzEkYXwSQgbBiRZGVqsiAf1E32X9ITq@vJ3PU5i5qzOw1dfKre855Py4R6aZd2tmpmhj9pfaCEFbztPUNk11medChfgfTM7WTMYq/OHo47mLtVgEGryeXvc8z4NwAlfgVb0VyR/xl5LhY2DEqOEtMgBvLn749LkX9FRJxwyHVR0f9OmLxx4ATk7Pjh02geQ4aOjQluthGo7ChZvGGXUABleqPRKcwbnbRsaqINYmLG1YcOyEegmoxQfExQCKSoKTOm9Es8XKDhBJyahKIUhTMsJlisekjKa2A8ysdVPAEZN/EdYp68jqM1xFAAIkFPsxyMK8TU5J9bIjrIUsH1AVrhDUdpY5li7qPK9H/LkKM2igKLeLhS9h4bruHDKezdve7xP8q5AfAQlaBUf3cZlC02i3aS/buENYIsdJxgfJxLZpP7EhiKY52uJCnHIutjnwBhtthQenNkCsdyzWE50jZgNJyEDZiyTJ3FlZ@bbyR@D1zLtqBiVNijXmFjAYDRB/wWK@iDPbWNht5S1qFcCqYCYqJcRj4Hv7P9G4bC5s0ZFMwPQxOgUtHISsi/0dwKF3oDdcA5ZW4WXDIOsE1ArhiQUkl3SDHlqLqEYNTsB8s2epaKw8@QU8iX@HNg5P@5qfO7Vdp7vBDmayNeDZWnjAKmmdFwP@s9WXfeKGQNaZT1ag1jm1xTbWIK6K0HC4z6vGci0dKtErag7t3QIF64dhXRjohNbHXBcyKW9VUDWB5SUOM6l2WwmTNcvcAZlbJAsXFQt4MMTFB0kT@1mjjrXbdKHqdhE6Em3uDbXbDWXW7munAHtseONMHbXcMH9ZFmr3dUyIXk8Y1NEGUZ6EfIkpGUPL2B7RTTfquy1up4iGvp@pWPLFnmP/S4dBbAChcBhPeaC89PnmUI3CUj1k19nrVDRx9R11cehGXXqWMkdIv7pr0WlEO7bqdXuFkFPtzgYWVsvzBh6cNR7Evm5iYbbBNYcwgamEBKAG2ZQhA@sGLnkIGnS7pE8SRSVzdaMFo2Xt9L/5LjFvNhOz@12h3c1C/yQ2aw6JqwON@aaXA0m7YD1g3Z5mmbBAfQ/OWbcHZ6xngv0fRB9AeqxhgwChtG5fjXiKciLaH3qSa59Tu@IExH9z9UDQJLkCdwRKsFhi4DteGaZxHlsFy@bQQydpmWTsMXwC3th4DnfSMr6Pc5BZzLM4K5MQbxFwkufsMWbT8CEGoFSE8JLNwmwJ4fP0GkfRuztkHKggJoplWuKPBrS4TngK0jUxaskVykw5DVlRj/q2I73thmjYQQ3l0f08TLE2PoHX2TiNx@y2MvtWa3nGb6IxMxapnBmism5XvXOCNyTUMUx/0XnwgIJ1pfBh0qvlxaCeFQ@ZefgPzGOAon35u1ubCcAhqzWKNOgyIxuiDk9IqpLrizqA2J0Aqo3RBQ3hUGJozcfzPpvFs2iBYZax4e3h/@vK8C9wZahc2dngSyB9ka4cbmdfrLrBZJw@ZDWArxG@KqA7m@ysXrR7KvOYCrR57Sr9oS@basOhKSlTiZb/@t/IyxxkqNHyA6tvomtt7io2qLJuffqHLzKqt61uMohr1G4zOhUSBjWOgpq0kSZRAhGdjhYTJv8K7olfvcxGs@YdM3sXKXZa79oRasgf@v09g5b34soQGB1WxyxA63ekTF48XH0W9moN7ZUgekXpYLXk@ZtK3h7XfYCvpfdp8D80RGgYPnErIt3863bI7I188BBX7fSwSaIGQcS/mKQHITryJMDq43gSQpIEz1SHmWQwmYzpR6QwKqFMWbuRhT0njnC25RaLynQNhG5Q/pAwC5MMm1UW5veRS0odB74/cPy5iu6X@G8c2yNr6te4l2//Bg)

[Bash - treat](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/30rBX72kKDM5W11NLTU5I1@hpCg1seT/fwA)

### knight

In knight, `:` is the noop command, which takes one argument, in this case that argument is the expression `O'trick'`, or `OUTPUT 'trick'`. I am not completely sure why the remaining characters don't cause a problem, but they don't.  I suspect because, since the program starts with the single expresion `:`, it stop reading after it consumes 1 expression worth of argument.

### bash

`:` is the "always true" function, and in this case it the argument `0'trick'`, with which it does nothing except return with the error code `0`, for success.  This means that the 2nd branch of the `&&` will execute, printing "treat".