# The meta-polyglot quine

Tags: code-golf, quine, code-generation, polyglot

In my time on PPCG, I've noticed that quine problems and polyglot problems are quite popular. Also, meta-solutions to problems, that is, scripts which generate a program which is the solution to a problem, tend to get a lot of positive feedback from the community. Therefore, I have created this challenge, which implements these three ideas.

Your task then, reader and [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) enthusiast, is to create as short as possible a script which can run in two languages A and B to generate quines for A and B. When your program is run in language A, it should generate a program that is a quine in language B **but not in language A** and vice versa. The languages A and B can be different version of the same language, provided you keep in mind that the generated quines should only work in one of the versions. 

Keep in mind that the [standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default/10033) should be considered closed and only [proper quines](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/what-counts-as-a-proper-quine) are allowed.

Good luck, fewest characters wins!

Comment: A quine is basically a meta-meta-meta-meta-meta-meta-meta-etc. program anyways :)

Comment: How to count bytes if the two languages use different character encodings? You should probably score in characters rather than bytes

Comment: If I run the quine in language A to generate a quine for language B, should that be runnable in A?

Comment: @LuisMendo When writing a polyglot for languages with different encodings, I'd assume that they both receive the same byte stream (not different encodings of the same characters).

Comment: @corvus_192 it doesn't matter how it runs in language A as long as it is not a quine.

Comment: @Pavel I actually wrote a similar challenge [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97747/write-a-quine-generator-polyglot), but it got closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## CJam 0.6.6 dev / GolfScript, <s>15</s> <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```
"0$p"0$~a:n;
```

*Thanks to @jimmy23013 for golfing off 2 bytes!*

Rest to be updated.

#### Verification

Since the submission involves significant whitespace, it's best to compare hexdumps.

```
$ xxd -g 1 mpquine
0000000: 22 60 30 24 7e 22 30 24 7e 4e 4d 3a 6e 3b        "`0$~"0$~NM:n;
$
$ cjam mpquine | tee quine.gs | xxd -g 1
0000000: 22 60 30 24 7e 22 60 30 24 7e 0a                 "`0$~"`0$~.
$ golfscript quine.gs | xxd -g 1
0000000: 22 60 30 24 7e 22 60 30 24 7e 0a                 "`0$~"`0$~.
$ cjam quine.gs | xxd -g 1
0000000: 22 60 30 24 7e 22 60 30 24 7e                    "`0$~"`0$~
$
$ golfscript mpquine | tee quine.cjam | xxd -g 1
0000000: 22 60 30 24 7e 22 60 30 24 7e                    "`0$~"`0$~
$ cjam quine.cjam | xxd -g 1
0000000: 22 60 30 24 7e 22 60 30 24 7e                    "`0$~"`0$~
$ golfscript quine.cjam | xxd -g 1
0000000: 22 60 30 24 7e 22 60 30 24 7e 0a                 "`0$~"`0$~.
```

### CJam

CJam prints `` "`0$~"0$~ `` and a trailing linefeed. [Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=ImAwJH4iMCR-Tk06bjs&input=)

The generated program prints `` "`0$~"0$~ `` with the trailing linefeed in GolfScript ([Try it online!](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=ImAwJH4iYDAkfgo&input=)), but without the linefeed in CJam ([Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=ImAwJH4iYDAkfgo&input=)).

#### How the metaquine works

```
"`0$~"         e# Push that string on the stack.
      0$~      e# Push a copy and evaluate it:
               e#   `     Inspect the string, pushing "\"`0$~\"".
               e#    0$   Push a copy.
               e#      ~  Evaluate, pushing "`0$~".
               e# Both "\"`0$~\"" and "`0$~" are now on the stack.
         NM    e# Push "\n" and "".
           :n; e# Map print over the elements of "" (none) and pop the result.
               e# "\"`0$~\"", "`0$~", and "\n" are now on the stack, and the
               e# characters they represent will be printed implicitly.
```

#### How the quine works

```
"`0$~"          # Push that string on the stack.
      0$~       # As in CJam.
         <LF>   # Does nothing.
                # "\"`0$~\"" and "`0$~" are now on the stack, and the characters
                # they represent will be printed implicitly, plus a linefeed.
```

Unlike GolfScript, CJam doesn't print a trailing linefeed by default, so this is not a quine in CJam.

### GolfScript

GolfScript prints `` "`0$~"0$~ ``, without trailing whitespace. [Try it online!](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=ImAwJH4iMCR-Tk06bjs&input=)

The generated program prints `` "`0$~"0$~ `` without trailing whitespace in CJam ([Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=ImAwJH4iYDAkfg&input=)), but GolfScript appends a linefeed ([Try it online!](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=ImAwJH4iYDAkfg&input=)).

#### How the metaquine works

```
"`0$~"0$~       # As in CJam.
         NM     # Unrecognized token. Does nothing.
           :n   # Store the top of the stack – "`0$~" – in the variable n. n holds
                # "\n" by default. When the program finishes, the interpreter
                # prints n implicitly, usually resulting in a trailing linefeed.
                # By redefining n, it will print "0$~" instead.
             ;  # Pop the string from the stack so it won't be printed twice.
```

#### How the quine works

```
"`0$~"0$~      e# Works as in GolfScript.
```

Unlike CJam, GolfScript will append a linefeed to the contents of the stack, so this is not a quine in GolfScript.

Comment: Just curious, in a broad sense, what's the difference between CJam and GolfScript, and why does your code work?

Comment: CJam was heavily inspired by GolfScript and is mostly backwards compatible. One big difference is that GolfScript, by default, appends a linefeed to the output, while CJam doesn't, which is what I'm exploiting here. I'll add a detailed explanation asap.

Comment: `"0$p"0$~a:n;`.

Comment: @jimmy23013 Nice, thank you! I had toyed with `a:n`, but using `p` didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 8):

### CJam / Fission, 22 bytes

```
"'!+OR'")5-"{'_'~}_~";
```

[Try it in CJam.](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=IichK09SJyIpNS0ieydfJ359X34iOw&input=) [Try it in Fission.](http://fission2.tryitonline.net/#code=IichK09SJyIpNS0ieydfJ359X34iOw&input=)

In CJam, this prints [the standard Fission quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/50968/8478):

```
'!+OR"
```

[Try the Fission quine.](http://fission2.tryitonline.net/#code=JyErT1Ii&input=)

In Fission, this prints a `"`-less variant of the standard CJam quine:

```
{'_'~}_~
```

[Try the CJam quine.](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=eydfJ359X34&input=)

This also works for 22 bytes (printing the same quines):

```
"& *NQ!":)R"{'_'~}_~";
```

#### Explanation

In CJam:

```
"'!+OR'"    e# Push this string.
)           e# Pull off the last character.
5-          e# Subtract 5, turning ' into ".
"{'_'~}_~"  e# Push this string.
;           e# And discard it again.
```

So at the end of the program, the stack contains the string `"'!+OR"` and the character `"`, both of which are implicitly printed.

In Fission, program flow starts at the `R` with a right-going atom. `'"` just changes the atoms mass, `)`, `5` and `-` are ignored for various reasons. Then the atom enters print mode at the `"` and prints `{'_'~}_~`. `;` destroys the atom and terminates the program.

Comment: +1 for emoticon `{'_'~}`

Comment: _destroys the atom_ I'd rather not be anywhere near when that happens

Answer (score 6):

## Clojure / Common Lisp, 274 bytes

```
(defmacro t []"((fn [s] (print (list s (list (quote quote) s)))) (quote (fn [s] (print (list s (list (quote quote) s))))))")(if '()(print(let[s clojure.string/replace](.toUpperCase(s(s(s(s(s(t)"fn""lambda")"[s]""(s)")"(quote ""'")"e)""e")")))))""))))"))))(eval '(princ(t))))
```

Some spaces added for readability

```
(defmacro t []"((fn [s] (print (list s (list (quote quote) s))))
     (quote (fn [s] (print (list s (list (quote quote) s))))))")
(if '()(print(let[s clojure.string/replace](.toUpperCase
    (s(s(s(s(s(t)"fn""lambda")"[s]""(s)")"(quote ""'")"e)""e")")))))""))))"))))
    (eval '(princ(t))))
```

Basically defines a macro which returns a quine in Clojure. Clojure requires parameters for macro definition provided as vector (`[]`) whereas Common Lisp (thankfully) just ignores it. After that we differ 2 languages by evaluating `'()` which equals to `nil` and thus falsey in Common Lisp and is `true` in Clojure. Then we do string manipulations using Clojure which Common Lisp doesn't even try to evaluate as it goes in another `if` branch. Clojure on the other hand tries to check if another branch is at least correct before executing so had to use `eval` there to both be correct in Clojure and output correct string in Common Lisp.

Note: just returning two different string might probably be shorter but then it won't be different to a polyglot challenges about outputing different strings in different languages.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Clojure original source run: https://ideone.com/SiQhPf

Common Lisp original source run: https://ideone.com/huLcty

Clojure output : `((LAMBDA (S) (PRINT (LIST S (LIST 'QUOTE S)))) '(LAMBDA (S) (PRINT (LIST S (LIST 'QUOTE S)))))`

Common Lisp output : `((fn [s] (print (list s (list (quote quote) s)))) (quote (fn [s] (print (list s (list (quote quote) s))))))`

Clojure output run in Common Lisp: https://ideone.com/T1DF7H

Vice versa: https://ideone.com/Fezayq

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly) / GolfScript, <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```
0000000: 3a 6e 22 ff cc cc 22 7d 7f fe 22 3a 6e 60 ff 3b  :n"..."}..":n`.;
```

#### Verification

Testing all involved programs with the exact byte streams can only be done locally.

```
$ LANG=en_US # Latin-1. Jelly doesn't care about the exact encoding,
$            # as longs as it's not UTF-8.
$
$ xxd -g 1 mpquine
0000000: 3a 6e 22 ff cc cc 22 7d 7f fe 22 3a 6e 60 ff 3b  :n"..."}..":n`.;
$
$ jelly f mpquine | tee quine.gs | xxd -g 1
0000000: 22 3a 6e 60 22 3a 6e 60                          ":n`":n`
$ golfscript quine.gs | xxd -g 1
0000000: 22 3a 6e 60 22 3a 6e 60                          ":n`":n`
$ jelly f quine.gs 2> /dev/null | xxd -g 1
$
$ golfscript mpquine | tee quine.jelly | xxd -g 1
0000000: ff cc cc                                         ...
$ jelly f quine.jelly | xxd -g 1
0000000: ff cc cc                                         ...
$ golfscript quine.jelly | xxd -g 1
0000000: 0a
```

### Jelly

With [Jelly's code page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page), the program looks as follows.

```
:n"”ṘṘ"}
“":n`”;
```

This prints ([Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=Om4i4oCd4bmY4bmYIn0K4oCcIjpuYOKAnTs&input=))

```
":n`":n`
```

which is a quine in GolfScript ([Try it online!](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=IjpuYCI6bmA&input=)), but a parser error in Jelly ([Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=IjpuYCI6bmA&input=)).

### GolfScript

In Latin-1, the program looks as follows, with an unprintable DEL character between `}` and `þ`.

```
:n"ÿÌÌ"} þ":n`ÿ;
```

This prints ([Try it online!](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=Om4iw7_DjMOMIn1_w74iOm5gw787&input=))

```
ÿÌÌ
```

or, visualized with Jelly's code page,

```
”ṘṘ
```

which is a quine in Jelly ([Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCd4bmY4bmY&input=)), but only prints a linefeed in GolfScript ([Try it online!](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=w7_DjMOM&input=)).

Comment: Good old `”ṘṘ`, thus `ØV` should be gone, right?

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript / C 278 bytes

At a staggering 278 bytes:

```
//\
console.log('int main(){char*A="int main(){char*A=%c%s%c;printf(A,34,A,34);}";printf(A,34,A,34);}');/*
int main(){puts("A='A=;B=String.fromCharCode(39);console.log(A.slice(0,2)+B+A+B+A.slice(2));';B=String.fromCharCode(39);console.log(A.slice(0,2)+B+A+B+A.slice(2));");}//*/
```

The C quine:

`int main(){char*A="int main(){char*A=%c%s%c;printf(A,34,A,34);}";printf(A,34,A,34);}`

The JavaScript quine:

`A='A=;B=String.fromCharCode(39);console.log(A.slice(0,2)+B+A+B+A.slice(2));';B=String.fromCharCode(39);console.log(A.slice(0,2)+B+A+B+A.slice(2));`

Comment: Holy mother of quines...

Answer (score 3):

## Befunge / Fission, 35 bytes

```
"$TQ-#'">,#-:#2_@;"+1_@#`+66:,g0:"L
```

[Try it in Befunge](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=IiRUUS0jJyI-LCMtOiMyX0A7IisxX0AjYCs2NjosZzA6Ikw&input=) |
[Try it in Fission](http://fission.tryitonline.net/#code=IiRUUS0jJyI-LCMtOiMyX0A7IisxX0AjYCs2NjosZzA6Ikw&input=)

In Befunge this produces the [Fission quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/50968/8478):

```
'!+OR"
```

In Fission this produces the [Befunge quine](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Quine#Befunge):

```
:0g,:66+`#@_1+
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python / Retina, <s>70</s> <s>65</s> <s>64</s> 66 bytes

I used the same strategy I used in [my previous Python / Retina polyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/56011/34718).

```
#
print"\nS`((.+))"*2+"\n\n"
#?
#_='_=%r;%_\n';_
#?;
#;print _%
#
```

[**Try in Python**](https://repl.it/EU80/3) | [**Try in Retina**](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=IwpwcmludCJcblNgKCguKykpIioyKyJcblxuIgojPwojXz0nXz0lcjslX1xuJztfCiM_OwojO3ByaW50IF8lCiMK&input=)

`#` is a comment in Python, so it simply prints the Retina quine in Python. In Retina, the first stage (2 lines) does nothing, because no `#` will be found in the input. The next stage replaces nothing with the basis of the Python quine. The third stage replaces each semicolon with the `#print _%` piece. The last stage removes all `#`'s.

---

**Quine in Retina:**

```
S`((.+))
S`((.+))
```

**Quine in Python:**

```python
_='_=%r;print _%%_\n';print _%_
```

The quines used may be seen in [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good). The Retina quine is an error in Python, and the Python quine has no output in Retina.

Comment: Can you add an explanation to your answer for how the metaquine works?

Comment: @Pavel Added it.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3 / Python 2, 62 bytes

```python
_='_=%r;print(_%%_['+'~'*-~int(-1/2)+'int(-1/2):])';print(_%_)
```

Try it in [Python 2](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@x9vqx5vq1pkXVCUmVeiEa@qGh@trq1ep66lWwcS0DXUN9LUVoczrWI11eFq4zX//wcA), [Python 3](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@x9vqx5vq1pkXVCUmVeiEa@qGh@trq1ep66lWwcS0DXUN9LUVoczrWI11eFq4zX//wcA).

Based on the Python quine [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115/16766). The distinguishing factor between the two versions is what they do with `int(-1/2)`: in Python 2, `/` is integer division (rounding down), with a result of `-1`; in Python 3, `/` is floating point division (`-0.5`), which `int` truncates to `0`.

We build a string `_` in three parts. `'_=%r;print(_%%_['` and `'int(-1/2):])'` are always the same. The interesting part is `'~'*-~int(-1/2)`:

- In Python 2, `-~int(-1/2)` is `0`, and the tilde is not added to the string;
- In Python 3, `-~int(-1/2)` is `1`, and the tilde is added to the string.

Thus, Python 2 outputs the [Python 3 quine](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@x9vqx5vq1pkXVCUmVeiEa@qGh8NYuga6htpWsVqqsMlUMX//wcA)

```python
_='_=%r;print(_%%_[int(-1/2):])';print(_%_[int(-1/2):])
```

and Python 3 outputs the [Python 2 quine](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@x9vqx5vq1pkXVCUmVeiEa@qGh9dB2LpGuobaVrFaqrDZdAk/v8HAA)

```python
_='_=%r;print(_%%_[~int(-1/2):])';print(_%_[~int(-1/2):])
```

In each version, the expression inside `[ :]` evaluates to `0`, which makes the slice include the entire string, whereas in the wrong language it evaluates to `-1`, which makes the slice include only the last character, truncating the output so it's not a full quine.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers) <s>4617</s> 4009 bytes

```
((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((()()()())))()())[()()])))()()())[()()])))())[()])[()()()()])))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))()()())()())[()()()()])()()())[()()])()())[()()()()])()()()))()()())[()()])[()()()()])))))))))))))))))))()())))()()())[()()()()])()()()()())[()()]))()())[()()()])()())[()()])))()()())[()()])))())[()()])[()()()])))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))()()()())[()()()])()()()())[()()])[()()()]))()()()())[()()()])()()()())[()()])[()()()])()()()())[()()()])()()()())[()()])[()()()]))))))))))))))()()()())[()()()])()()()())[()()])[()()()]))()()()())[()()()])()()()())[()()])[()()()])))))))))))))))))))))))))))))()()()())[()()()])()()()())[()()])[()()()]))()()()())[()()()])()()()()()))))))[()()()])[()])()()))))()()){({}<>)<>}<>([]){({}[()]<(({}[()]<((((((()()()){}())){}{}){}())<>)>)<>){({}[()]<({}()())>){({}[()]<({}())>){({}[()]<({}((()()()){}()){})>){({}[()]<({}()())>){({}[()]<({}(((()()()){}()){}){}())>){(<{}({}()())>)}}}}}}{}([]<({}<{({}<>)<>}<>>)>){({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}{({}[()]<(({}))>)}{}(((({})(((()()())){}{}){}())))<>>)}{}{<>({}<>)}{+++++++>>>+>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+++>>>++++>>>++>>>+++>>>++++>>>++++++++>>>+++>>>++++>>>+>>>+++++>>>++++++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>+>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+++++>>>+>>>++>>>++++++>>>+++>>>+>>>+>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+++++>>>+>>>++>>>++++++>>>+++>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>++>>>+++>>>++++>>>++>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>++>>>++++>>>++>>>+++>>>++++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>+>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+++++>>>+>>>++>>>++++++>>>+++>>>+>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>++++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>+>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+++++>>>+>>>++>>>++++++>>>+++>>>+>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>++++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>+>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+++++>>>+>>>++>>>++++++>>>+++>>>+>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>++++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>+>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+++++>>>+>>>++>>>++++++>>>+++>>>+>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>++++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>+>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+++++>>>+>>>++>>>++++++>>>+++>>>+>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>++++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>+>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+++++>>>+>>>++>>>++++++>>>+++>>>+>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>++>>>++++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>+>>>+++>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>++++>>>++>>>++++++++>>>++++++++>>>++++++++>>>++++++++>>>++++++++>>>++++++++>>>++++++++>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+>>>+++++>>>++++++>>>+++>>>+>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+++>>>+++++++>>>+>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+++>>>++++>>>++>>>+++>>>++++>>>++++++++>>>+++>>>++++>>>++++>>>++>>>++++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>+>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+++++>>>+>>>++>>>++++++>>>+++>>>+>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+++>>>++++>>>++>>>+++>>>++++>>>++++>>>++>>>++++++++>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+++++++>>>+>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+++++>>>+>>>++>>>++++++>>>+++>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+++++>>>+>>>++>>>++++++>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>++>>>++++>>>++>>>++++++++>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+++>>>++++>>>++++>>>++>>>++++++++>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+++>>>++++>>>+++++++>>>+>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+++>>>++++>>>++>>>+++>>>++++>>>++++++++>>>+++>>>++++>>><<<[<<<]>>>[>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.<[->.+.->+<<]>+.[-]>>]<[<<<]>>>[<++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>-[<+>-[<+++++++++++++++++++>-[<++>-[<+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>-[<++>-[<++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>-[<++>-]]]]]]]<.>>>>]}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#7VYLisQgDL2ORfQEQdhziCcRz96J2vpr/XXaHZadDG1jkvdiEsFZyf@Sxf9Q3Efat9pW@drqyht246hsZJHRE@Q5Kt4iqpk/qeSMK6soDVFDxSfp54svk5FT0onYGdpf2M7zHSAbW3DIMLh99JpoA2IBgW8ilVvbKCBRiad@0cZitdHGqwi14ARmzegoTaUhI0S2PsUBEmgBtYAxTnApHQzSAkXB6ewIwXrSsh2Nz4iLmDipewlAbJsjMpp6EUK4J64ydTO4z9FSidx9ISaBD@RMAnKGYH8b3HqGlcY2rnsODT9J2R7KjX0@Bbb28WzWgSn1mjw3k8@V@lc6PdS1b8vvafnTx71bc7t/bzX2VrWyu5mRTAz90h1JP3DM@lutD6VqvOUuniUYuhR7FVwu/TDeBw4IAEh8FKoyBPWEg2SCU84EtVDKJUMCFZlglEkwjHWviq/mnA4LccoLcNyoUPhndV1X9vMC)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brainfuck#7VYLzoMgDL4OxsgJGi5COAnh7P6lKC/l5XTLsr@LWtp@X2lLwlb2WzK5Hwp9pH2rbZWura6cYTf2ykYWGB1BmqPgzaKq@aNKzriSiuIQ1VV8lH68@DwZOyUdiB2hfcN2nu8A29i8Q/rB7aPXTBsQEwh8M6lobaOABSWc@kkbi9VGG6ci1IIjmDWjIzflhoQQ2doUB4inBdQ8xpDgUhIM4gJFxkl2hGA9cdlE4zLiIiSO6p48ENtGREbPToQQ9IRVom4G@hwthcjd52MieEfOKCBl8PaXwbWnW6ls47rn0PCTlPWh3NjnU2BtH89m7ZhSq8ljM/lcqd/S6a6u/bf8npY/fdybNdf791Jjb1ULuxsZycDQL92R8weOWXur5aEUjbfcxaMEXZdiq4LLpR/G@8ABAQCJj0JV@qCWcJCL4DNfxGyhM5cLEqjABL1MYsFYehV8JedwmI9TToDjRoXCP6vr@gc)

Explanation is on its way I am still golfing this

Comment: This generates a brainfuck quine in brainfuck, and a Brain-Flak quine in Brain-Flak. It *should* generate a brainfuck quine when run in Brain-Flak and a Brain-Flak quine when run in brainfuck.

Comment: I will do it again.  I am sorry I just have a hard time following the As and Bs