# Wait, what language is this?

Tags: code-challenge, decision-problem, polyglot, haskell

Recently I had the pleasure of writing a Haskell program that could detect if the `NegativeLiterals` extension was engaged.  I came up with the following:

```hs
data B=B{u::Integer}
instance Num B where{fromInteger=B;negate _=B 1}
main=print$1==u(-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcqxCsIwEADQvV9xg4MOHbJWbskmSGc3Oeo1DSanXC46lP66EcE3v4XKnVNq7UZG4NGvdRhOYhxYty5KMZKJYawZPLwXVl5nfeT/QH8UDmQMV/Tgti5TFHxqFNs5xLrv3aG1zzQnCqX1l/GX44vP0VgplS8)

This will print `True` normally and `False` otherwise.

Now I had so much fun doing this I'm extending the challenge to all of you.  What other Haskell language extensions can you crack?

### Rules

To crack a particular language extension you must write a Haskell program that compiles both with and without the language extension (warnings are fine) and outputs two different *non-error* values when run with the language extension and it turned off (by adding the `No` prefix to the language extension).  In this way the code above could be shortened to just:

```hs
data B=B{u::Integer}
instance Num B where{fromInteger=B;negate _=B 1}
main=print$u(-1)
```

which prints `1` and `-1`.

Any method you use to crack a extension must be specific to that extension.  There may be ways of arbitrarily detecting what compiler flags or LanguageExtensions are enabled, if so such methods are not allowed.  You may enable additional language extensions or change the compiler optimization using `-O` at no cost to your byte count.

### Language extensions

You cannot crack any language extension that does not have a `No` counterpart (e.g. `Haskell98`, `Haskell2010`, `Unsafe`, `Trustworthy`, `Safe`) because these do not fall under the terms outlined above.  Every other language extension is fair game.

### Scoring

You will be awarded one point for every language extensions you are the first person to crack and one additional point for every language extension for which you have the shortest (measured in bytes) crack. For the second point ties will be broken in favor of earlier submissions.  Higher score is better

You will not be able to score a point for first submission on `NegativeLiterals` or `QuasiQuotes` because I have already cracked them and included them in the body of the post.  You will however be able to score a point for the shortest crack of each of these.  Here is my crack of `QuasiQuotes`

```hs
import Text.Heredoc
main=print[here|here<-""] -- |]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRCEktaJEzyO1KDUlP5krNzEzz7agKDOvJDoDKFQDImx0lZRiFXR1FWpi////l5yWk5he/F83IrA0sTgzsDS/JLUYAA)

Comment: Can programs take input?

Comment: Can we require more than one extension, but only toggle one

Comment: @H.PWiz programs should not take input.  You may require additional language extensions if you wish.

Comment: I think [this](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Pz0jOVNBV7c4I79cN7@gJDM/r1ihRiG9KLVAQTdAQT1Cw17RL19THSiWkZqYoqCbp6Br9v8/AA) is a list of all valid options

Comment: Note that my above comment does not include `NondecreasingIndentation` for obvious reasons

Comment: If certain circumstances raise an exception and the program can recover from it (printing a message to stderr), is this acceptable behaviour? Asking because of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153774/48198).

Comment: @BMO You are free to print to STDERR during compilation for warnings but at run time STDERR should be empty.

Comment: How should other flags be scored? See the comments [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153781/56433) for context.

Comment: I'd suggest that language extensions *other* than the one you're testing for should count for bytes. Mostly because I'm disappointed about all the `TemplateHaskell` use I see here.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen In retrospect it might not have been a good idea to let all language extensions get by for free, but I don't intend to change the rules now.

Comment: I think you should drop the requirement for a `No` counterpart. I'm not sure, but I think there might be at least one game to play with safe Haskell.

Comment: @dfeuer The problem with extensions that don't have `No` counter part is it is hard to tell what we should be comparing it to. `No` counterparts make it nice and clear.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic, in those cases, compare to the effect of not giving the option. The same goes for `No` options without a positive counterpart, if there are any.

Comment: I'm quite curious whether it's possible to crack `RelaxedPolyRec`, for a compiler ancient enough to *actually* support turning it off. (The option hung around, with documentation, for some years after it stopped doing anything.)

Comment: @dfeuer I don't have an old compiler to check, but would ``x=0^y;y=seq(x/)0;y::Int`` work? (Needs `NoMonomorphismRestriction`.)

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, my intuition for `NoRelaxedPolyRec` is rather poor. The description of the restriction in the Haskell 98 Report is just awful.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, I'm really not sure. GHC is the only compiler I've been able to find that (at one point) claimed to be able to turn the extension on and off. As far as I can tell, there's no way to turn it on in Gofer, and the only way I've found to (maybe!) turn it off in Hugs also disables all other extensions. I don't see any mention of it in the nhc98 docs. It's probably still possible to get some really old GHC versions....

Comment: @dfeuer ``x()=0^y;y=seq(x()/)0;y::Int`` ought to work without `NoMonomorphismRestriction`. However, changing between Hugs and Haskell 98 mode (which I'm guessing you mean) doesn't change the result. :(

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. That was the only option I saw that looked like it *might* disable the extension. I could've missed something though.

Comment: @dfeuer Looking at [this ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3819) it seems like GHC 6.12.1 supported turning it off.

Comment: Are we allowed to print more than one value?

Comment: @dfeuer What does it mean to print more than one value?

Comment: For example, to print two numbers, one on each line. Also, we need an answer about whether the output is allowed to be empty, or just a newline, sometimes. Do the things printed have to represent Haskell values, or can they be arbitrary strings?

Comment: @dfeuer Yeah, I don't care whether things are haskell values or how many lines they are on etc.  As long as the outputs are different and non-error. (output to STDERR or non-zero exit code)

Comment: What are the rules about compiler flags (e.g., `-O`)?

Comment: @dfeuer I'd like to say that you can use whatever flags you want at no cost, but I am pretty sure there are ways that you can just write all your code as flags and thus "score" zero bytes.  I went ahead and said you can use the various `-O`s at no additional cost, if there is any other flags you or any one else would like me to add I'd probably do so.

Comment: Incidentally, solutions to this challenge demonstrate the importance of keeping language extensions behind pragmas

Answer (score 27):

## MagicHash, 30 bytes

```hs
x=1
y#a=2
x#a=1
main=print$x#x
```

[-XMagicHash](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v8LWkKtSOdHWiKsCSBpy5SZm5tkWFGXmlahUKFf8//8vOS0nMb34v26Eb2J6ZrJHYnEGAA) outputs 1, [-XNoMagicHash](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v8LWkKtSOdHWiKsCSBpy5SZm5tkWFGXmlahUKFf8//8vOS0nMb34v26EX75vYnpmskdicQYA) outputs 2

MagicHash allows variable names to terminate in a `#`. Therefore with the extension, this defines two functions `y#` and `x#` which each take a value and return a constant `2`, or `1`. `x#x` will return 1 (because it is `x#` applied to `1`)

Without the extension, this defines one function `#` which takes two arguments and returns `2`. The `x#a=1` is a pattern that never gets reached. Then `x#x` is `1#1`, which returns 2.

## 29 bytes

```hs
a=1
a#b=a
main|a<-0=print$a#0
```

Comment: I'm now singing *X Magic Hash* to the tune of *Dance Magic Dance*. I hope you're proud!

Comment: I'm astonished that `MagicHash` doesn't allow non-trailing hashes. Weird!

Answer (score 20):

## CPP, <s>33</s> 20 bytes

```hs
main=print$0-- \
 +1
```

Prints `0` with [`-XCPP`](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oCgzr0TFQFdXIYZLQdvw//9/yWk5ienF/3UjnAMCAA) and `1` with [`-XNoCPP`](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oCgzr0TFQFdXIYZLQdvw//9/yWk5ienF/3Uj/PKdAwIA).

With `-XCPP`, a slash `\` before a newline removes the newline, thus the code becomes `main=print$0--  +1` and only `0` is printed as the `+1` is now part of the comment.

Without the flag the comment is ignored and the second line is parsed as a part of the previous line because it is indented.

---

#### Previous approach with `#define`

```hs
x=1{-
#define x 0
-}
main=print x
```

Also prints `0` with [`-XCPP`](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v8LWsFqXSzklNS0zL1WhQsGAS7eWKzcxM8@2oCgzr0Sh4v//f8lpOYnpxf91I5wDAgA) and `1` with [`-XNoCPP`](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v8LWsFqXSzklNS0zL1WhQsGAS7eWKzcxM8@2oCgzr0Sh4v//f8lpOYnpxf91I/zynQMCAA).

Comment: Oh god, until now I kind of thought GHC would strip Haskell comments before passing over to the CPP.

Comment: @Cubic Is it not a *pre*-processor?

Comment: @Bergi Sure, but _pre_-processors doesn't necessarily mean "is the first thing that runs", especially since GHC has to make a pass over the file first to even find the pragma. I guess comments are kept in so doc comments and the like work after CPP is done.

Answer (score 15):

## NumDecimals, 14 bytes

```hs
main=print 1e1
```

[-XNumDecimals](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oCgzr0TBMNXw//9/yWk5ienF/3Uj/EpzXVKTM3MTc4oB) prints `10`. [-XNoNumDecimals](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oCgzr0TBMNXw//9/yWk5ienF/3Uj/PL9SnNdUpMzcxNzigE) prints `10.0`.

Answer (score 14):

## BinaryLiterals, 57 bytes

```hs
b1=1
instance Show(a->b)where;show _=""
main=print$(+)0b1
```

[-XBinaryLiterals](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P8nQ1pArM6@4JDEvOVUhOCO/XCNR1y5JszwjtSjVuhjIV4i3VVLiyk3MzLMtKMrMK1HR0NY0SDL8//9fclpOYnrxf90Ip8y8xKJKn8yS1KLEnGIA) prints a single newline. [-XNoBinaryLiterals](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P8nQ1pArM6@4JDEvOVUhOCO/XCNR1y5JszwjtSjVuhjIV4i3VVLiyk3MzLMtKMrMK1HR0NY0SDL8//9fclpOYnrxf90Iv3ynzLzEokqfzJLUosScYgA) prints a `1`.

I am sure there is a better way to do this. If you find one, please post it.

Comment: Can't you just define `b` as a function (so no binary becomes `b(0, 1)`, but binary becomes `0b1`)?

Answer (score 13):

## MonomorphismRestriction + 7 others, 107 bytes

This uses TH which requires the flag `-XTemplateHaskell` at all times.

#### File T.hs, 81 + 4 bytes

```hs
module T where
import Language.Haskell.TH
p=(+)
t=reify(mkName"p")>>=stringE.show
```

#### Main, 22 bytes

```hs
import T
main=print $t
```

Compiling with the flag [MonomorphismRestriction](https://tio.run/##rZBLC8IwEITv@ytCEVHECJ7b3hQPPkBy8FCQWNcm2DxIIsVfX9v66F26x1nmm2Eu3Iu6znkgKWFUeBLHq8MalLk@SiSMVAIdglTWuEC2XBcPXiDdcH/HsqRsAzaZzKYQEofy9pyo@54rjGw0TdPEByd1saJemApaKrxzdlzqPurDZqAaObGNJZBsFHpDVysdL6H73Uh0/ucynemow3TQb4chuVCI/AeenxgqW/KAn7EaZWe0UcZZIb06YjtPHqTRg5agi7ZBXb8A) forces the type of `p` to `Integer -> Integer -> Integer` and thus produces the following output:

```hs
"VarI T.p (AppT (AppT ArrowT (ConT GHC.Integer.Type.Integer)) (AppT (AppT ArrowT (ConT GHC.Integer.Type.Integer)) (ConT GHC.Integer.Type.Integer))) Nothing"
```

Compiling with the flag [NoMonomorphismRestriction](https://tio.run/##rZBLC8IwEITv@ytCEVHECJ7b3hQPPkBy8FCQWNcm2DxIUoq/vra16l3c4yzzzTAX7kXT5DyQlDAqPInj1WENylyrEgkjtUCHIJU1LpAt10XFC6Qb7u9YlpRtwCaT2RRC4lDeHhN133OFkY2maZr44KQuVtQLU0NHhVfOjkv9jRrYDFQrJ7a1BJKNwtfQ10rHS@h/NxKdf7lMZzrqMT303eGfXChE/gHPTwyVLXnAYaxW2Zud0UYZZ4X06ojdQHmQRv@1Bl10HZrmCQ) leaves the type of `p` at the most general, ie. `Num a => a->a->a` - producing something like (shortened the `VarT` names to `a`):

```hs
"VarI T.p (ForallT [KindedTV a StarT] [AppT (ConT GHC.Num.Num) (VarT a)] (AppT (AppT ArrowT (VarT a)) (AppT (AppT ArrowT (VarT a)) (VarT a)))) Nothing"
```

[Try them online!](https://tio.run/##rZBPq8IwEMTv@ymWIqKIPXi2vSk9@Ackh3coPGJdm2CTDUmK@Omr1ufzKIh7nGV@M8xeBtV1lYyYo0hVwPl8sV2C4UPbEAo8K/IE2jj2EVfS1q2sKS1kOFHTpKIAl40mY4iZJ328jMxpIw0lLhnneRai17ZepEHxGe5UeOSspbavqD@2AHOTM3ezRCwH8WXoa@XDGfS/Iya/n1xpS5v0mB767PBNLvjWqscyOP0RZFwjIxX/yobXbNmwd0oHs6P7PlXUbJ9tgCrF7yhvGF13BQ)

---

### Alternatives

Since the above code simply prints out the type of `p`, this can be done with all flags that somehow influence how Haskell infers types. I will only specify the flag and with what to replace the function `p` and if needed additional flags (besides `-XTemplateHaskell`):

#### OverloadedLists, 106 bytes

Additionally needs `-XNoMonomorphismRestriction`:

```hs
p=[]
```

Either `p :: [a]` or `p :: IsList l => l`, [try them online!](https://tio.run/##rZA/T8MwEMX3@xRWhBAMZOjcZCvK0D9S5QGJIGSSa2zV9ln2hYpPH1qX0okFuPE9vd97ujeV9DR1ikUtZKmTmM8Xm0dw1I8WhRQHjRHBuECRxVL5YVQDlo1Ke7S2lA2E6vkFuIpodh93br9WDotQ3Nd1lTgaPyzKpOkAJyica1bK@GvTF1qCO8pVOEZYtDd8DeRV9e0MsrcTxetvrvWtLzImQy8b/pMLcfT6/Bjx8CTRBasYm29lTSvy5CgGbZLb4uk/HRvy2du8Y7SkeuyXJnG6LATsNP2F/AN3mj4B)

#### OverloadedStrings, 106 bytes

Additionally needs `-XNoMonomorphismRestriction`:

```hs
p=""
```

Either `p :: String` or `p :: IsString s => s`, [try them online!](https://tio.run/##rZAxT8MwEIX3@xWWhRAMZGBushVloK0EHhgioSO5xlZtn2U7VPz60LqUTizAje/0vvf03jDpee4xi0aoSiexWCw3D@B4mCwJJfaaIoFxgWMWj@jHCUeqWkw7srZSLYRaSsh1JLP9uHG7NTqSQd42TZ1yNH5cVknzHo5QOMWs0PhL0hdagTvIdThYsuiu8sVQWjXX91B@WyFff3Od77wsmAI9d/hPLsTJ69Mw4u5FkQsWM7XfyppX7NlxDNok90THffps2Jff5p2iZRxoeC67pXNHoF7zX9g/kuf5Ew)

#### PolyKinds, 112 bytes

This is entirely due to  @CsongorKiss:

```hs
data P a=P
```

Either `P :: P a` or `P :: forall k (a :: k). P a`, [try them online!](https://tio.run/##rZA9i8JAEIb7@RVDkOOuMMXVJp1HwK8UW1gEZDRjdnE/wu4G8ddHjacWFsJxU77D@zzDbCnIvt9RxBxFKgNOJtPVDxhXd5pR4FGyZ1CmdT7inGzTUcNpQeHAWqeigJoiYYmUlRAzz2p/@jSHJRlOyuQrz7MQvbLNNA3SHeGKhptsQco@fb8CAeYSZ@2lErEaxWdhuC3/@IZht8dk85epbGWTATNA7zf8Jxd8Z@XtPTheCzatpsjFI1m60unTTNk63P3AO@ne9V5afX8G)

#### MonadComprehensions, 114 bytes

```hs
p x=[i|i<-x]
```

Either `p :: [a] -> [a]` or `p :: Monad m => m a -> m a`, [try them online!](https://tio.run/##rZBBS8NAEIXv8yuGIKKH5uA5yUUqOdh62YPQiIztNLs0O7vsbmgL/vdYU2tvLYhzfMP73uN9UNTDsKSEFapcRyyK6csTWLfqO0aFW82BwVjvQsJnkranlvOa4oa7Llc1eNyVC/NpisnuDVIZ2Kz3d3YzJ8uZz@6rqowpGGmnedRuC99wOMbNyMg58SdCgT3IpT9YEjY36WwY21W3DzD@1pi9/@UaaSQbMSP01OE/uRB60ceBcPKq2PqOEte/ytzNnNDq0VkfWLNE4ySemgAvtbtGuOAfhi8)

#### NamedWildCards, 114 bytes

This one was found by @Laikoni, it additionally requires `-XPartialTypeSignatures`:

```hs
p=id::_a->_a
```

They both have the save type (`p :: a -> a`) but GHC generates different names for the variables, [try them online!](https://tio.run/##rZA/a8MwEMX3@xTClNIO8ZAxxFpKioc2KVTQDgZzjS6WiP4hyYR8etdxmmbpFHrjO97vPd4XJjUMW8yMM1GqxJbL1eYZrJe9ISbYQVEk0Db4mNkLuq7Hjsoa056MKUUNodJysWhxxluEXEXSu@OD3a/RUhGKR86rlKN23apMyh/gBIdz3Ctqd038iRBgR7kKoyWz5i5fDVM7fj@H6bdjRXvLNa5xxYSZoJcO/8mF2Dt1HojNPgXZYDBT/au8YcwajTgGetedw9xHSqO@9qfR5Ic28gmjTJdyQFvlb4b@iRyGbw)

#### ApplicativeDo, 120 bytes

```hs
p x=do i<-x;pure i
```

Either `p :: Monad m => m a -> m a` or `p :: Functor f => f a -> f a`, [try them online!](https://tio.run/##rZBNa8JAEIbv8yuGIFIPyaFXk4CgkoPVyx48BMpWx@zifrG78ePXp2ms9VIoFOc4w/M@L/PBg@i6HY9YIstEwDxfbJag7b5VhAzPgjyB1M76iCtumpY3lFU8HEmpjFXg8FLsLco8vUxd6wklxMKTPFxf9HHNNSUumZRlEaKXpllkQdgzfCngJn3j0jy83yIGul8Xrkci1qP4AIaO5fgVhtsBk/f/TG1qkwwxQ@i9wzNzwbdG3N6E6ZaRdopHqn42aztzTsleL080t/cOQDth/2J/JbvuEw)

#### OverloadedLabels, 120 bytes

This needs the additional flag `-XFlexibleContexts`:

```hs
p x=(#id)x
(#)=seq
```

Either types as `p :: a -> b -> b` or `p :: IsLabel "id" (a->b) => a -> b`, [try them online!](https://tio.run/##rZA9b4MwEIb3@xUWqSoYwtA5sFSJGNJk8dABqTrCBVvxV23T0F9PKWmaqUvUG9/TPc@razCIcTxgZCXjuQhstVrvN6Bt2ytinJ0FeQKpnfWRbdF0PXaUVxhOpFTOK3BsKNKFbLMB0kVWBHqHWHiSx89Un3aoKXFJVpZFiF6abp0HYc/wrYCL9AWluXl/RBz0FBduOomsfoi3g7lj@fgE8@7Ikrd7pja1SWbMDL12@E8u@N6Iy5vY8pWTdgojVb/JRtEgG0XP1kQaYpiind1/kFcWW2q32JAK12ZAB2HvIP7FG8cv)

Comment: Does a similar thing work for other flags?

Comment: Yeah, you could do it with `OverloadedStrings` or `OverloadedLists` for sure and probably others as well..

Comment: It also works with `PolyKinds`:
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY29CsIwFEb3PMVFhOpg3iCdKhSU4pDB9WqvTWh@SpJS@vTRUuni4PpxzvkeGFXO9FQeCuvb0RBImBQFYtoOPiS4outG7IjXGHsyhsuatZgQKkBRsSQC6dd8sH2DlnbV7liWIqagXXfmUfmpgBIkV5Gx9eWblcyidmL4gAn2aaGWYQHD6NT6Bae7JDsYTFRvy82b@aJdGzdhDRf/xMb/qDm/AQ "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: Also seems to work with `NamedWildCards`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZA/a8MwEMX3@xTClNIO8ZAxxFpKioc2KVTQDgZzjS6WiP4hyYR8etdxmmbpFHrjO97vPd4XJjUMW8yMM1GqxJbL1eYZrJe9ISbYQVEk0Db4mNkLuq7Hjsoa056MKUUNYbFoccZbhFBpCbmKpHfHB7tfo6UiFI@cVylH7bpVmZQ/wAkP58BX1O6a@RMiwI5yFUZLZs1dvhqmfvx@DtNvx4r2lmtc44oJM0EvHf6TC7F36jwRm30KssFgpvpXecOYNRpxDPSuO4e5j5RGfe1Po8kPbeQTRpku5YC2yt8M/RM5DN8 "Bash – Try It Online") (Requires `-XPartialTypeSignatures`)

Answer (score 11):

## ScopedTypeVariables, <s>162</s> 113 bytes

```
instance Show[()]where show _=""
p::forall a.(Show a,Show[a])=>a->IO()
p a=(print::Show a=>[a]->IO())[a]
main=p()
```

[-XScopedTypeVariables](https://tio.run/##TY5BCsIwEEX3PUXoKgHrAQIpiCh05aIighQZ42iDMQlJwHp5Y2pddDfz/5vh9RAeqHVKyoQIRiJpe/s6Uda9evRIQt7IWZRl4Ti/WQ9aE1jSESKw@LHQMVFDVTc7ygpHQFDnlYmcT5CoMzG1LE/FE5QRjrKUPvKm4R5SddxqHNRFY/OXmGdrayIOcYw2g9NKqri1fpWdq2NjpB01TZxfttI6vO7fDg/gFeQf4Qs) prints `""` (empty), [-XNoScopedTypeVariables](https://tio.run/##TY5BCsIwEEX3PUXoKgHrAQIpiFjoyoWbghQZQ2qD0yQkgfb0xtSKuPvz5314I4SnQkxJmxDBSEUuo52vlPXzqLwiIV/kJsqycJwP1gMigT1dIQK7Dws9EzVUdXumrHAEBHVem8j5Bok6E9uX5VRMoI1wlKX0kgPCI6Sqa1At@o6q/Ur8d0drolriWp0Wh1rq2Fh/yM5V1xppV00Tf8s3) prints `"[()]"`.

Edit: updated solution thanks to useful suggestions in the comments

Comment: Ah I see.  Its generally nicer to include your code in the body, but ungolfed versions are nice as well.  I'm also noticing that `"T"` can just be replaced with `""`.

Comment: Another thing you can do is replace your datatype `T` with `()`. To avoid having to define it. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/NCsIwEITvfYqgHlowPkAhBZGKvVSwIoKIrHW1wZiEJGBFfHVj6g94m5n9FmYasGcUwnsurQNZ4532i3Iyn@WLvFz26aNq1HUTJ9trgwaJDY7sWK8X6TQ9KgNCEBjFHURg@GZhm7AMaFY5w@Up0gRY3L2l6YdiWUB@5yTo6AJcMh2sG@g48f5ZHwWcrKfrqcCW7wUW33L/2URJh63rorzVgtfcTZUZhy10XdVK42F507gCwyHQ9gU "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: Nice catch, I just realised that the incoherent pragma can be included as a flag: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7NCsIwEITvfYogHlqwPkAgBRELPVekIEXWuG2DMQlJoPXljak/0NvOzDfLDODuKGUIQjkPiiOpBz2e06wdB7RIXFTkwlarxFDaaQtSEtimM0Rg82GhzVgBeVF7K1SfGAIsnWuUfilWROQfZ/FOHiAUM1H6tUmzEF68k9C7kDelxElcJVa/NUtvr5XHyc/WYTJScOFLbXdxfN5Uiut5r/LLZs21wdvxafAEVkD84d4 "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: Additionally `show`  can be changed for [print](https://tio.run/##TY5BCsIwEEX3PUXoKgHrAQIpiCh05aIighQZ42iDMQlJwHp5Y2pddDfz/5vh9RAeqHVKyoQIRiJpe/s6Uda9evRIQt7IWZRl4Ti/WQ9aE1jSESKw@LHQMVFDVTc7ygpHQFDnlYmcT5CoMzG1LE/FE5QRjrKUPvKm4R5SddxqHNRFY/OXmGdrayIOcYw2g9NKqri1fpWdq2NjpB01TZxfttI6vO7fDg/gFeQf4Qs)

Comment: Unicode syntax for `forall` will save you a few bytes. I doubt any solution that needs extra instances has much hope of winning, though.

Answer (score 11):

## CPP, <s>27</s> 25

```
main=print({-/*-}1{-*/-})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oCgzr0SjWldfS7fWsFpXS1@3VvP//3/JaTmJ6cX/dSOcAwIA)

Prints `()` for `-XCPP` and `1` for `-XNoCPP`

***Previous version:***

```
main=print[1{-/*-},2{-*/-}]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oCgzryTasFpXX0u3VseoWldLX7c29v//f8lpOYnpxf91I5wDAgA)

Prints `[1]` with `-XCPP` and `[1,2]` otherwise.

Credits: This is inspired by Laikoni's answer, but instead of a `#define` it simply uses C comments.

Answer (score 9):

## BangPatterns, 32 bytes

```hs
(!)=seq
main|let f!_=0=print$9!1
```

[-XBangPatterns](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/X0NR07Y4tZArNzEzryYntUQhTTHe1sC2oCgzr0TFUtHw//9/yWk5ienF/3UjnBLz0gMSS0pSi/KKAQ) prints `1` whereas [-XNoBangPatterns](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/X0NR07Y4tZArNzEzryYntUQhTTHe1sC2oCgzr0TFUtHw//9/yWk5ienF/3Uj/PKdEvPSAxJLSlKL8ooB) will print `0`.

This makes use that the flag BangPatterns allows to annotate patterns with a `!` to force evaluation to WHNF, in that case `9!1` will use the top-level definition `(!)=seq`. If the flag is not enabled `f!_` defines a new operator `(!)` and shadows the top-level definition.

Answer (score 9):

## OverloadedStrings, <s>65</s> <s>48</s> 32 bytes

Taking advantage of RebindableSyntax, use our own version of fromString to turn any string literal into `"y"`.

```
main=print""
fromString _=['y']
```

Must be compiled with `-XRebindableSyntax -XImplicitPrelude`.

Without `-XOverloadedStrings` prints `""`; with prints `"y"`.

Also, it only just now struck me that the same technique works with (e.g.) OverloadedLists:

## OverloadedLists, 27 bytes

```
main=print[0]
fromListN=(:)
```

Must be compiled with `-XRebindableSyntax -XImplicitPrelude`.

Without `-XOverloadedLists` prints `[0]`; with prints `[1,0]`.

Comment: You can shorten the last line to `fromString a=['y']`.

Comment: The space in `print "n"` can also be dropped.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen thanks! I was having it fail with `="y"`, but `=['y']` works fine!

Comment: You can remove the second `n` from `print"n"`

Comment: You can also use `-XImplicitPrelude` after `RebindableSyntax` to avoid the import line.

Answer (score 9):

## MonoLocalBinds, GADTs, or TypeFamilies, <s>36</s> 32 bytes

EDIT:

- -4 bytes: A version of this was incorporated into the [great polyglot chain](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167537/) by stasoid, who surprised me by putting all the declarations at top level. Apparently triggering this restriction does not require actual *local* bindings.

```hs
a=0
f b=b^a
main=print(f pi,f 0)
```

- With [no extensions](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P9HWgCtNIck2KS6RKzcxM8@2oCgzr0QjTaEgUydNwUDz/38A), this program prints `(1.0,1)`.
- With either of the flags [-XMonoLocalBinds](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P9HWgCtNIck2KS6RKzcxM8@2oCgzr0QjTaEgUydNwUDz//9/yWk5ienF/3UjfPPz8n3ykxNznDLzUooB), [-XGADTs](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P9HWgCtNIck2KS6RKzcxM8@2oCgzr0QjTaEgUydNwUDz//9/yWk5ienF/3Uj3B1dQooB), or [-XTypeFamilies](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P9HWgCtNIck2KS6RKzcxM8@2oCgzr0QjTaEgUydNwUDz//9/yWk5ienF/3UjQioLUt0SczNzMlOLAQ), it prints `(1.0,1.0)`.
- The `MonoLocalBinds` extension exists to prevent some unintuitive type inference triggered by GADTs and type families. As such, this extension is automatically turned on by the two others.
- It *is* possible to turn it off again explicitly with `-XNoMonoLocalBinds`, this trick assumes you don't.
- Like its more well-known cousin the monomorphism restriction, `MonoLocalBinds` works by preventing some values (<s>in local bindings like `let` or `where`, thus the name</s> apparently it can also happen at top level) from being polymorphic. Despite being created for saner type inference, the [rules for when it triggers](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#let-generalisation) are if possible even more hairy than the MR.
- Without any extension, the above program infers the type `f :: Num a => a -> a`, allowing `f pi` to default to a `Double` and `f 0` to an `Integer`.
- With the extensions, the type inferred becomes `f :: Double -> Double`, and `f 0` has to return a `Double` as well.
- The separate variable `a=0` is needed to trigger the technical rules: `a` is hit by the monomorphism restriction, and `a` is a *free variable* of `f`, which means that `f`'s binding group is not *fully generalized*, which means `f` is not *closed* and thus doesn't become polymorphic.

Answer (score 9):

## [RebindableSyntax](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-RebindableSyntax), 25 bytes

I was reading the recently posted [Guide to GHC's Extensions](https://limperg.de/ghc-extensions/) when I noticed an easy one that I didn't recall seeing here yet.

```hs
main|negate<-id=print$ -1
```

- With [-XNoRebindableSyntax](https://tio.run/##DcixDkBADADQXzFYb7DzARYRFmvd1WlUiauExLcrb3wzpAWZzVYgeQQjKJaOQrUfJJpnrjB7/cQQk7mh2TocSQKMjP0tCtef9bozedL2QD4Dfg), prints `-1`.
- With [-XRebindableSyntax](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM68mLzU9sSTVRjczxbagKDOvREVB1/D//3/JaTmJ6cX/dSOCUpMy81ISk3JSgyvzShIrgEKeuQU5mcmZJQFFqTmlKakA), prints `1`.

Also requires `-XImplicitPrelude`, or alternatively `import Prelude` in the code itself.

- `-XRebindableSyntax` changes the behavior of some of Haskell's syntactic sugar to make it possible to redefine it.
- `-1` is syntactic sugar for `negate 1`.
- Normally this `negate` is `Prelude.negate`, but with the extension it's "whichever `negate` is in scope at the point of use", which is defined as `id`.
- Because the extension is meant to be used to make replacements for the `Prelude` module, it automatically disables the usual implicit import of that, but other `Prelude` functions (like `print`) are needed here, so it is re-enabled with `-XImplicitPrelude`.

Answer (score 8):

## ApplicativeDo, 146 bytes

```hs
newtype C a=C{u::Int}
instance Functor C where fmap _ _=C 1
instance Applicative C
instance Monad C where _>>=_=C 0
main=print$u$do{_<-C 0;pure 1}
```

Prints 1 when ApplicativeDo is enabled, 0 otherwise

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYyxDoIwFEV3vuINrCSyoiUxGBMGnd2al1Kksbw2tJUYwq9b6yKu555zB3QPqXWMJGf/shIaQNYsoapa8mumyHkkIeEcSHgzpXke5CShH9ECB84aKDfraK1WAr16pqMNXwxh90t5XbNvt8tGVMTspMjnIe/Mwg9FwnsbklWuMb5Fr/HuYnG7mr/rk/kA)

Comment: Thanks! Ah, I think I'm on an older version of GHC (the "no applicative" was a warning on my system)

Comment: Using -XDeriveAnyClass you can derive `Applicative` and `Show` to save using record syntax, see [this](https://tio.run/##TY69DoIwFIV3nuIODppIIrNCQiAkDk4ubs1NW6Cx3DZtgfjy1rKo4zn5zs@I/im1jlFgQGgAywauFEBIpxZFw/4@mvVYW6sVx6AWecgU@YDEJXQz8WBcSq2jdBL6CS0wYKmi@FE3Qyi@DKuqcgNO2YSKSusUhZ0wwC55Ms92TkwR45v3Ggcf88ffdGuSbrdjsqZXo9H7Dw).

Answer (score 8):

## ApplicativeDo, 104 bytes

```hs
import Control.Applicative
z=ZipList
instance Monad ZipList where _>>=_=z[]
main=print$do a<-z[1];pure a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc2xCsIwEIDhPU9xg2sFZ01BdNS9WEo50mgP09yRnAp5eKODg@vPB/@M@e5DqJUW4aRw4KiJw3ovEsih0tObYi8kJ8pqKGbF6DycOeIEvwyv2ScPY9va0ZZ@MAtStJIo6mpiwF1T@s2wlccXYa1vdw14y7Xp/iZH/gA)

With `ApplicativeDo`, this prints

```hs
ZipList {getZipList = [1]}
```

Without it, it prints

```hs
ZipList {getZipList = []}
```

`ZipList` is one of the few types in the base libraries with an instance for `Applicative` but not for `Monad`.
There may be shorter alternatives lurking somewhere.

Answer (score 8):

## BinaryLiterals, <s>31</s> 24 bytes

Edit:

- -7 bytes: H.PWiz suggested adjusting it further by using a single `b12` variable.

An adjustment to [H.PWiz's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153751/), avoiding the function instance.

```hs
b12=1
main=print$(+)0b12
```

- With [-XNoBinaryLiterals](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P8nQyNaQKzcxM8@2oCgzr0RFQ1vTACj4//@/5LScxPTi/7oRfvlOmXmJRZU@mSWpRYk5xQA),  `0b12` lexes as `0` `b12`, printing 0+1 = `1`.
- With [-XBinaryLiterals](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P8nQyNaQKzcxM8@2oCgzr0RFQ1vTACj4//@/5LScxPTi/7oRTpl5iUWVPpklqUWJOcUA), `0b12` lexes as `0b1` `2`, printing 1+2 = `3`.

Answer (score 7):

## Strict, <s>87 84</s> 82 bytes

<sup>-5 bytes thanks to [dfeuer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38603/dfeuer)!</sup>

Could be less with `BlockArguments` saving the parens around `\_->print 1`:

```hs
import Control.Exception
0!_=0
main=catch @ErrorCall(print$0!error"")(\_->print 1)
```

Running this with [-XStrict](https://tio.run/##HY0xDoJAEEV7TgHEAgoMHgCjIZxAYyxMyLiuMmHYncxOoZd3Ze3@f694E4TZEsWIC3vRvPdOxdN2eBvLit5lbTF2bbYAus6Amik/DCJeeiCqWNDppi1sImVZV7ex2f9hvqtj/JonwSvE5npSQaNpGM/2cf6wvYAg3Mkmnf6RmXAtrM3wAw) prints a `1` whereas running it with [-XNoStrict](https://tio.run/##HY0xDoJAEEV7TwHEAgoMHgCjIbQ2GGNhQsZ1lYnDzmSYQi/vCnb/v7zkDTC9PFGMOAqrJQ0HU6ZN@3ZeDDmsqrSvq9UIGGoH5oZk36qyNkCUi2KwdZX6hWRZkV/7cveHybaI8eseBM8plpcjd6bobJ6dY/H300f8GRThRn4Rln8QIZwbc3X6AQ) will print a `0`. This uses that Haskell by default is lazy and doesn't need to evaluate `error""` since it already knows that the result will be `0` when it matched on the first argument of `(!)`, this behaviour can be changed with that flag - forcing the runtime to evaluate both arguments.

If printing nothing in one case is allowed we can get it down to [**75 bytes**](https://tio.run/##FY1BDsIwDATvfUVbcYADKB@oBKr6AhDihkww1MJJLMcH@nlCc9udlWZnyB9kLoWCJLV2TNE08WH6ehSjFBvX3QfXBKA4eDA/t8dJNekIzFtRirZxHVbS97uAQWwp5edfDO9c9rezKXmrwSfB52URvIISPBjrXPtJhGlVr2f5Dw) replacing the main by (also some bytes off by [dfeuer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38603/dfeuer)):

```hs
main=catch @ErrorCall(print$0!error"")mempty
```

## StrictData, <s>106 99</s> 93 bytes

<sup>-15 bytes thanks to [dfeuer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38603/dfeuer)!</sup>

This basically does the same but works with data fields instead:

```hs
import Control.Exception
data D=D()
main=catch @ErrorCall(p$seq(D$error"")0)(\_->p 1);p=print
```

Prints `1` with the [-XStrictData](https://tio.run/##Fc2xDoIwEIDhnadoCEM7YHQ2GA3lCXRwMDGXWqXhaM/rDfryVlj/4ftHyJNHLCXMlFhUn6Jwws3wcZ4kpFg9QEDZzmpTzRBi50DcqI4Dc@IeEDU12b@1bfxa6tpsjb7d2wOpndlTRxyilPJzT4RXLu318iV/IsKwQIu/prNwcGKX0R8) flag and `0` with [-XNoStrictData](https://tio.run/##Fc2hDsIwEIBhv6dololWjIAmI5B1FgMCQUIupbCGW3tcT8DLUzb7i@8fIb88YilhosSi@hSFE66Gj/MkIcXqDgLKdlabaoIQOwfiRrUfmBP3gKipyf6tbeOXUtdmbfT11u5IbcyWOuIQpZSfeyA8c2kv5y/5AxGGGZr9JR3TSTg4sfPqDw).

If printing nothing in one case is allowed we can get it down to [**86 bytes**](https://tio.run/##Fc0xDsIwDEDRvaeIqg7JAOIClUBNTwADqxUCtXAS43iglye06x/eX6C@I1FrmLiImqlklULH@RsiK5bcPUDB@NFb1yXAPAbQsJjzLFJkAiLLglmHGj/WD3Gvfe9OLsXEurb2C0@CV22H@23leGEm3IQN3tNVBYP67fAH) replacing the main by (19 bytes off by [dfeuer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38603/dfeuer)):

```hs
main=catch @ErrorCall(print$seq(D$error"")0)mempty
```

---

**Note:** All solutions require `TypeApplications` set.

Comment: You can cut this down pretty easily to 98 bytes, which happens to match my (very different) solution exactly. [TIO](https://tio.run/##HcqxDoIwEIDhnadoiEMZILqS4EJ5Ao1xcOAshzQcbXPcoDG@ujW4/fnyT7DOSJSSW2JgUW3wwoGq7mkxigs@G0BAmcboIhuVeX@afbaA801k50WPldkhc@A8L3oLYqf@prGuu81aICrK4/9Uh5S@diR4rKm8noSdlS1siDicXxEvwA7uhOsP).

Comment: Actually, you can do even better: instead of printing in the exception handler, just use `pure()`.

Comment: @dfeuer: Nice, the `D{}` trick is pretty cool! Shaved another one off by using `PartialTypeSignatures` instead of `ScopedTypeVariables` :)

Comment: You used the `Monoid` instance for `ErrorCall ->IO ()`?! Devious! The record syntax trick is useful in real code when the number of fields in a sum type constructor can potentially change, but you only care which constructor it is.

Comment: I'm not optimistic that my own `StrictData` solution can be cut down any, but do you think you could give it a try?

Comment: You can drop one more byte by switching from `catch` to `handle`: [95 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcjNCoJAEADgu08h0kEPLp0Fu7jeAzt0i0FHHZr9YZwgiV69rW4f3wrbHZlTIheDaN4FrxLY9M8Ro1Lw2QQKuW1tWWVzbl/v9pg5IN@u4CfG0qGLujdNLxKkA@b6dKtMFPJqZmMP@P@iSOkzzgzLlurroEKj/nAGUQK@7BEHWjzoQ3D7Ag)

Comment: BTW, your TIO for `StrictData` actually invokes `Strict` (unnecessarily).

Comment: I'm not sure printing nothing qualifies as printing a value.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, that's a good point, but it's not really clear to me what *exactly* "print a value" is supposed to mean in general. As I recall, `putStrLn.show$ ("'::Text)` doesn't print anything either.

Comment: @dfeuer: I had a look and tried a few things, but I never used Generics, so I'm probably not the right person.

Comment: [93 bytes](https://tio.run/##FY2xCsIwEED3fkUoGdqhgjhXlKZfoIODIEd62uA1OS836M8b7foevDdDfiJRKWHhJGqGFFUSbca3R9aQYjWBgnG9a9pqgRD7GeJEaA6jSJIBiJrrrduz2bWWbcZX4yyuqq7bbcU9S4haytffCR65dJfzh/HITMHD2l/RSSV4df/RDw)

Comment: You can do even better with bleeding edge GHC and `-XBlockArguments`: `main=catch @ErrorCall(p$seq(D$error"")1)\_->p 3`

Comment: It looks like empty output is fine.

Comment: 58 bytes for `StrictData`, taking advantage of some truly disgusting trickery. See my latest answer.

Answer (score 7):

## ExtendedDefaultRules, <s>54</s> 53 bytes

```hs
instance Num()
main=print(toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)
```

Prints `()` with [`-XExtendedDefaultRules`](https://tio.run/##HcmxDkAwEADQ3Vd0bBMSs4SJ1WCyXjg0rkf0mvh6R4wvb4O4I5Gq5yjAE5o@BeuyAJ7r8/IsVo6OUzBlVdnvDOQ/wdUNONVnWgjWqMXY3YI849ziAolkSITxBQ) and `0` with [`-XNoExtendedDefaultRules`](https://tio.run/##HcmxDkAwEIDh3VN0ZJCYJTXpajBZL3poXI/oNfH0jpj@fPk3SDsSqQZOAjyjGXIsqyJCYHtegaWUw3GOpmnbbxmw3c@vUKk@80KwJq2n4XC3IHv0PS6QScZMmF4).

This flag is enabled by default in GHCi, but not in GHC, which recently [caused some confusion for me](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42958768#42958768), though [BMO](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48198/bmo) was quickly able to help.

The above code is a golfed version of an example in the GHC User Guide where [type defaulting in GHCi](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#type-defaulting-in-ghci) is explained.

*-1 byte thanks to [Ørjan Johansen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66041/%c3%98rjan-johansen)!*

Comment: While looking at this code borrowed into [the polyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167271/) (where the parentheses give some trouble), I remembered that GHC supports the one byte shorter syntax `toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a`.

Comment: You can get it down to 48 bytes with `PartialTypeSignatures`: `main=print(toEnum 0::_=>Num a=>a)`. Also, your TIO link is out of date.

Answer (score 6):

## Strict, 52 bytes

```hs
import GHC.IO
f _=print()
main=f$unsafePerformIO$f()
```

[-XStrict](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRMHdw1nP058rTSHetqAoM69EQ5MrNzEzzzZNpTSvODEtNSC1KC2/KNfTXyVNQ/P//3/JaTmJ6cX/dSOCS4oyk0sA)

[-XNoStrict](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRMHdw1nP058rTSHetqAoM69EQ5MrNzEzzzZNpTSvODEtNSC1KC2/KNfTXyVNQ/P//3/JaTmJ6cX/dSP88oNLijKTSwA)

With `-XStrict`, prints `()` an extra time.

Thanks to @Sriotchilism O'Zaic for two bytes.

Answer (score 6):

## StrictData, 58 bytes

```hs
import GHC.Exts
data D=D Int
main=print$unsafeCoerce#D 3+0
```

[-XNoStrictData](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRMHdw1nPtaKkmCslsSRRwcXWRcEzr4QrNzEzz7agKDOvRKU0rzgxLdU5P7UoOVXZRcFY2@D//3/JaTmJ6cX/df3/60b4JqZnJnskFmcA2X75wSVFmcklLkDDAA)

[-XStrictData](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRMHdw1nPtaKkmCslsSRRwcXWRcEzr4QrNzEzz7agKDOvRKU0rzgxLdU5P7UoOVXZRcFY2@D//3/JaTmJ6cX/df3/60b4JqZnJnskFmcA2cElRZnJJS5AowA)

Requires `MagicHash` (to let us import `GHC.Exts` instead of `Unsafe.Coerce`) and `-O` (absolutely required, to enable unpacking of small strict fields).

With `-XStrictData`, prints 3. Otherwise, prints the integer value of the (probably tagged) pointer to the pre-allocated copy of `3::Integer`, which can't possibly be 3.

#### Explanation

It will be a bit easier to understand with a little expansion, based on type defaulting. With signatures, we can drop the addition.

```hs
main=print
  (unsafeCoerce# D (3::Integer)
    :: Integer)
```

Equivalently,

```hs
main=print
  (unsafeCoerce# $
    D (unsafeCoerce# (3::Integer))
    :: Integer)
```

Why does it ever print 3? This seems surprising! Well, small `Integer` values are represented very much like `Int`s, which (with strict data) are represented just like `D`s. We end up ignoring the tag indicating whether the integer is small or large positive/negative.

Why can't it print 3 without the extension? Leaving aside any memory layout reasons, a data pointer with low bits (2 lowest for 32-bit, 3 lowest for 64-bit) of 3 must represent a value built from the third constructor. In this case, that would require a *negative* integer.

Answer (score 5):

## DeriveAnyClass, <s>121</s> 113 bytes

<sup>Thanks to [dfeuer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38603/dfeuer) for quite some bytes!</sup>

```hs
import Control.Exception
newtype M=M Int deriving(Show,Num)
main=handle h$print(0::M);h(_::SomeException)=print 1
```

[-XDeriveAnyClass](https://tio.run/##PY2xDoIwFAB3vqKDAyRqdK1hMGCMAywY42YqPGlj@9q0VcSPt4Ia17vkjjN3BSlDEMpo60mm0Vst55tHDcYLjRFC53sDpEgLskNPGrDiLrCNK667aXlTSaSYwJQzbCQQPjFWoI8XlBbJiscnSiut4N9L0o8nyxBe9UWy1oXZMR@bsMY@k8yNYAsIlknxhKb8/vPfdpBVrQ00@wEemBXsLMG9AQ) prints `1` whereas [-XNoDeriveAnyClass](https://tio.run/##PY6xDoIwFEV3vqKDAyRqdK1hMGCMAywY42YqPGlj@9q0VcSPt4Ia13OScy9n7gpShiCU0daTTKO3Ws43jxqMFxojhM73BkiRFmSHnjRgxV1gG1dcd9PyppJIMYEpZ9hIIHxirEAfLygtkhWPT5RWWsG/l6QfT5YhvOqLZK0Ls2Op87EKa@wzydyItoBgmRRPaMrvg/w3PMiq1gaa/QAPzAp2luDe) prints `M 0`.

This is exploiting the fact that DeriveAnyClass is the default strategy when both DeriveAnyClass and GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving are enabled, as you can see from the warnings. This flag will happily generate empty implementations for all methods but GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving is actually smart enough to use the underlying type's implementation and since `Int` is a `Num` it won't fail in this case.

---

If printing nothing in case the flag is enabled replacing the `main` by the following would be [**109 bytes**](https://tio.run/##PY1NC4JAEEDv/gqPChmdBYPQiA5KYIduNeikQ7uzyzp92I9vM4qu78F7PQwXVMp70tY4CXPD4oyarx8NWiHDAeNdRothmZXhliVs0dGNuIvq3txn1VXHgQbizDpiiRZpWsanBqTpT5FGbWVM09po/AeT5TH2/tWcFXSDTw7Fp4crHnMFwwdskNGBoie21fdd/JaT3IETArWfaE0dg1wdDm8):

```hs
main=print(0::M)`catch`(mempty::SomeException->_)
```

Comment: At least in `runhaskell`, this actually prints `M 1` with `-XDeriveAnyClass`, due to laziness...

Comment: @ceasedtoturncounterclockwis: Yes in GHCi as well, but when compiling on TIO (and my machine) & then running it results in `1` :)

Comment: [113 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY7PasJAEMbvPoXHBLQPIKQgWnqKiOmhtzpspsng7swyO2rTh@82i6XH7w@/7xshXdD7nClEUVvuhE3FP718OYxGwgvGu00Rl23TVnWPSjfioepGua9aYaG@XgQgbqISWxU2m7Y@OzA3novoJOA/a/38MZebgCHalPOP@/QwpLx@P8i@gHHL085DKtYrMip4@sb@8Hiw/9uewyOoEfi32e1oYLCr4oNTLgXROFIKJ0ym5MryLw)

Comment: [109 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY1Ba8JAEEbv/oocE6hCrwELRUV6SChND73psI7J0N2ZZXasTX@8W4Pi9X187w2QvtH7nClEUStWwqbiF5tfh9FIeMZ4tjFi0Syb4o2tOKDSD3FfdoOcn9pTqGYBiJdRia18ruum2jswN@zLgCHaWNedBHwI5y@7KueLO3roU55/rScfvvK48pAmsEVGBU9/eGhv7fU9eR3fQY3Af15pRz2DnRSnUyuNsATROFAKH5hMyU25fw)

Comment: I got it down to 104 in a completely different way, so I added my own answer.

Answer (score 5):

## UnboxedTuples, 52 bytes

```hs
import Language.Haskell.TH
main=runQ[|(##)|]>>=print
```

Requires `-XTemplateHaskell`. Prints `ConE GHC.Prim.(##)` with [-XUnboxedTuples](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRMEnMS@9NDE9Vc8DIqEX4sGVm5iZZ1tUmhcYXaOhrKxZE2tnZ1tQlJlX8v//v@S0nMT04v@6ESGpuQU5iSWpUH1AkdC8pPyK1JSQ0oKc1GIA) and `UnboundVarE ##` with [-XNoUnboxedTuples](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRMEnMS@9NDE9Vc8DIqEX4sGVm5iZZ1tUmhcYXaOhrKxZE2tnZ1tQlJlX8v//v@S0nMT04v@6ESGpuQU5iSWpUH1AEb/80Lyk/IrUlJDSgpzUYgA).

Comment: Shouldn't there be another +16 in the score for the required option `-XTemplateHaskell`?

Comment: @celtschk I did not count it because the current [meta consensus on command line flags](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14337/command-line-flags-on-front-ends/14339#14339) says they are not counted but constitute a new language instead. Though upon thinking about it I see that in the context of this challenge which only allows Haskell answers but also the use of other flags it is not quite clear what todo. I'll ask OP about it.

Comment: I wasn't aware that the consensus on this has changed. Thank you for the pointer. Asking the OP is a good idea for sure.

Answer (score 5):

## OverloadedLists, 76 bytes

```hs
import GHC.Exts
instance IsList[()]where fromList=(():)
main=print([]::[()])
```

With [-XOverloadedLists](https://tio.run/##Pc1LCsIwEAbgfU@RZbLQAxS6Eh8BoVuhdBHTqQ1OkpIZtKc3MiBuP/7H4ugJiLWGuObC6nw57I8bUxMSsUselKVrIB60Gd8LFFBzyVGk09q0pokupG4tIbEexraVnKn142d0D6q7W/@CgtlNMElJ5ISwhTuC/T2I2eSzrCf@6xc) it prints `[()]`. With [-XNoOverloadedLists](https://tio.run/##Pc1LCsIwEAbgfU@RZbLQAxS6Eh8B0a1Quojp1A4mk5IJ2tMbGRC3H/9jdvyEEGrFuKRc1PG02@7Xwg0SF0celOUzcum1Gd4zZFBTTlGk09q0pokOqVsyUtH90LaSM7V@/BTcg@vmdknXF@SQ3Aij1MQOAVa8B7C/DzFLPsk@lb9@AQ) it prints `[]`

This requires the additional flags: `-XFlexibleInstances`, `-XIncoherentInstances`

Comment: You can get away with overlapping instances.

Answer (score 5):

## [HexFloatLiterals](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#hexadecimal-floating-point-literals), <s>49</s> 25 bytes

*-24 bytes thanks to Ørjan Johansen.*

```hs
main|(.)<-seq=print$0x0.0
```

Prints `0.0` with `-XHexFloatLiterals` and `0` with `-XNoHexFloatLiterals`.

There are no TIO links because HexFloatLiterals was added in ghc 8.4.1, but TIO has ghc 8.2.2.

Comment: `main|(.)<-seq=print$0x0.0` avoids the import hiding.

Comment: `main|let _._=0=print$0x0.0` might be easier for the polyglot though.

Answer (score 5):

## ScopedTypeVariables, 37 bytes

```hs
main=print(1::_=>a):: ∀a.a~Float=>_
```

This also requires `UnicodeSyntax`,`PartialTypeSignatures`, `GADTs`, and `ExplicitForAll`.

[Try it online (without extension)](https://tio.run/##FY2xCsIwFEV/xVGHCq6BFApaNxFapVu5prE@fCYhidAu4uh3@iHGdrocOId7Q7hr5pQeICOdJxOXGyFamWMlxOL7eWONV8kWUeZtSj91ZfQhZc3JkLKdrkYTMUx8hI8ErkenK@oN4tPr2dsX23re3eCYFMXS@mI6zJqDrZR1upuLMzzhwjr8AQ)

[Try it online (with extension)](https://tio.run/##FY2xCsIwGAZfxVGHCq6BFApaVyFVupXPNNYf/yYhjdAu4uhz@iDGdjoODu6O4WGYU@pBVvpANq53QjQyx0aI1ffzxhavkh2izJuUfvrG6IaU1WdL2rVGTTZinP2EEAlcTd4o6iziM5ilOxb7auFh9EyaYulCMQ@zWmnnTbv0FwTClc3wBw)

#### Explanation

The partial type signatures are just to save bytes. We can fill them in like so:

```hs
main=print(1::(Num a, Show a)=>a):: ∀a.a~Float=>IO ()
```

With scoped type variables, the `a` in the type of `1` is constrained to be the `a` in the type of `main`, which itself is constrained to be `Float`. Without scoped type variables, `1` defaults to type `Integer`. Since `Float` and `Integer` values are shown differently, we can distinguish them.

Thanks to @ØrjanJohansen for a whopping 19 bytes! He realized that it was much better to take advantage of the difference between `Show` instances of different numerical types than differences in their arithmetic. He also realized that it was okay to leave the type of `main` "syntactically ambiguous" because the constraint actually disambiguates it. Getting rid of the local function also freed me up to remove the type signature for `main` (shifting it to the RHS) to save five more bytes.

Comment: [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##FY2xCsIwFEV3v8JRhwqugRQKWjcRWqRbuca0Pnwm4SWCLn660UwXzuFwb4h3y5zzA@SUmryAeYkNPi17JF2Pi2J0EHJptVVq1DXWOX/NxJhjroYTJBG4fwfb0eyQnmILPzS7vuz@FZgMpdZL8z@qhqPvjA/2WoozhHBhG38 "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, *nice*.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, should I make the edit, or would you prefer to add your own?

Comment: Edit, it was a gradual evolution from yours.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, thanks, that was beautiful.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, five more down. I suspect this may be minimal.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know the `:: forall a. ...` for scoping could be on a local expression.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, I learned that trick from Ed Kmett.

Answer (score 4):

## PostfixOperators, 63 bytes

```hs
import Text.Show.Functions
instance Num(a->b)
main=print(0`id`)
```

[Try it online (without extension)](https://tio.run/##BcExDoMwDADAnVcwwgDiA@3ISJFg6IibBrCa2FFsBK/HvdtBfj4EM4yJs5azv7Sddj7b/iCnyCQFkiiQ8@VwxAqa56cuIiA9UkbSqlvwu9Rmt1sDbGLNe@CRRVe8XslnUM7yBw)

[Try it online (with extension)](https://tio.run/##BcExDoMwDADAnVcwwgDiA2XsWCqVgRGThmKR2FFsVF6PudtAdh@CGcbEWcvRn9p@Nv63z4OcIpMUSKJAzpevI1bQ9EtdREB6pIykVTfjd67NLrcG@Ik105tFVzyH5DMoZ7kB)

This is a cut-down version of [a Hugs/GHC polyglot I wrote](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180958/38603). See that post for explanation. Thanks to @ØrjanJohansen for realizing I could use `id` instead of a custom operator, saving four bytes.

Comment: `id` can be used instead of `!`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, yes indeed! That saves a cool four bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## StrictData, 97 bytes

```hs
import GHC.Generics
data A=A()deriving Generic
main=print$selDecidedStrictness$unM1.unM1$from$A()
```

[Try it online (no strict data)](https://tio.run/##LY07DsIwEER7n8JFiqQAKQdwEWEpNKGhoV3Zm7DCn8hrcXwWI1LOzNObJ/ALQxChuOdS9Xy9nGdMWMix8lBBT2bqB9@KN6VNH5taxn4ZNQxmLTl2jVARKJm9UKodY7DoyKO/1wbXhMwaRD5uDbCxnB63/F9se2jR/vR4uL8)

[Try it online (strict data)](https://tio.run/##LYwxDoMwEAR7v8IFBRSJxANcoFgiDRVN2pN9kFNsg3ynPB/jKJQ7O5o38AdDKIXivmXR4/NxHzFhJsfKg4AezNB2voIvpVVfn5r6duo1dGbJW2yqoSJQMnumJA1jsOjIo5@lypKQWUMph1sCrFxurz@3tV@H/cXxKp8)

Also requires `DeriveGeneric`.

Answer (score 4):

## DeriveAnyClass, 104 bytes

```hs
import Control.Exception
newtype M a=M a deriving(Show,Exception)
main=print.displayException$M Deadlock
```

[Try it online (without extension)](https://tio.run/##PY2xDoJAEER7vuIKC02UP6AwYKygobHdcCtsWHYvdxcRP95ToqGYZuZl3gBhROaUaHLqoylVolfOL88OXSSVTHCOi0NTGyi@MRY9PUj6fTvofNy4QzYBSeE8ScwtBcewbOOuNhWCZe3GlN7dnaEP6XRrtFrP8CxLyRDW6oqCHpheaJufuPr7Pg)

[Try it online (with extension)](https://tio.run/##PY0xDsIwEAT7vMIFBUiQH6RAMaIKDQ3tyT6SUy5ny7YI5vEYIlCKbXZHOwPEEZlLocm7kFTrJAXH9elp0CdyUgnOKXtUnYLmG2Ux0IOk314HN@9XbldNQNL4QJJqS9Ez5HXcdEojWHZmLOVt7gx9LIebXq7wKLlliEtxRsEATC@0l59W/20f)

Also requires `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`.

Answer (score 4):

## TemplateHaskell, <s>140</s> 91 bytes

Just copied from [mauke](https://github.com/mauke/poly.poly/blob/master/poly.poly) with small modifications. I don't know what's going on.

*-49 bytes thanks to Ørjan Johansen.*

```hs
import Language.Haskell.TH
instance Show(Q a)where show _=""
main=print$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1LCsIwFAD3OcVDCm0XzQFK667QhQjFLgQReYZnE2yTkA/19vGD4MbZDQzMFb1MAgM0TQU5z2ELNy59Uos1LsAO9RRxIt6jv9M887FnSvuAWhAcpFmLAbBcJTkC/1K4tJsNW1Dp1jqlQ1bY6Cgbo@1O57ruHnYoE2cu6kkKqI57M9JiZwz0HXzujIQ0UL35pf9CSE8)

Comment: `$(...)` (no space) is template evaluation syntax when TH is enabled, and `TupE[]` ("empty tuple") gives `()`. [Using `Show`](https://tio.run/##bc29CsIwFEDhPU9xKYW2Q/MApXUrdBCh2EEQkWu5NsEkDfmhvn0UEVwcD99wbuhFmjFA29ZQ8AJ2cOfCJ6nt6gLs0SwRF@ID@gcpxaeBSeMDmpngKNatHAGrTZAj8O@Ea5dlTKM0nXXShLy00VE@RdufL03TP@1YJc5cNIuYoT4d1om0VRjoO/jcf/5PIb0A "Bash – Try It Online") might work well for the polyglot, although for this particular challenge I feel a bit bad about defining a value to print as an empty string...

Answer (score 4):

## UnicodeSyntax, 33 bytes

```bash
(∀)=0
main|forall<-1=print(∀)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFiiYGOjq6Cup65gp5Cml1H8X@NRR4OmrQFXbmJmXk1aflFiTo6NrqFtQVFmXglY7r8eV1FpXnpGsoJuhF9@aF5mcn5KanBlXkliBdgEhCymnMJ/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## MonomorphismRestriction, <s>31</s> 29 bytes

Edit:

- -2 bytes with an improvement by H.PWiz

```hs
f=(2^)
main=print$f$f(6::Int)
```

[-XMonomorphismRestriction](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P81WwyhOkys3MTPPtqAoM69EJU0lTcPMysozr0Tz//9/yWk5ienF/3UjfPPz8nPziwoyMotzg1KLS4oyk0sy8/MA) prints `0`. [-XNoMonomorphismRestriction](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P81WwyhOkys3MTPPtqAoM69EJU0lTcPMysozr0Tz//9/yWk5ienF/3Uj/PJ98/Pyc/OLCjIyi3ODUotLijKTSzLz8wA) prints `18446744073709551616`.

- With the restriction, the two uses of `f` are forced to be the same type, so the program prints `2^2^6 = 2^64` as a 64-bit `Int` (on 64-bit platforms), which overflows to `0`.
- Without the restriction, the program prints `2^64` as a bignum `Integer`.

Comment: I think `f=(2^);main=print$f$f(64::Int)` would save a byte. But it won't realistically terminate

Comment: @H.PWiz Fortunately `64=2^6`, which saves yet another byte.

Answer (score 2):

## ScopedTypeVariables, <s>119</s> 97 bytes

Just copied from [mauke](https://github.com/mauke/poly.poly/blob/master/poly.poly) with small modifications.

Currently there are two other answers for ScopedTypeVariables: [113 bytes by Csongor Kiss](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153762) and  [37 bytes by dfeuer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181047).
This submission is different in that it does not require other Haskell extensions.

*-22 bytes thanks to Ørjan Johansen.*

```hs
class(Show a,Num a)=>S a where s::a->IO();s _=print$(id::a->a)0
instance S Float
main=s(0::Float)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY6xCoMwFAB3v@INBROo4pyqY6GLHVJKt/KMaROIieRFpF@fgkunjnfccCOSyQoTtG0FZV1CD6/aUFYOiZg0YQM8DusMyLteAsJmdNRAQmDVX66Mnwie3RKtTwdmp10jbwrrKaFXGiScXcBUzGh9R6wRYmee6yKu/m0UVI8hSBUWPd0@i75jtDg6TfvHr/lXQP4C)

Comment: [97 bytes](https://tio.run/##dY6xCoMwFAB3v@INBROo4pyqY6GLHVJKt/KMaROIieRFpF@fgkunjnfccCOSyQoTtG0FZV1CD6/aUFYOiZg0YQM8DusMyLteAsJmdNRAQmDVX66Mnwie3RKtTwdmp10jbwrrKaFXGiScXcBUzGh9R6wRYmee6yKu/m0UVI8hSBUWPd0@i75jtDg6TfvHr/lXQP4C "Bash – Try It Online") (although the `IO()/print` trick won't work in the polyglot).

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I added ScopedTypeVariables, but [broke ExtendedDefaultRules](https://pastebin.com/8M0BP1Td). How it can be fixed? I already had such error before, but I am unable to apply your explanation here. The ScopedTypeVariables code I added is [this](https://tio.run/##dc6xCoMwFIXh3ac4Q0GFKs7WOHYRXCyl6zVGE4xRkoj06a3YoVP37z@clpzcOXkURYIwDVGiT6XbuSbnokbOG@harxMoZmUFwiaFFRjznJKy8VaZ4TayZbXi4g4c9cjiL@mZ6k5FgTLOk@ECFe56Jh9oENPCDF6eFSiYSBm2HHM@gr6MUZbnJ40R72lgVzNIjuRVzw2fF9E93ot4klXUauHOxz/zT@wf).

Comment: I see, the codes use similar defaulting tricks, and they interfer with each other. One solution is to let the new one use a more restricted class than `Num`. I think ``class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k=pure$ show(f pi)where f=id::a->a};`` should work, conveniently using that `Float` and `Double` display `pi` with different precision.

Answer (score 2):

## OverloadedStrings, 77 bytes

```hs
import Data.String
instance IsString Double where fromString _=0
main=print""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY0xDsIwDEX3nMLq0omIA7RMXVhgYOmG3NRtIjVJZbtw/IAoEgvjf/9Jb0DxxaFC00BtazjBZL2UENfMCh0q2ptySLMJSRSTIzjLTqDL27AQPD0xwcQ5fvm9PZqIIbXre2pVFWt4S7N3cOgv@fogXjKONO66fIo/4/9fXg)

Other OverloadedStrings answers: [by ბიმო](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153755), [by felixphew](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153913).
This one does not require other extensions. Created by Ørjan Johansen.

Answer (score 1):

## NegativeLiterals, 20 bytes

```hs
main=print$ -1`mod`2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFiiYGOjoK6nrmCnkKaXUfw/NzEzz7agKDOvREVB1zAhNz8lwei/HldRaV56RrKCboRfvl9qemJJZlmqT2ZJalFiTjFYH5ICbNL/AQ)

Copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54429195).

Answer (score 1):

## [LexicalNegation](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/lexical_negation.html), 20 bytes

```hs
main=print$ -1`mod`2
```

*(No TIO: ghc 8.2.2 < 9.0.1)*

Same as NegativeLiterals.

Answer (score 1):

## [MonomorphismRestriction](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/monomorphism.html?highlight=monomorphismrestriction#extension-NoMonomorphismRestriction), 24 bytes

```
p=1
x=p+0.0
main=print$p
```

[`-XMonomorphismRestriction`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8FNjWpdZQWfxLz00sT0VAXf_Lz83PyigozM4tyg1OKSoszkksz8PAVl3dqlpSVpuhY7CmwNuSpsC7QN9Ay4chMz82wLijLzSlQKINILoBSUBgA) gives `1.0`

[`-XNoMonomorphismRestriction`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8FNrWpdZQWfxLz00sT0VAW_fN_8vPzc_KKCjMzi3KDU4pKizOSSzPw8BWXd2qWlJWm6FjsKbA25KmwLtA30DLhyEzPzbAuKMvNKVAog0gugFJQGAA) gives `1`

### Explanation

So here we have `p` which I assign to `1`.  Now in Haskell `1` is a numeric literal and can be any `Num` type.  Next we assign `x` to `p+0.0`, `0.0` is another literal, but it's a fractional literal so it has a more specific type than `1`.  That's ok since `Fractional`s are also `Num`s.  So `x` is just some fractional type.  Then we print `p`.

So how does the monomorphism restriction come into play?  Well since `p` doesn't have a type anotation, the compiler needs to come up with a type for `p`.  With the monomorphism restriction this type is going to be concrete, i.e. it's going to come up with the first type it can rather than the most general kind.  It sees that `p` is used as a fractional in the definition of `x` so it picks `Float` as the type for `p`.  When we print `p` it's then printing a float, so it prints a decimal.

Without the monomorphism restriction the compiler takes some extra time and figures out that there is a polymorphic type that can be given to `p`.  So it assigns it the polymorphic type `Num a => a` rather than `Float`.  It then doesn't matter what's going on in `x` as long as it type checks it can't influence the type of `p`.  When we print `p` at the end then the compiler once again has to guess a concrete type, however since the type is fully polymorphic it can choose its preferred default of `Int` and thus it prints `1` as an `Int` *without* the decimal place.

So here we are using type defaulting to control the type of the object that gets printed.  Since `1` prints differently as a `Float` and an `Int` this results in different output.